# ASCII's 95 Characters...95 Movie Quotes

Tags: restricted-source, printable-ascii, answer-chaining

***Update:* The winner has been decided, but the challenge is not over!**

Finally, nearly 3 months after the question first started, someone has remained the last answerer for more than a week! Congratulations to [jimmy23013](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/25180/jimmy23013) with his [P1eq answer!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42427/26997)

There are still however 8 characters left: `48KSaclw`. If anyone is really ambitious they can keep on trying with those :D

Thanks a ton to everyone who participated, especially those of you who kept the contest going so long with multiple answers, notably [KennyTM](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32353/kennytm) with a whopping 25 answers!!

Also, thanks to anyone who kept the answer list up to date, it was a great help :) (especially since I've been away from SE for a couple months :P).

---

***Original Question:***

In 2005 the [American Film Institute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Film_Institute) produced [AFI's 100 Years...100 Movie Quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AFI%27s_100_Years...100_Movie_Quotes), a list of the best quotes in American cinema. Here they are listed exactly as they should be used in this challenge:

```
(answer  6) 1. "Frankly, my dear, I don't give a damn." - Rhett Butler
(answer  7) 2. "I'm gonna make him an offer he can't refuse." - Vito Corleone
(answer  5) 3. "You don't understand! I coulda had class. I coulda been a contender. I could've been somebody, instead of a bum, which is what I am." - Terry Malloy
(answer  3) 4. "Toto, I've a feeling we're not in Kansas anymore." - Dorothy Gale
5. "Here's looking at you, kid." - Rick Blaine
(answer  2) 6. "Go ahead, make my day." - Harry Callahan
(answer 11) 7. "All right, Mr. DeMille, I'm ready for my close-up." - Norma Desmond
(answer  8) 8. "May the Force be with you." - Han Solo
(answer 12) 9. "Fasten your seatbelts. It's going to be a bumpy night." - Margo Channing
(answer 13) 10. "You talking to me?" - Travis Bickle
(answer 16) 11. "What we've got here is failure to communicate." - Captain
(answer 15) 12. "I love the smell of napalm in the morning." - Lt. Col. Bill Kilgore
(answer  4) 13. "Love means never having to say you're sorry." - Jennifer Cavilleri Barrett
14. "The stuff that dreams are made of." - Sam Spade
(answer 18) 15. "E.T. phone home." - E.T.
(answer 20) 16. "They call me Mister Tibbs!" - Virgil Tibbs
17. "Rosebud." - Charles Foster Kane
(answer 10) 18. "Made it, Ma! Top of the world!" - Arthur "Cody" Jarrett
(answer 17) 19. "I'm as mad as hell, and I'm not going to take this anymore!" - Howard Beale
(answer 25) 20. "Louis, I think this is the beginning of a beautiful friendship." - Rick Blaine
(answer 26) 21. "A census taker once tried to test me. I ate his liver with some fava beans and a nice Chianti." - Hannibal Lecter
(answer  9) 22. "Bond. James Bond." - James Bond
(answer 22) 23. "There's no place like home." - Dorothy Gale
(answer 29) 24. "I am big! It's the pictures that got small." - Norma Desmond
25. "Show me the money!" - Rod Tidwell
(answer 31) 26. "Why don't you come up sometime and see me?" - Lady Lou
(answer 27) 27. "I'm walking here! I'm walking here!" - "Ratso" Rizzo
(answer 14) 28. "Play it, Sam. Play 'As Time Goes By.'" - Ilsa Lund
(answer 28) 29. "You can't handle the truth!" - Col. Nathan R. Jessup
(answer 23) 30. "I want to be alone." - Grusinskaya
(answer 30) 31. "After all, tomorrow is another day!" - Scarlett O'Hara
(answer  1) 32. "Round up the usual suspects." - Capt. Louis Renault
(answer 24) 33. "I'll have what she's having." - Customer
(answer 36) 34. "You know how to whistle, don't you, Steve? You just put your lips together and blow." - Marie "Slim" Browning
(answer 19) 35. "You're gonna need a bigger boat." - Martin Brody
(answer 39) 36. "Badges? We ain't got no badges! We don't need no badges! I don't have to show you any stinking badges!" - "Gold Hat"
(answer 40) 37. "I'll be back." - The Terminator
(answer 33) 38. "Today, I consider myself the luckiest man on the face of the earth." - Lou Gehrig
(answer 37) 39. "If you build it, he will come." - Shoeless Joe Jackson
(answer 43) 40. "My mama always said life was like a box of chocolates. You never know what you're gonna get." - Forrest Gump
(answer 34) 41. "We rob banks." - Clyde Barrow
(answer 38) 42. "Plastics." - Mr. Maguire
43. "We'll always have Paris." - Rick Blaine
(answer 49) 44. "I see dead people." - Cole Sear
(answer 21) 45. "Stella! Hey, Stella!" - Stanley Kowalski
(answer 32) 46. "Oh, Jerry, don't let's ask for the moon. We have the stars." - Charlotte Vale
(answer 35) 47. "Shane. Shane. Come back!" - Joey Starrett
(answer 42) 48. "Well, nobody's perfect." - Osgood Fielding III
(answer 51) 49. "It's alive! It's alive!" - Henry Frankenstein
(answer 41) 50. "Houston, we have a problem." - Jim Lovell
(answer 45) 51. "You've got to ask yourself one question: 'Do I feel lucky?' Well, do ya, punk?" - Harry Callahan
(answer 55) 52. "You had me at "hello."" - Dorothy Boyd
(answer 46) 53. "One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got in my pajamas, I don't know." - Capt. Geoffrey T. Spaulding
(answer 44) 54. "There's no crying in baseball!" - Jimmy Dugan
(answer 59) 55. "La-dee-da, la-dee-da." - Annie Hall
(answer 60) 56. "A boy's best friend is his mother." - Norman Bates
(answer 47) 57. "Greed, for lack of a better word, is good." - Gordon Gekko
(answer 56) 58. "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Michael Corleone
(answer 48) 59. "As God is my witness, I'll never be hungry again." - Scarlett O'Hara
(answer 50) 60. "Well, here's another nice mess you've gotten me into!" - Oliver
(answer 65) 61. "Say "hello" to my little friend!" - Tony Montana
(answer 66) 62. "What a dump." - Rosa Moline
(answer 52) 63. "Mrs. Robinson, you're trying to seduce me. Aren't you?" - Benjamin Braddock
(answer 61) 64. "Gentlemen, you can't fight in here! This is the War Room!" - President Merkin Muffley
(answer 68) 65. "Elementary, my dear Watson." - Sherlock Holmes
(answer 64) 66. "Take your stinking paws off me, you damned dirty ape." - George Taylor
(answer 53) 67. "Of all the gin joints in all the towns in all the world, she walks into mine." - Rick Blaine
(answer 72) 68. "Here's Johnny!" - Jack Torrance
(answer 71) 69. "They're here!" - Carol Anne Freeling
(answer 73) 70. "Is it safe?" - Dr. Christian Szell
(answer 54) 71. "Wait a minute, wait a minute. You ain't heard nothin' yet!" - Jakie Rabinowitz/Jack Robin
(answer 77) 72. "No wire hangers, ever!" - Joan Crawford
(answer 67) 73. "Mother of mercy, is this the end of Rico?" - Cesare Enrico "Rico" Bandello
(answer 70) 74. "Forget it, Jake, it's Chinatown." - Lawrence Walsh
(answer 74) 75. "I have always depended on the kindness of strangers." - Blanche DuBois
(answer 78) 76. "Hasta la vista, baby." - The Terminator
(answer 75) 77. "Soylent Green is people!" - Det. Robert Thorn
(answer 76) 78. "Open the pod bay doors, HAL." - Dave Bowman
(answer 80) 79. Striker: "Surely you can't be serious." Rumack: "I am serious...and don't call me Shirley." - Ted Striker and Dr. Rumack
(answer 84) 80. "Yo, Adrian!" - Rocky Balboa
(answer 81) 81. "Hello, gorgeous." - Fanny Brice
(answer 83) 82. "Toga! Toga!" - John "Bluto" Blutarsky
(answer 63) 83. "Listen to them. Children of the night. What music they make." - Count Dracula
(answer 87) 84. "Oh, no, it wasn't the airplanes. It was Beauty killed the Beast." - Carl Denham
(answer 88) 85. "My precious." - Gollum
(answer 86) 86. "Attica! Attica!" - Sonny Wortzik
(answer 57) 87. "Sawyer, you're going out a youngster, but you've got to come back a star!" - Julian Marsh
(answer 82) 88. "Listen to me, mister. You're my knight in shining armor. Don't you forget it. You're going to get back on that horse, and I'm going to be right behind you, holding on tight, and away we're gonna go, go, go!" - Ethel Thayer
(answer 58) 89. "Tell 'em to go out there with all they got and win just one for the Gipper." - Knute Rockne
(answer 90) 90. "A martini. Shaken, not stirred." - James Bond
(answer 85) 91. "Who's on first." - Dexter
(answer 62) 92. "Cinderella story. Outta nowhere. A former greenskeeper, now, about to become the Masters champion. It looks like a mirac...It's in the hole! It's in the hole! It's in the hole!" - Carl Spackler
(answer 69) 93. "Life is a banquet, and most poor suckers are starving to death!" - Mame Dennis
(answer 89) 94. "I feel the need - the need for speed!" - Lt. Pete "Maverick" Mitchell and Lt. Nick "Goose" Bradshaw
(answer 79) 95. "Carpe diem. Seize the day, boys. Make your lives extraordinary." - John Keating
(answer 91) 96. "Snap out of it!" - Loretta Castorini
(answer 92) 97. "My mother thanks you. My father thanks you. My sister thanks you. And I thank you." - George M. Cohan
(answer 93) 98. "Nobody puts Baby in a corner." - Johnny Castle
(answer 94) 99. "I'll get you, my pretty, and your little dog, too!" - Wicked Witch of the West
(answer 95) 100. "I'm the king of the world!" - Jack Dawson
```

<sup>(Feel free to mark quotes as used.)</sup>

There are 95 [printable ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) characters (hex codes 20 to 7E), that's pretty close to 100:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

In this challenge users will take turns writing programs that print one of the movie quotes using a new programming language and a smaller subset of printable ASCII each time.

## How This Works

I've already submitted [the first answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40563/26997) and I've labeled it 95 since I was allowed to use all 95 printable ASCII characters in my program. It is a Python program that prints the 100th quote, `"I'm the king of the world!" - Jack Dawson`, to stdout.

The second person to answer needs to choose a new quote, a new programming language, and one of the 95 printable ASCII characters to exclude from their code. They must write a program without using this character that prints their chosen quote to stdout. They should mark their answer as 94 since they had 94 printable ASCII characters to work with (think of it like a countdown).

The third person to answer must choose a quote and language that haven't been used in any previous answers (only 95 and 94 in this case), and a new character to forgo. They must not use this character or any previously forbidden characters in their code. They mark their answer as 93.

This answering process continues like this until all printable ASCII characters are forbidden and someone gives the "1" answer, or much more likely, no one can figure out how to answer again.

## Rules *(please read carefully)*

It's important to understand that **only one person can answer at a time and each answer depends on the one before it.** There should never be two answers with the same number, quote, or programming language.

There's bound to be clashing answers submitted at the same time, and that's ok. If that happens the person who technically answered later should quickly (like 10 min or less) delete their post or edit it so it becomes the next answer. Otherwise, **don't edit code unless truly necessary**. Editing posts to only fix formatting is encouraged.

#### Specific Rules

- **A user who just answered must wait at least an hour before answering again.**
- A user may not answer twice in a row.
- **The quote number you choose must not be more than 5 below your answer number.** For example, answer 90 can choose any unused quote from number 85 to 100. This leaves the better quotes for the harder answers. Other than this rule the quote numbering is irrelevant.
- Programs may only contain tabs, newlines, and the printable ASCII character that are not forbidden so far. (Tabs and newlines are never forbidden.)
- There is no program length limit, but there may not be more that 64 tabs or 64 newlines in your program.
- Languages are considered distinct if they are commonly referred to by different names. Different versions of programming languages are not considered distinct. (Markup languages like HTML do count but full on programming languages are preferred.) Your language must have existed prior to the start of this contest.
- If your language does not have stdout use some similar text output mechanism.
- Your program should not take input or have unexpected side effects like creating files.

**Please make sure your program is valid.** It should be able to run as a full program as is, not just in a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) environment.

**Note that the "quote" you must output includes the quotation marks and the person who said it (but not the quote number).** Your program should solely produce your quote exactly as it appears in the list above (a leading/trailing newline is fine).

## Formatting

Please format your answers like this, `{stuff in curly braces}` needs to be replaced:

```
#{answer number}. {language}, uses no <code>{the forbidden character you just chose}</code>

    {program}

Output is quote {quote number}:

    {program output, should be identical to quote}

[Previously forbidden:]({url of previous answer (hit "share" just below it)}) <code>{the previous answerer's forbidden character followed by his previously forbidden list}</code>

{anything else you wish to say}
```

The `<code>` tags can be replaced with backticks (`` ` ``) as long as no backtick occurs within them.

## Scoring

The communal goal of this challenge is to keep answers coming for as long as possible.

The official winner is the user who answers last, after a week of no additional answers. I will accept their last answer.

## Answer List (newest first)

> 1. `4` [Progressive Unary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125006/32353)
> 2. `a` [Bueue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124753/25180)
> 3. `c` [Udage](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82421/32353)
> 4. `S` [1L_a105](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80902/25180)
> 5. `w` [Binaryfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80705/32353)
> 6. `K` [Subskin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66836/25180)
> 7. `l` [23](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55678/32353)
>
> ---
>
> 8. `n` [P1eq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42427/21487)
> 9. `t` [Addleq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42292/2946)
> 10. `9` [x86 Machine Code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42250/25315)
> 11. `r` [BSM](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42214/32353)
> 12. `D` [ShaFuck 0.2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42121/20506)
> 13. `u` [Villmark](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42113/25180)
> 14. `O` [PDP-11 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42089/25315)
> 15. `f` [ProgFk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42068/32139)
> 16. `i` [NUMPAD](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42037/32139)
> 17. `H` [Tri](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42021/32139)
> 18. `2` [ferNANDo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42014/4098)
> 19. `P` [Pointy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42001)
> 20. `m` [Subleq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41976/25180)
> 21. `G` [FlogScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41973/25180)
> 22. `?` [Nqubl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41970/25180)
> 23. `%` [Glypho](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41965/194)
> 24. `!` [3var](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41961/32139)
> 25. `q` [ETA](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41942/32139)
> 26. `j` [BrainSpace 1.0](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41935/32353)
> 27. `V` [Insomnia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41931/32353)
> 28. `` ` `` [asdf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41926/32139)
> 29. `6` [Lazy K](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41887/32139)
> 30. `C` [!Py!Batch 1.5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41869/32139)
> 31. `T` [Fuckfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41834/32353)
> 32. `F` [PoGo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41821/32139)
> 33. `R` [Golunar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41816/25180)
> 34. `b` [6502 machine code + Apple II System Monitor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41812/25180)
> 35. `Y` [Headsecks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41802/788)
> 36. `I` [BRB](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41796/788)
> 37. `U` [Braincrash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41794/788)
> 38. `Z` [Ecstatic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41755/788)
> 39. `M` [Farm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41686/788)
> 40. `A` [Enema](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41678/788)
> 41. `L` [ADJUST](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41640/788)
> 42. `$` [Beatnik](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41635/788)
> 43. `N` [Rebmu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41604/788)
> 44. `g` [Dupdog](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41591/788)
> 45. `B` [Gammaplex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41569/788)
> 46. `J` [Fuck4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41542/788)
> 47. `5` [A0A0](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41534/788)
> 48. `W` [gs2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41513/788)
> 49. `:` [l33t](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41502/788)
> 50. `h` [Tonoco](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41414/788)
> 51. `E` [Malbolge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41341/788)
> 52. `k` [D1ffe7e45e](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41325/788)
> 53. `1` [evil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41303/788)
> 54. `Q` [CaneCode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40925/788)
> 55. `d` [Grass](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40900/788)
> 56. `#` [URSL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40875/788)
> 57. `|` [Burlesque](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40822/788)
> 58. `x` [Emmental](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40813/788)
> 59. `~` [Applesoft BASIC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40807/788)
> 60. `^` [Forth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40775/788)
> 61. `7` [80386 machine code + DOS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40771/788)
> 62. `_` [Argh!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40770/788)
> 63. `v` [Rexx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40755/788)
> 64. `}` [AlphaBeta](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40718/788)
> 65. `o` [Super Stack!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40686/788)
> 66. `e` [Pyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40680/788)
> 67. `z` [Plain TeX](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40674/788)
> 68. `>` [WASD](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40667/788)
> 69. `]` [POSIX shell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40664/788)
> 70. `&` [Gibberish](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40642/8478)
> 71. `/` [GolfScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40634/8478)
> 72. `*` [x86_64 assembly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40622/788)
> 73. `0` [AppleScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40614/788)
> 74. `X` [Deadfish~](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40612/788)
> 75. `,` [Spoon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40610/788)
> 76. `-` [oOo CODE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40609/788)
> 77. `=` [J](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40608/788)
> 78. `@` [Mathematica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40606/788)
> 79. `.` [Perl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40604/788)
> 80. `+` [DNA#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40597/788)
> 81. `<` [Pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40595/788)
> 82. `)` [Postscript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40593/788)
> 83. `[` [ABC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40589/788)
> 84. `s` [dc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40587/788)
> 85. `{` [HTML](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40586/788)
> 86. `(` [Unary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40584/788)
> 87. `;` [Ook!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40583/788)
> 88. `'` [CJam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40582/788)
> 89. [PHP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40579/788)
> 90. `"` [Brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40576/788)
> 91. `\` [Marbelous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40570/788)
> 92. `3` [C++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40569/788)
> 93. `y` [Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40567/788)
> 94. `p` [JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40566/788)
> 95. [Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40563/788)

<sup>(Feel free to edit if incorrect or out of date)</sup>

**[This question works best when you sort by "oldest".](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40562/asciis-95-characters-95-movie-quotes-testing-new-challenge-type?answertab=oldest#tab-top)**

*NOTE: Like my [last question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40376/26997), this is a test of a new challenge type where each answer depends on the last and increases in difficulty. Come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18189/discussion-for-evolution-of-hello-world) or [meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2415/26997) to discuss either question or the idea in general.*

Comment: How strange. Everyone knows how to do #2, but nobody wants to do it (mostly because #1 would become impossible). If this challenge was rebooted, it would probably be finishable.

Comment: I will do this!

Comment: @CalculatorFeline how do you do 2?

Comment: Same way you do #1. Lenguage. Of course, that would kill the challenge.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage) was made up for this challenge, which is a [standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/25180). (See the link in the first line.)

Comment: ...Oh. I suppose that means we'll need some other way :/

Comment: Too bad #53 killed `1`, or else Unary would save the day :(

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Unary is used in answer 86.

Comment: Also not using Unary until #1. Maybe this should be done somewhere where we can have branching :P (and not here, have you even seen [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49223/evolution-of-oeis)? If we do, backlinking (and maybe frontlinking) should be required.

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo I never found the right esolang :_(

Comment: @Christopher  The right language now is Nullary https://esolangs.org/wiki/Nullary - convert the Progressive Unary answer to a time and you can have the last answer by prohibiting future answers from using 8 (the last available character).

Comment: So, are all the characters taken? there is a 1 answer but there are unmarked quotes and the title hasn't been updated

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## 8. [P1eq](http://esolangs.org/wiki/P1eq) (uses no `n`)

It requires non-Windows 64-bit platform to work correctly, just like the Addleq answer. It used the same trick for the -1.

It has 64 newlines and 57 tabs.

It is slow and ended in about 18mins on my computer.

```
844 844 88888   848
844 4
844 444
444
8   448
444 448 4
484
884 488
488
488
484 488 88
84  48
48
844 4444
4444
848 844 88888
88884884    888484  4484
8884484 4444848 4848888
4448448 4488    4444848
488 88  44888
4884848 4488    4444848
8488884 4488    4444848
484884888   48848   4848888
4448448 4444848 8884484
88  4488848 884484
88884884    4444848 4844848
4444848 4444888 4484
44884   4444848 8
444844  88  8484484
48  884
844 484
88
4444
444 4448
4444    4448    4
4448
444 4448    88888888888888888888
48  4444
444 4448
4444    4448    4
4448
4448
444 4448    4
444
444
444
444
444
444
444
444
444
444
444
444
444
444
444
444
444
444
444
444
444 88888888888888888888
848 844 4
```

Output is quote 8:

```
"May the Force be with you." - Han Solo
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42292/25180):

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./01235679:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkLmMNoOpPqQrRstTuUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining:

- Numbers: `4` `8`
- Uppercase: `K` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `l` `w`

P1eq is just like Subleq and Addleq, with the instruction B=A+1 and jump if B isn't changed.

Explanation:

```
844 844 88888        # *844 = 1.
848 addr4:844 4 7    # Jump back to 4. And add some nonsense values to *4,
                     #   which is never read. Note that if it jumps to 8, 
                     #   neither *44 nor *48 could be a jump target.
844 444 10           # Initialize *444 to 2.
addr10: 444 444 13   # Increment *444.
8 448 16             # *448 = 445.
444 448 4            # If *444 == 444, jump back to 4.
484 484 22           # Increment *484.
884 488 25           # *488 = *884 + 1.
488 488 28           # Increment *488 two times. This prevents the infinite
488 488 31           #   loop when *884 is uninitialized.
484 488 88           # If *484 + 1 == *488, jump to 88.
84 48 37             # *48 = 10.
48 48 40
844 4444 43          # *4444 = 3.
4444 4444 46
848 844 addr48:88888 # Jump back to 10.

# Data.

88884884 888484 4484
8884484 4444848 4848888
4448448 4488 4444848
488 88 44888
4884848 4488 4444848
8488884 4488 4444848
484884888 48848 4848888
4448448 4444848 8884484
88 4488848 884484
88884884 4444848 4844848
4444848 4444888 4484
44884 4444848 addr84:8    # The 8 is for getting 10 in the loop.
444844 88 8484484

addr88:48 884 91     # *884 = content of current cell. 48 is also the last
                     #   data cell, which will be 88, the address of itself
                     #   when read. 884 is also the end-of-data marker.
                     # *444 will be (current cell value mod 441) + 3
844 484 94           # Reset *484 to 1.
88 88 97             # Increment the data pointer.
4444 4444 100        # *4444 = 4.
444 4448 103
4444 4448 4          # If *884 was uninitialized, skip.
4448 4448 109
444 4448 (-1)        # If it is at the end of data (2 mod 441), stop.
48 4444 115          # *4444 = 10
444 4448 118
4444 4448 4          # If the current cell value is 8, skip.
4448 4448 124
4448 4448 127
444 4448 4           # If the current cell value is 10 (the jump target), skip.
444 444 133          # *444 += 20. This makes the last cell value 88 outputs the
444 444 136          #   last character "o".
444 444 139          # *444 will be (current cell value mod 441) + 23, which is
444 444 142          #   either the character to output, or the character to
444 444 145          #   output + 256. Some characters' minimum mod 441
444 444 148          #   representations using only 4 and 8 overflowed 32 bit
444 444 151          #   integer. But those characters plus 256 worked well.
444 444 154
444 444 157
444 444 160
444 444 163
444 444 166
444 444 169
444 444 172
444 444 175
444 444 178
444 444 181
444 444 184
444 444 187
444 444 190
444 (-1) 193         # Output the character.
848 844 4            # Jump back to the loop.
```

This program increments *444 and *484 together, and resets *444 when it becomes a certain value. When *484 equals to the data, *444 will be the remainder of the data divided by some value.

Only 6 memory cells in the code are addressable directly with 4 and 8. I must reuse some of them. This also made some operations not in the order I wanted, such as using uninitialized variables. But I can just discard whatever is returned in the first time of the loop and initialize after that.

---

Some other languages found interesting but no longer usable:

- More Unary variants

  - [Dot](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Dot) (uses `.`)
  - [A Language With Only One Instruction](https://web.archive.org/web/20080703211706/http://www.xyzzy.bravehost.com/NULL.html) (uses `*`)
  - [A](http://web.archive.org/web/20110319032415/http://www.sksk.info/a.html) (uses `A` but case sensitive, unfortunately) I found it in the Japanese Wikipedia.
- Languages using numbers

  - [NULL](http://esolangs.org/wiki/NULL) I believed it should work without odd numbers. Unfortunately it doesn't.
  - [Smith#](http://esolangs.org/wiki/SMITH_sharp)

Now I have 3 languages left.

For anyone who want to write more answers, here are some directions to look for:

- Real machine codes, if they have formats that don't require a file header, and have text input/output instructions.
- Number-based OISC.
- Non-esoteric languages, which happens to have single character instructions for some reasons. Maybe the APL family.
- Self-modifying binary code.
- Languages that are designed for some ideas about how the language should look like.
- Languages not on the esolangs wiki and don't have an English description, which means they are hardly known to other users.

To be exact, I had:

- A hexadecimal language which should be able to print a quote with some self-extraction code.
- A 2D language that works with any two distinct characters (except newlines).
- An undocumented language that can use line lengths as instructions.

Comment: Wow I thought P1Eq is not possible in 64 lines. +1. Excluding "Lenguage" I have 1 language left for answer #3. "Wunnel" would have been a perfect candidate for answer #2 but it prints literal 0s and 1s instead of bits. Totally wasted.

Comment: @KennyTM I didn't test my answer #2 yet. And I guess there will be no quote printable with my answer #1 language after someone post an answer #2. Now I'm looking for some other sources for languages than the wiki, but didn't find anything that works.

Comment: @KennyTM I found another way printing strings with my answer #1 language, which can print up to 62 characters. In fact it is just how the default example works, but I was too lazy to read the source to learn that undocumented language.

Comment: I've been off of SE for a while but unless I'm quite mistaken this answer has won! This was posted Dec 17 and a couple weeks have passed. Great job!

Answer (score 128):

## 90. Brainfuck, uses no `"`

```
     ++++             ++++        [>+>++>+++>++++>+  ++++>++++++>+++++++
   >+++++++         +>++++++      +++>++++++++++>+   ++ ++   ++++++>++++
  +++    +++       ++>    +++     +++       ++++  +++>++++++++
 +++      +++     >++      +++             ++++  ++ ++     ++
>+++      ++++   ++++      ++++           +<<<  <<   <   <<
<<<<      <<<<   -]>>      >>++          .-->  >>>+.-<<<<.>
>>>>      >>>>   >---      .+++         <<+.
->>+      +.--   >---      -.++        ++<<
 +.-      >--     .++      <+.        -<<<
  <<<    <--       .++    <<.       >>>>>
   >+++.---         >>>.<+.-       >+++.--
     ----             .+++        >--.++<<<

<<<<<----.++++<<.>>>>>>>>>>--.+.+>----.++++<<<<<<<<<<<.>>>>>>>>>>+++.--->----.
++++<<+.->++..--<---.-.++++<<<<<<<--.++<<++.--.>>---.+++<<.>>>>>++.-->>>+.->>-
--.+++<---.+++>+++.---<<<<<<<<<<.>>>>++.-->>>>>>-.-.++<----.++++<<<<<<<<<<<<<.
```

Output is quote 90:

```
"A martini. Shaken, not stirred." - James Bond
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40570/16120) `py3\`

Someone had to do it before any of `.+-` is forbidden.
Try it here : http://ideone.com/dlu8VE

Comment: Absolutely beautiful.

Comment: Why would you remove `"`? That's kind of mean for all the people after you.

Answer (score 79):

## 51. [Malbolge](http://esolangs.org/wiki/malbolge) (uses no `E`)

(Newlines are just for clarification and not part of the source.)

```
ba`r:?!!6l:jVVw5ut2rqML:nllHFFhDfAcR?P`ut:rqZYtm2qCRhPPNNihgf%qFF!!2AA??TSwutOTr55PImGFKJCBfFc
cbONq9!!6Y4W8hCf4ttOONL:JlHGFFDgfAS?b``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWttNML4nOlMFjhCBAF?
cC%A:9!!65492Vw5uu2rqMMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfRuPrr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::88ZYWmr2SSRglOjihgfI%FFDCBAWV?ZYw::8Tr54JImGFKDCgAF?
DC%%:98!654WWDUBRRPONqLLnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!m2AWVUZSRWPONMR54m!ljjihffw?
ct``:?8nmHGWWDUBRRPONqLLnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!m2AWVUZSRWPONMR54m!ljjihffw?
ct`%qLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rq6b4!BBW?UZYw:99Nr64JO2MFjDgffw?
ct`%qLKJZZGWWDTB4RPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rq6b4DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZ549ihwfut2bqNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBjihgfw::tTqLKPO!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZ549ihwfut2bqNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBjihgfw::tTqLKPO!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGW8hTfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUTww::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGW8hTfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUTww::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`%qLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONqLLnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rq6b4DBBWVUZSRWPONMR54m!ljjihffw?
ct`%qLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONqLLnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rq6b4DBBWVUZSRWPONMR54m!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6HGWWDUBRRPONNMKm%ljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAWVUZSRWPONMRKPOmlLjihffw?
ct``:?!!6HGWWDUBRRPONNMKm%ljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAWVUZSRWPONMRKPOmlLjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwT4uPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfwu98NMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwT4uPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfwu98NMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rrNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`6KPONMFjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rrNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`6KPONMFjihffw?
ct`NML8nml:jihwfut2bqNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDm2Aj??gfw::tTqLKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NML8nml:jihwfut2bqNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDm2Aj??gfw::tTqLKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKm%ljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPOmlLjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKm%ljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPOmlLjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONqLLnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMR54mHMLKDCgAF?
DC%A:9!!65:92Vw5uttONqLLnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMR54m!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nIljiFhfBTc!?``N:98Z65t42qjRRgfNMLLK9HHG5DZ2AA??gww:ttN6RKPOHlFKDCBGF?
DCB%:98!6Y:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6549WDUBRR2bq`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAjihZSRWPOTqL4nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6549WDUBRR2bq`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAjihZSRWPOTqL4nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6HGWWDUBRRPON`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAWVUZSRWPONMR4nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6HGWWDUBRRPON`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAWVUZSRWPONMR4nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6HGWWDUBRRPON`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAWVUZSRWPONMR4nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6HGWWDUBRRPON`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAWVUZSRWPONMR4nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?8nmHGWihwfutPONqLLnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!m2AWVUgfw::tNMR54m!ljjihffw?
ct``:?8nmHGWihwfutPONqLLnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!m2AWVUgfw::tNMR54m!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6HGW8hTT4uPON`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAWVUTwwu98NMR4nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6HGW8hTT4uPON`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAWVUTwwu98NMR4nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWihwfutPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUgfw::tNMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWihwfutPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUgfw::tNMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct`%qLKJZHGWihwfutPONNMKm%ljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rq6b4DBBWVUgfw::tNMRKPOmlLjihffw?
ct`%qLKJZHGWihwfutPONNMKm%ljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rq6b4DBBWVUgfw::tNMRKPOmlLjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWihwfutPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUgfw::tNMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWihwfutPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUgfw::tNMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZ549ihwfut2bqNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBjihgfw::tTqLKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZ549ihwfut2bqNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBjihgfw::tTqLKPONMFjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rq6F!DBBAVUTSw:99Nr54J22MFjDCBAF?
DC%A:9!!6549Vhwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nnlGFjJIBGF?
cC%%:?8!65:9Vhwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6uWVUTSSRPlOjihgJI%FFDCCAAV?ZYw:98NMR5Jn2GFKDCHGF?
DCBA:9!!Zl:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZ549ihwfut2bqNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBjihgfw::tTqLKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZ549ihwfut2bqNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBjihgfw::tTqLKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rrNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`6KPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rrNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`6KPONMFjihffw?
ct`%qLKJZHGWihwfutPONNMKm%ljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rq6b4DBBWVUgfw::tNMRKPOmlLjihffw?
ct`%qLKJZHGWihwfutPONNMKm%ljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rq6b4DBBWVUgfw::tNMRKPOmlLjihffw?
ct`%qLKJZHGWihwfutPONNMKm%ljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rq6b4DBBWVUgfw::tNMRKPOmlLjihffw?
ct`%qLKJZHGWihwfutPONNMKm%ljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rq6b4DBBWVUgfw::tNMRKPOmlLjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWihwfutPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUgfw::tNMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGWihwfutPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUgfw::tNMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGW8hTT4uPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUTwwu98NMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGW8hTT4uPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUTwwu98NMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGW8hTT4uPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUTwwu98NMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?KJZHGW8hTT4uPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!DBBWVUTwwu98NMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct``:?8nmHGWWDUBRRPONqLLnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!m2AWVUZSRWPONMR54m!ljjihffw?
ct``:?8nmHGWWDUBRRPONqLLnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!m2AWVUZSRWPONMR54m!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6HGWWDUBRRPON`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAWVUZSRWPONMR4nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6HGWWDUBRRPON`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAWVUZSRWPONMR4nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6HGWWDUBRRPON`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::8qZun4!2SRAm?OjLhgJIHGF!!CAW?UTYRWu8NrLKPnHGFKDCBfF?
DC%%:9!!6YGWWDUSAttrNMLKJ%lGFFggUBc??P`NM9Kw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAWVUZSRWPONMR4nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6HGWWDUBRRPON`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAWVUZSRWPONMR4nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6HGWWDUBRRPON`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAWVUZSRWPONMR4nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKnZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKnlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPO!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZl:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct`NMLKJZHGWWDUBRRPONNMKKIHjj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqGFDDBBWVUZSRWPONMRKPONMFjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
DC%%:?8!65:92Vw5uu2rqqL:nllGihg%BTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jiAPONjchgJI%cbaDYBWV?ZYw:P9NMq5J2HlFKDCHAF?
DCB%:98!Zl:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jWDUBRR?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??ZSRWPOr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffTc!?``u::rw6ut4!2jinm?Ojcu:`rqc5!`lAj??gfw::tr`64nn!ljjihffw?
ct``:?!!6l:jihwfut?rr`L:nlljj!hffAcbaa`ut:rZYuWml2SRhPfOjchgJI%FbaDYBWV?ZYw:99NSLKPn2GFKDCBAF?
DC%A:98!65492Vw5utP
```

Output is quote 49:

```
"It's alive! It's alive!" - Henry Frankenstein
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41325/32522): `"#&'()*+,-./0137;<=>@[\]^_ deopQksvxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `$` `%` `:` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `456` `89`
- Uppercase: `ABCD` `FGHIJKLMNOP` `RSTUVW` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `fghij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

You can run it with the [reference Malbolge interpreter](http://www.lscheffer.com/malbolge_interp.html).

Comment: Could you make this answer 51? The current 51 is invalid.

Comment: This answer is amazing! I've never seen a useful Malbonge program before, let alone such a constrained one. Well done!

Comment: Done, but still no '$' in the code :).

Comment: Holy mother of God. How did you write this?

Comment: I really mean to ask how you came up with this? I mean it's obviously generated just like every malbolge program, but how did you work in the character restrictions?

Comment: When I get a chance, I'll get some details up. The one (and probably only) advantage of Malbolge is that the encoding of instructions depends on their address, so even with the restrictions, it's possible to use all of the opcodes as long as they're at the right addresses. The restrictions do throw a couple wrenches into the search, but luckily there weren't any addresses where all of the opcodes were forbidden.

Comment: I just now noticed that the code is formatted such that it spells' "It's alive" in two columns. Dang, this is awesome. This is worth a bounty, so I'll put one up.

Comment: Thanks for the rep! The details are coming, I promise. :)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. Pure genious.

Comment: Great choice of quote for the language.

Comment: @gone_native Details then? How did you do it?

Answer (score 38):

## 10. x86 Machine Code, uses no  `9`

When I realized that the remaining characters included the opcodes for 'Dec BX' and 'Push BX', I concluded that a x86 program was still possible.

[Link for the code and .com file](http://lags.leetcode.net/Quote.zip)

The code looks like a much longer version of this:

```
44444444444444444444444444444444448444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
44444444444444444444444444444448444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444484444444444444444444444444444444
44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444844444444444
44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
444444444844444444444444444444444444444448KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKSSSSSSSSaKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKSKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKSKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKSKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
```

The code, compressed with `bzip2` and base-64-encoded, is this:

```
QlpoOTFBWSZTWSPev2AAAC3//IQAAE8AxAVVAljshO2a1CIgAAQCIAACQAKABEgwALtaISjAEwAC
YEwAE/RCKepoDIDQDQhgAATBEqUyYJ6TTCYm0RiYAmjE9y2DggyCjSr7QBKBBfLXbplPpVr0UZ9F
fce4QKIQigD2luNYchgZJSn9wWwWTL+vYVhM0o2SZAgIgLAWoqgeIwgnxBokBQJABPmuigiPswCA
CIqGH0GnHfFahZ987YEg6UpWEhB7jmzKcAOjGZxPEKJIMikhAUX/F3JFOFCQI96/YA==
```

Output is quote 18:

```
"Made it, Ma! Top of the world!" - Arthur "Cody" Jarrett
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42214/32353):

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdDeEFfgGhHiIjJkLmMNoOpPqQRrsTuUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters:

- Numbers: `4` `8`
- Uppercase: `K` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `l` `n` `t` `w`

**It is self-modifying code that creates self-modifying code, here's how it works:**

The text is first encoded by entering runs of '4' terminated by '8', which map to instructions that are effectively NOPs for this program. Next, BX is decremented ('K') until it has the value of where the print code will end up at on the stack. This is pushed 8 times ('S'), and then Pop All, 'a', is executed to set up SI and DI for later. BX is then repeatedly decremented and pushed to enter the arbitrary values of the print program on the stack (the low byte), along with a garbage byte (the high byte). Next, a long sequence of decrements gets BX to the value 0xAAAD, which is the two 1-byte instructions 'Load Word' and 'Store Byte'. Each pair of these instructions will remove one garbage byte from the print code. These instructions are pushed 28 times (the size of the print program), and the rest of the file is filled up with more decrement instructions to act as NOPs. These NOPs will be executed until the region of memory used by the stack is hit, which has been overwritten with the condensing code. The condensing code is executed, removing the garbage bytes in the code on the stack (pointed to by SI and DI, which were set up earlier). Finally, when the condensing code is done, the printing program has been successfully stored in memory at the next instruction to execute.

**Assembly code to generate the machine code (FASM)**

```
org 100h

;"Made it, Ma! Top of the world!" - Arthur "Cody" Jarrett

repeat '"'
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'M'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'a'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'd'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'e'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat ' '-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'i'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 't'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat ','-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat ' '-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'M'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'a'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat '!'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat ' '-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'T'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'o'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'p'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat ' '-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'o'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'f'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat ' '-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 't'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'h'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'e'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat ' '-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'w'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'o'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'r'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'l'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'd'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat '!'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat '"'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat ' '-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat '-'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat ' '-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'A'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'r'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 't'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'h'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'u'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'r'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat ' '-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat '"'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'C'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'o'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'd'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'y'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat '"'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat ' '-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'J'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'a'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'r'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'r'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 'e'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 't'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
repeat 't'-1
db      '4'
end     repeat
db      '8'
string_end:

data_start:
repeat 28*2+2
dec    bx
end    repeat
repeat 8
push   bx
end    repeat
popa

repeat 0x10000-0xFF21-28*2-2
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xFF21-0xFECD
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xFECD-0xFE4C
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xFE4C-0xFDB4
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xFDB4-0xFCEB
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xFCEB-0xFC7C
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xFC7C-0xFC12
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xFC12-0xFBB7
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xFBB7-0xFAFE
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xFAFE-0xFA81
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xFA81-0xFA61
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xFA61-0xFA21
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xFA21-0xF8CD
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF8CD-0xF802
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF802-0xF7B4
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF7B4-0xF760
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF760-0xF6F9
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF6F9-0xF674
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF674-0xF634
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF634-0xF53C
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF53C-0xF480
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF480-0xF442
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF442-0xF346
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF346-0xF2D2
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF2D2-0xF231
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF231-0xF201
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF201-0xF200
dec bx
end repeat
push bx
repeat 0xF200-0xF1BE
dec bx
end repeat
push bx

; 28 bytes of code

; done storing print code

repeat 0xF1BE-0xAAAD
dec    bx
end repeat
repeat 28
push   bx
end    repeat


; done storing compact code, fill the remaining space with  'dec bx'
; to act as a nop until the modified code is hit
fill_pos:
repeat 0xffff-fill_pos -2
dec    bx
end repeat
```

Comment: My answer used 80386 instructions (`IMUL` of a certain type), so it may be called a different "language". I didn't even try to check whether x86 is still possible at this stage - apparently it is!

Comment: And now all odd numbers are gone :(

Comment: @anatolyg I'm really happy to hear that, I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 24):

## 61. 80386 machine code + DOS, uses no `7`

```
u`t^cGFntlFmFnmaZKuacanftafightainahFrF!aThi2ai2ath$aWaraRLKm!calaPrFWidFntaMFrkinaMufflF8
$k!2!5%B!%!BH%!!%BAPH4?4#P^jAZj#Y1T!1L#1T41T61T?1LA1LC1TE1TI1TJ1TL1TM1TU5
1LW1T^1La1Th1Lj1LuF1Ld1Tn1TO1TZ1TuF1TO1L%1TZ1T:F1TZF1L%5
FF1T%F1T%F1L%Fj$Y1L%1LY1LOkLqEQFF1T%k|q6^1|A1|C5!   ZBBBBA!O
```

Output is quote 64:

```
"Gentlemen, you can't fight in here! This is the War Room!" - President Merkin Muffley
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40755/25315) `"'&()*+-,./\03;<=>@X_[sovy pez]{}`

---

Making an executable file that uses only printable ASCII is not an easy task. Fortunately, not many characters were forbidden by previous answers, so I only needed a few patches here and there.

To run this program, copy it into a file with extension `.com`, and run it (linebreaks use the DOS format `0d 0a`; there is one `TAB` character in the code). It's too bad that modern 64-bit Windows systems don't support 16-bit code; one needs a 32-bit Windows system or [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) to run the code.

I used the DOS `debug.com` debugger to develop the code. To "assemble" the "source code", redirect it into the debugger. On DOSBox:

> debug < quote.asm

Source code:

```
a100
    jnz 162; jump over the output data, to have it at a convenient address 104
    jz  162; (continued)
    db 'cGFntlFmFnmaZKuacanftafightainahFrF!aThi2ai2ath$aWaraRLKm!calaPrFWidFntaMFrkinaMufflF8',d,a,'$'
    ;   "Gentlemen, you can't fight in here! This is the War Room!" - President Merkin Muffley
    ; Some weird numbers; see explanations below
    dw 216b, 2132
    ; Padding
    db 35
    and ax, 2142
    and ax, 4221
    dec ax
    and ax, 2121
    and ax, 4142
    push ax; push the value 100; we will need it later
    dec ax
    xor al, 3f
    xor al, 23
    push ax
    pop si; now si points to the output message
    push byte ptr 41
    pop dx
    push byte ptr 23
    pop cx
    ; Fix the forbidden characters in the output message
    xor [si+21],dx
    xor [si+23],cx
    xor [si+34],dx
    xor [si+36],dx
    xor [si+3f],dx
    xor [si+41],cx
    xor [si+43],cx
    xor [si+45],dx
    xor [si+49],dx
    xor [si+4a],dx
    xor [si+4c],dx
    xor [si+4d],dx
    xor [si+55],dx
    xor ax, a0d
    xor [si+57],cx
    xor [si+5e],dx
    xor [si+61],cx
    xor [si+68],dx
    xor [si+6a],cx
    xor [si+75],cx
    inc si
    xor [si+64],cx
    xor [si+6e],dx
    xor [si+4f],dx
    xor [si+5a],dx
    xor [si+75],dx
    inc si
    xor [si+4f],dx
    xor [si+25],cx
    xor [si+5a],dx
    xor [si+3a],dx
    inc si
    xor [si+5a],dx
    inc si
    xor [si+25],cx
    xor ax, a0d
    inc si
    inc si
    xor [si+25],dx
    inc si
    xor [si+25],dx
    inc si
    xor [si+25],cx
    inc si
    push byte ptr 24
    pop cx
    xor [si+25],cx
    xor [si+59],cx
    xor [si+4f],cx
    ; Done with the output message
    ; Now fix the code (program patches itself)
    imul cx, [si+71], 45; "calculate" the address of the code
    push cx
    inc si
    inc si
    xor [si+25],dx; message patching was not finished... now it is
    imul di, [si+71], 36; "calculate" the patch value 0x8c
    pop si
    xor [si+41], di; make code "0xcd 0x21" - DOS function call
    xor [si+43], di; make code "0xc3" - terminate the program
    xor ax, 921; select DOS function 9 (output a string)
    pop dx; set dx to point to the output message
    inc dx
    inc dx
    inc dx
    inc dx
    db 41, 21, 4f

rcx 11b
n quote.com
w
q
```

Some notes:

- The output message has all forbidden characters XOR-masked with one of 3 masks, `0x41`, `0x23` and `0x24`. I chose masks that were not forbidden.
- The code that does the output contains forbidden characters, or worse - non-ASCII bytes `0xcd` and `0xc3`. They are XOR-masked as well, so the code must modify itself.
- All memory accesses are performed with an offset: pointers never point to the stuff itself, but several bytes lower. The reason is, when using memory access without an offset, the instruction codes are non-ASCII.
- The character `k` is very important here: it encodes the `IMUL` multiplication instruction. I use it to acquire constant values: for example, the constant `0x216b`, when multiplied by `0x45`, gives the useful constant `0x01d7`, which is a pointer (with an offset, as described above) to the code that has to be patched. In a similar manner, the patching mask is `0x2132*0x36=0x8c` (don't mind the truncation there).
- As described above, obtaining constants is a major pain. To make it even worse, I assumed nothing about the initial values of registers. DOS typically sets them to 0, but one can never be sure... This led to a fun exercise in initializing a register to 0: `and ax, 2142; and ax, 4221`.
- I added 2 linebreaks for "readability" (fortunately, this is not code-golf!). They are specified as "xor ax, a0d" in code; there must be an even number of them, so the value of `ax` doesn't change.

---

Edit: not using the `_` character anymore (bad timing in post) - cannot use `pop di`, so using the `di` register much less now.

Comment: `@` is already banned in 78, choose another symbol please.

Comment: Props, sir, props.

Comment: "Making an executable file that uses only printable ASCII is not an easy task." You might find this article interesting: http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~sam/ccs243-mason.pdf

Answer (score 22):

## 85. HTML5 (uses no `{`)

```html
&#x22&#x57&#x68&#x6f&#x27&#115&#x20&#x6f&#x6e&#x20&#x66&#x69&#x72&#115&#x74&#x2e&#x22&#x20&#x2d&#x20&#x44&#x65&#x78&#x74&#x65&#x72
```

Output is quote 91.

```
"Who's on first." - Dexter
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40584/32353):  `py3\" ';(`

Comment: What on earth...

Answer (score 19):

## 12. [ShaFuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ShaFuck) 0.2 (uses no `D`)

The source code is exactly 4,784,128 bytes long, containing all allowed characters except `D`. It looks like:

```
atawSaa(a×1017)KKla8Kc(a×1017)atawSaa(a×1017)KKla8Kc(a×1017)…atawSaa(a×1017)4cwtrtr(a×1017)
```

here (a×1017) means the character "a" repeated 1017 times. The base64-encoded bzip2-compressed file (247 bytes) is:

```
QlpoOTFBWSZTWW9SDOgAgfoPgIRgAAgIACgFFIAAeEAB+52sQ2KYACaCT1VQ0AATUqgBoAUlSTEyemk+qV2BSuKhVc
hIq6AoeKqI5BEe6qI+gUpfOZshoMraraVbDZsFiti1YtEbRawVajWLbCW0mybWwthG0qrZDGrYqirG21o1BrYq2xtD
NNyCI9CoPYAiOuARHABEeqqI6FQfIjiqiOhUHdEYVKvFW2qvv6QtEYjJhpkkxEKo2qKjWjWo1jRGrFUUaNUVaNqNYq
xqNFYtqNtbVFWgzaNhW1WYtaapVPGEpxEdRHYER3iMARH+LuSKcKEg3qQZ0A==
```

The SHA1-sum of the original file should be 1250ecf73c61ef93a31c4f7dfaa0a7631ada50bf.

Output is quote 9:

```
"Fasten your seatbelts. It's going to be a bumpy night." - Margo Channing
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42113/32353):

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFfgGhHiIjJkLmMNoOpPqQRsTuUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters:

- Numbers: `4` `8` `9`
- Uppercase: `K` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `l` `n` `r` `t` `w`

---

ShaFuck is a variant of Brainfuck. It takes every 1024-byte chunk, compute the SHA-1 digest, then use the 20-byte output as a Brainfuck program. As explained in the [blog post](http://shinhoge.blogspot.kr/2012/12/shafuck-is-not-unbeatable.html) linked from the wiki, there is a "vulnerability" in v0.2 that the SHA-1 output of the form:

```
valid-bf-program[(garbage)]valid-bf-program
```

is accepted. This allows a straight-forward conversion from a brainfuck command to a 2048-byte chunk. The encoder uses `a`–`z` as the character set, which is not suitable for us. So we need to write a "miner" ourselves. Now, there are 13 valid character available. Assuming SHA-1 output is random, if we want to fix the first 3 bytes, it corresponds to 3 × log₁₃(256) ~ 6.5 input characters. Therefore we need to iterate all 7-character strings made from these 13 alphabets:

```python
import hashlib
import itertools

characters = b'aclnrtwDKS489'

starts = {b'+>[', b'->[', b'.>[', b'.<[', b'+<[', b'-<[', b'>[', b'<['}
ends = {b']<+', b']<-', b']<.', b']>.', b']>+', b']>-', b']>', b']<'}

for i, group in enumerate(itertools.product(characters, repeat=7)):
    seq = bytes(reversed(group)) + b'a'*(1024-7)
    sha = hashlib.sha1(seq).digest()

    for s in starts:
        if sha.startswith(s):
            starts.remove(s)
            print(seq, sha)
            break

    for e in ends:
        if sha.endswith(e):
            ends.remove(e)
            print(seq, sha)
            break

    if i % 1000000 == 0:
        print('***', i, seq[:7])
```

We could quickly then get these equivalents:

```
>[(garbage)  = atawSaaaaaaa…
(garbage)]<- = 9t9nctaaaaaa…
(garbage)]<+ = KKla8Kcaaaaa…
(garbage)]<. = 4cwtrtraaaaa…

- = >[(garbage)]<- = atawSaaaaaaa…9t9nctaaaaaa…
+ = >[(garbage)]<+ = atawSaaaaaaa…KKla8Kcaaaaa…
. = >[(garbage)]<. = atawSaaaaaaa…4cwtrtraaaaa…
```

So finally we have this straightforward encoder:

```python
def encode(quote):
    SUFFIX = 'a' * (1024 - 7)
    PREFIX = 'atawSaa' + SUFFIX
    MINUS = PREFIX + '9t9ncta' + SUFFIX
    PLUS = PREFIX + 'KKla8Kc' + SUFFIX
    DOT = PREFIX + '4cwtrtr' + SUFFIX
    value = 0
    for c in quote:
        char = ord(c)
        if char > value:
            yield PLUS * (char - value)
        elif char < value:
            yield MINUS * (value - char)
        yield DOT
        value = char

with open('1.txt', 'w') as f:
    for seg in encode('''"Fasten your seatbelts. It's going to be a bumpy night." - Margo Channing'''):
        f.write(seg)
```

Comment: `SUFFIX = 'a' * (1024 - 7)` - just in case `1024 - 7` isn't always `1017`? :-)

Comment: @Joe: Yes it is.

Comment: Darn, there goes my answer #2.

Comment: @gone_native I had this too. But I still have another answer #2...

Comment: @Joe, `(1024 - 7)` is more readable.

Answer (score 18):

## 87. Ook!, uses no `;`

```
Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.
```

Output is quote 84:

```
"Oh, no, it wasn't the airplanes. It was Beauty killed the Beast." - Carl Denham
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40582/32045) `py3\" '`

Comment: Did you write that all yourself?

Comment: I have written a Java program that converts a String to an Ook! program that outputs the String. But it does not use loops, just incrementing and decrementing.

Comment: @feuerball so... that's a *really* inefficient Ook! program you've generated there. (in terms of space)

Comment: I know, but at least it does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: That is a perfect match of language and quote. I take it you've read *Moving Pictures*?

Answer (score 18):

## 76. [oOo CODE](http://esolangs.org/wiki/OOo_CODE), uses no `-`

```
WhaT_the_FuCk_iS_thE_coDe_i_Am_rEadIng_herE?
iT_AcTuaLlY_WorkS_liKe_oTHer_VaLid_CodE_in_The_ProGraMming_lAnGuaGe_CAlleD_oOO_CoDe
I_oNlY_wrOte_The_codE_hEre_To_MAke_iT_LoOk_bEttEr
tHe_cOde_CouLd_bE_wrIttEn_iN_loTS_oF_tHE_lETtER_o
BUt_I_DeCIdED_tO_MaKE_ReAdinG_iT_a_niceR_eXPeRIeNCe
NOw_I_am_RuNNing_Out_OF_cOdiNg_tIme_aNd_Fun_thiNgS_To_WRiTE
tHerEfORe_i_dECiDed_To_dO_thE_reSt_oF_thE_thIng_WitH_juSt_tHe_lETtEr_o
So_eNjoY
OoOooOoooOoOooOooOoooooOoOooOoOOoooOooOOooOoOooOoooooOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOooOoOOoooOOoOooOOoOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOOoOoooOoOooOooOoooooOoOooOoOOoooOooOOooOoOoooooOoOOoOOoOooOoOOoooOoOOoOOOoOooOOoOoOoOoOooOooOoooooOoOooOoOOoooOoOOoOOoOOOoOoooOoOooOooOooOoooooOoOooOoOOoooOoOOoOOOoOoOoOoOoooooOoOOoOOoOooOoOOoooOoOOOoOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOOoOOoOoOOoOOoOOOoOoOOOoOoooOoOoOOoOoooOooOooOooooOoOOoooOoOOOoOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOOoOoOOoOOoOOoOoOoOoooooOoOOoOooOoOOoooOOoOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOOoOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOOooOoOoooooOoOOoOOoOOoOooOoOOoooOooOooOOoOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOOoOooOooOOoOooOoooOoOooOoooooOoOOoOOoOooOoOOoooOOooOoOooOooOoooooOoOOoOooOoOOoooOoOOoOOOoOoOOoOoOoOoooooOoOOoOooOoOOoooOOoOooOoooOoOooOoooooOoOOoOOoOooOoOOoooOooOooOOoOoOoOoOooOooOoooooOoOooOoOOoooOOoOoOoOoOoooooOoOOoOOoOooOoOOoooOOoOooOoooOoOooOooOoooooOoOooOoOOoooOooOOoOoOoOoOoooooOoOOoOooOoOOoooOOoOoooOoOooOooOoooooOoOooOoOOoooOoOOoOOoOOoOOOoOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOOoOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOOoOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOOoOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOOo
```

Output is quote 78:

```
"Open the pod bay doors, HAL." - Dave Bowman
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40608/30164): `py3\" ';({s[)<+.@=`

I won't post another BF equivalent/derivative. Promise.

**EDIT:** I updated the code to be more readable. (lol) Doesn't affect any forbidden characters.

I used [this tool](http://copy.sh/brainfuck/text.html) to generate my pure BF. I then converted it to oOo CODE:

```js
'<lots of bf code>'.replace(/>/g,'ooo').replace(/</g,'ooO').replace(/\[/g,'oOo').replace(/\]/g,'oOO').replace(/-/g,'Ooo').replace(/\+/g,'OoO').replace(/\./g,'OOo')
```

And then used this Python script to get the "readable" version from pure oOo CODE and an input text:

```python
ooocode = '<lots of oOo CODE>'
alphabet = [chr(x) for x in range(ord('A'), ord('Z') + 1)] + [chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)]
if len(ooocode) % 3: print("INVALID CODE")
inp = input()
index = 0
while inp != '':
    for char in list(inp):
        if char in alphabet:
            case = ooocode[index]
            if case.upper() == case:
                print(char.upper(), end='')
            else:
                if char.lower() in 'py3\\" \';({s[)<+.@=':
                    print("INVALID INPUT")
                else:
                    print(char.lower(), end='')
            index += 1
        elif char in 'py3\\" \';({s[)<+.@=':
            print("INVALID INPUT")
        else: print(char, end='')
    print("")
    inp = input()
print(ooocode[index:])
```

Comment: And for some reason, I always read it in a ghost voice.

Answer (score 18):

## 9. [Addleq](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Addleq) (uses no `t`)

Uses `sqasm.cpp` in the esolang page to assemble. Requires non-Windows 64-bit platform to work correctly.

There are exactly 64 tabs and 64 new lines (no trailing new lines). Whew.

```
8   448
448
88  448
448
88  444
444
448 444
444 844
448 844
844 848
88  848
8   848
84  884
884
8   884
8   4844
4844
884 4844
88  488
488
8   488
488
444 488
488 4444
4444
8   4444
4444    888
88  888
44  4488
448 88888888888888888888
844 4488
4444    4484
8   4484
88  4448
4484    4448
844 88888888888888888888
4488    88888888888888888888
4484    88888888888888888888
888 88888888888888888888
488 88888888888888888888
444 88888888888888888888
848 88888888888888888888
884 88888888888888888888
4448    88888888888888888888
4444    88888888888888888888
4844    88888888888888888888
444 88888888888888888888
844 88888888888888888888
4488    88888888888888888888
4484    88888888888888888888
888 88888888888888888888
488 88888888888888888888
448 88888888888888888888
444 88888888888888888888
44  88888888888888888888
444 88888888888888888888
848 88888888888888888888
884 88888888888888888888
4448    88888888888888888888
4444    88888888888888888888
4844    88888888888888888888
444 88888888888888888888
844 88888888888888888888
4488    88888888888888888888
4484    88888888888888888888    4   888 88888888888888888888    4   8888    8888    88888888888888888888
```

Output is quote 22:

```
"Bond. James Bond." - James Bond
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42250/32353):

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./01235679:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdDeEFfgGhHiIjJkLmMNoOpPqQRrsTuUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining:

- Numbers: `4` `8`
- Uppercase: `K` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `l` `n` `w`

---

"Addleq" an OISC is similar to "Subleq", but uses addition instead of subtraction.

### Constructing "-1"

Output in Addleq works by writing to memory address -1. Since all odd numbers are forbidden we cannot construct a -1 by normal means. However, we can trick the assembler into creating a -1:

```cpp
int str2int(const string &s)
{
        int ret=0;
        sscanf(s.c_str(),"%d",&ret);
        return ret;
}
```

Here `sscanf(s, "%d", &ret)` behaves like `ret = strtol(s, NULL, 10);` (C11 §7.21.6.2/12), and when the input overflows, `strtol` will return LONG_MAX (C11 §7.22.1.4/8). Thus, if `sizeof(long) > sizeof(int)`, we should get `ret == -1`. However, on platform which `sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)` e.g. 32-bit platforms or Windows, we would get 0x7fffffff making the solution above invalid.

### Saving tabs with the assembler

In low-level addleq, each instruction is 3-number long. As we only have 128 whitespaces budget, we have to print the whole string with 129/3 = 43 instructions. This is completely insufficient as the shortest quote (chosen here) is 32-character long.

Nevertheless, the assembler supports some shorthand notation:

1. If a line contains only 2 numbers, it will automatically provide the 3rd number as the address of the next instruction
2. If a line contains only 1 number, that number is copied and a 3rd number is provided using rule #1.

Rule #2 was designed for "subleq" to quickly zero an address. But for "addleq" it allows us to *double* a value without any tabs.

These allow us to barely fit the whole program into 129 numbers.

## Creating numbers

The quote is chosen because it is short and has a lot of duplicated characters. The numbers we need to create are:

```
32  space
34  "
45  -
46  .
66  B
74  J
97  a
100 d
101 e
109 m
110 n
111 o
115 s
```

We could use numbers at address 4, 8, 44, 48, 84, 88, .... Rule #1 of the assembler already placed "9" at *8 and "45" at *44, so we will just use them (it is good they are odd numbers). Furthermore, we will try to fit "-1", "8" and "44" into these addresses by moving the calculations around. The result is the first half of the code:

```python
# *448 = 34 = (9×2 - 1)×2 = (*8×2 + *88)×2
8   448
448
88  448     # Here we get *8 == 9.
448

# *444 = 32 = -2 + 34 = (*88×2) + *448
88  444
444
448 444

# *844 = 66 = 32 + 34 = *444 + *448
444 844
448 844

# *848 = 74 = 66 + 9 - 1 = *844 + *8 + *88
844 848
88  848
8   848

# *884 = 97 = 44×2 + 9 = *884×2 + *8
84  884
884
8   884     # Here we get *44 == 45.

# *4844 = 115 = 9×2 + 97 = *8×2 + *884
8   4844
4844
884 4844

# *488 = 46 = (-2 + 9)×2 + 32 = (*88×2 + *8)×2 + *444
88  488
488
8   488
488
444 488

# *4444 = 101 = 46×2 + 9 = *488×2 + *8
488 4444
4444
8   4444

# *888 = 100 = 101 - 1 = *4444 + *88
4444    888
88  888

# *4488 = 111 = 45 + 66 = *44 + *844
# The line in the middle prints '"', and also set *88 == -1
44  4488    # Here we get *84 == *44
448 88888888888888888888    # Here we get *88 == -1
844 4488

# *4484 = 110 = 101 + 9 = *4444 + *8
4444    4484
8   4484

# *4448 = 109 = 110 - 1 = *4484 + *88
88  4448
4484    4448
```

### The last line

After all numbers are constructed we can print each character. The final program, however, has more than 67 lines, two too many. Therefore, we must combine the last 3 lines together:

```python
# From:
4484    88888888888888888888
888 88888888888888888888
8888    8888    88888888888888888888

# To:
4484    88888888888888888888    4   888 88888888888888888888    4   8888    8888    88888888888888888888
```

Since the line has more than 2 numbers, we have to manually supply the 3rd parameter of the instructions. That means we trade each newline for 2 tabs. Fortunately before the combination we used 60 tabs, so the final result barely passed the requirements.

Comment: What an impressive list of coincidences! Looks almost like it all was a part of your cunning plan.

Comment: @anatolyg: This is actually the third version of the code :), the equations are rewritten several times to minimize the number of lines. The older versions have ~3 lines too much.

Comment: It would be even nicer if instead of `4` and `8` there were `0` and `7`.

Comment: @Vi. Or at least 8 and 9... There seemed to be some number-based language still works, though.

Answer (score 17):

## 89. PHP, uses no

```php
$j=chr(46);$k=chr(0x20);$l=chr(0x22);$z=chr(112);$q=<<<H
${l}I${k}feel${k}the${k}need${k}-${k}the${k}need${k}for${k}s${z}eed!$l$k-${k}Lt.${k}Pete$k${l}Maverick$l${k}Mitchell${k}and${k}Lt.${k}Nick$k${l}Goose$l${k}Bradshaw
H;
echo$q;
```

Output is quote 94:

```
"I feel the need - the need for speed!" - Lt. Pete "Maverick" Mitchell and Lt. Nick "Goose" Bradshaw
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40570/29611): `py3\"`

Comment: You damn evil man.

Comment: Someone block `'` now!!!

Comment: @Optimizer done

Answer (score 16):

## 81. [PI](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Pi), uses no `<`

```
9.1415926525897922284626422822795028841971692992751058209749445927078164062862089986280048252421170679821480865102822066470928446095505822017252594081284811174502841027019285211055596446229489549200819644288109756659224461284756482227867801652712019091456485669224602486104542266482122906072602491412727245870066062155881748815209209628292540917152642678925902600112005205488204665212841469519415116094220572702657595919520921861172819026117921051185480744622799627495672518857527248912279281820119491298226720624406566420860212949462952247271907021798609427027705292171762921767522846748184676694051220005681271452605608277857712427577896091726271787214684409012249524201465495852710507922796892589225420199561121290219608640244181598126297747712099605187072110499999982729780499510597217228160962185950244594552469082026425222082522446850252619211881710100001278287528865875222082814206171776691472025982524904287554687211595628628822527875907519577818577805221712268066120019278766111959092164201989280952572010654858622788659261522818279682202019520252018529689957726225994128912497217752804791215155748572424541506959508295221168617278558890750982817546274649292192550604009277016711290098488240128582616025627076601047101819429555961989467678274494482552797747268471040475246462080466842590694912902126770289891521047521620569660240580281501925112522824200255876402474964722629141992726042699227967822547816260092417216412199245862150202861829745557067498085054945885869269956909272107975092029552211652449872027559602264806654991198818247977525662698074265425278625518184175746728909777727928000816470600161452491921722172147722501414419725685481612611572525521224757418494684285211219071941411145477624168625189815694855620992192221842725502542568876717904946016514668049886272127917860857841818279679766814541009518817861609506800642251252051171929848960841284886269456042419652850222106611864067442786220891949450471207107869609560640719172874677646575729624128908658526459958144904780275900994657640789512694681981525957098258226205224894077267194782684826014769909026401161944074550050682004962524517490996514014298091906592509072216964615157098580874105978859597729754989001617509284681582686818689427741559918559252459519594110499725246808459872716446958486518167162226260991246080512418841904512441065497627807977156914059977001296160894416948685558484060504220722258284886481584560285060168427094522674676788952521085225499546667278209864565961160548862005774564980055906045681740241125150760694794510965960940252288797108941456691468672287489405601015045086179286809208747609178249285890097149096759852612655497818921297848216829989487226588048575640142704775551121796414515217462141645428584447952658678210511411547157195211114271661021159695162114429524849071871101457654005902799044007420070105785090621980874478084784896800214457108687519405064002184501910484810050706146806749192781911979499520614196644287544406447451247181921799985910159195618146751426912297489409071864942219615679452080951465502252216028819101420917621178559566189177870810190697920771467221825625996615014215010680184477145492026054146659252014974428507125186660021124140881907104860017046496514509057962685610055081066587969981605747060840525714591028970641401109712062804090097595156771577004200078699060072005587601764594218741251471205429281918261861258674215791984148488291644706095752706957220917567116722910981690915280175506712748582222871825209252965725121081579151169882091444210067510114671101141267111169908658516198115019701651511685171417657618151556508849099898599821871455281116055076479185058902261854896021029000898570642046752590709154814165498594616071802709819940099244889575712828905920200260972997120844005742654895822911912597461667105816041428118810120182490175898524174417029112765618091771444010707469211201910020000080197621101100449290215160842444859607669848952286847841245526582141449576857262452441892029686426242410771226978028071189154411010446821252716201052652272111660196665571092547110557851760466820650109896526918620564769012570586056620185581007295606598764861179104511488501461116576867502494416680096265797877185560845529654126654085006140444018586769751456614068007002078776591044017127494704205622005089945610140711270004078547002699090814546646458807972708266840654228587856981052158089110657574067954571617752542021149557615814002501262285941102164715509792592109907965471761255176567511575178296664547791745011299614890104619947112962107140407518957059614589019089710111790429782856475002001986915140287080859904801094121472210179476477726224142548545400021571850061422881075850400600217518297986622471721591607716692547487589866549494501146540628421661917900197692656721461851067160965712091807618127166416274888800786925602902284721040117211860820419000422966171196177921117575114959501566049611862947265470642520081770067515906705020507280540567040086740510622224771589150495009844489000096040878076922599297805419541447477441842641298608099888687411260472156951621965864571021611598191195167151812974167729478672422924654166800980676928218280689964004824154017014161149658979409241217896907069779422062508221688957080798620001590776471651228905786015881617557829705200446042815126272007040146501977774160419906655418765979292144195215411418994854447145671811624991419111814809277771018618771411772075456545122077709212019051660962804909261601975988281610020166606528619026686006062705676000544776280050450777205547105859548702790814056240145171806246446267945612754181440785202262542127819449751824172058151114771199260618111467768796959701098119110771098704085910074641442822772604659470474587847787201927715280701767907707157210444700605700700492406901108050490160128404251219256517980694114528015147012047816417885185290928545201165819141965621149141415956258658655705526904965209858011850722426482919728584781161057777560688876446248246857926019515277148010480290058760758251047470916409610626760449256274204208020856611906254540072101505958450687724602901618766795240616042522577195429162991900645507799140070404028752628889609958794757291746426057455254079091451457111469410911949525191076020825202618798521887705842972591677812149699009019211697172727847684726860849001177024242916511005005168121164150189517029891922114517220118128069650117844087451960121228599171621110171144484640900890644954440061986907548516026027505298049187407866808818008510228004508504860825009002100219715518400605455007668282949004127765527929751754612955984684494618104746119966518581518420568511862186725211402810871121282789212507712629461229561989898915821167456270102181564622010496715188190970008119800497040720961006854066441949509790190699659552452005450580685501956720229219119119185680144901982059551002261505061920419947455085908102242955449597785779024742161727111724641415419478221818528624085140066604410258885698670540154706965747458550002521142107101545940516551790686627000799585115625784022988270720198987571415957811196458440059408750681216028764962867446047746491599505497274256269010490277819868259181465741268049256487985561451721478671101904688080406046555794986419270561872911748721120807601120029911067908627089408799062016295154100714248928007220126901475466847654576164774794675200490757155527819655621222926406160116158155907422020201187277605277219005561484255518792510141511984425122141576200610642506090497500865627109505919465897514101004822769006247405060256916078154781811528406679570611086150215044521274759245449454246828860611408414861776700961207151249140410272518607648216141411462151897576645216411767969011495019108575984421919862916421909949072062046468441170940026591840440780510008945257420995082965912285085558215725001071257012668002402929525220118726767562204154205161841604847565169998116141010029960780869092916040288400269104140792886215078424516709087000699282120660418471806555567252522567522861291042487761825829765157959847015622262914860014158722980514989650226291748788202714209222245119856264766914905562842501912757710284027998066165825488926488025456610172967026640765590429099456815065265105171829412701169110785178609040708667114965580404047690085781711086455870678120014587687126600489109095620099090610010291616152881484479099042517472261948045759114911405297614757481191567091101177517210080115590248510906692017671922011229094114676851422144771790907517004406619910400075111705471918550464490260655128162288244625759160000091072250807421821408805086572917715096828874782656995995744906617585441475221970968140800515598491754171818819994469748676265516582765848158845114277568790029095170281529716144562129640415211176006651012412006597558512761785818292041974844216080071910457618912049229279650198751872127267507981255470958904556057921221000546697499215610254947802490114195212182815109114079070860251522742995818072471625916685451000120948049470791191502670400282441860414262629548000448002670496248201792896476697585184271414251702969214889627668440121260927524960157996469256504916818160900121809290459588970695065049406004021665440755890045602882250545255640564482465151875471196218440965825007540885690941100015095261790780029741207665147909425902989695946995565761218656196722786256256125216420862869222104274889218654164802296780705765615144612046927906821207188177814211562821608961208068222468012248261177185896181409181901671672220888121511755600072798094004152970028780076670944474560104556417254070906979096122571429894671540578468788614445812014590571984922528471605049221242470141214780570455105008019086996000027604787081081754501192071412254908661918119529425786905076411006181519814189141596111854147546495569781018290097164651408407007070604112070599840452251610507027056205266012764848008407611800100527902054274628654006026745228651057065874882256981579267897669742205750596854408697450201410206724585020072452256426511410559240190274216248419140159989515194590944070469120914091870012645600162174288021092764579110657922955249887275846101264816999892256959688159205600101655256175678566722796619885782794848855814197518744545512965604404800966420557982906804052202770984294202500022576041807009476994159791594500069752148290066555661567874640054666564165474217045902521229542529169414599041608751201868179170214888689479151071617852902145292440771659495610510074210871426114974595615118498711757047101787957110422969066670214498617464595280824569445789772
```

Output is quote 81:

```
"Hello, gorgeous." - Fanny Brice
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40593/16120) `py3\" ';({s[)`

What ? Pi without `3` ?
My interpreter here (sorry about the rudimentary UI, based on this [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28734/16120)) : http://migl.io/projects/pi/index.php

Answer (score 16):

## 79. Perl 5, uses no `.`

```perl
$PRINT=lc
q|PRINT|and$Q=chr
0x22
and$C=q|C|and$ARPE=lc
q|ARPE|and$W=chr
0x20
and$DIEM=q|diem|and$T=chr
46
and$SEIZE=q|Seize|and$THE=q|the|and$DAY=lc
q|DAY|and$BOYS=lc
q|BOYS|and$MAKE=q|Make|and$YOUR=lc
q|YOUR|and$LIVES=lc
q|LIVES|and$EXTRA=lc
q|EXTRAORDINARY|and$JOHN=q|John|and$KEAT=q|Keating|and
eval
qq|$PRINT
q^$Q$C$ARPE$W$DIEM$T$W$SEIZE$W$THE$W$DAP,$W$BOYS$T$W$MAKE$W$YOUR$W$LIVES$W$EXTRA$T$Q$W-$W$JOHN$W$KEAT^|
```

Output is quote 95:

```
"Carpe diem. Seize the day, boys. Make your lives extraordinary." - John Keating
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40597/32353) `py3\" ';({s[)<+`

---

As a TMTOWTDI language, Perl offers lots of way to get around the restrictions. The method used here is to construct the statement `print "that quote"` as a string, and evaluate it.

Although `'` and `"` are banned, Perl additionally allows expressing strings using `q«…»` and `qq«…»` respectively. And although `;` is forbidden, as all statements are not falsy, we could use `and` to chain together statements. Since the uppercase letters `P`, `Y`, `S` are still allowed, we could put `p`, `y`, `s` into the final string using the `lc` (lowercase) function, while `chr` can be used to put the symbols `"` and  .

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the rules but this uses both P and Y as well as S

Comment: @G_Wilson: Uppercase and lowercase are different.

Comment: Sorry, My bad. I forgot that they have different ASCII Values.

Comment: "all statements are not falsy": you mean all *these* statements are not falsy, right? (`$foo=0` is falsy, of course.) Anyway, very nice; +1.

Comment: @msh210 Yeah, all *these* statements are not falsy.

Answer (score 16):

## 54. [CaneCode](http://esolangs.org/wiki/CaneCode) (uses no `Q`)

(New lines and spaces are not necessary.)

```
                                 111111111111
                            1111111111111111111111
                         8111111111111111111111111111
                      111111111111111111111111118111111
                    1111811111111811111111111822222222222
                   222222222222222222222222222222222222222
                 222222222222222222222222222222222281111111
               111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
              11111111111111822222222222222222222222222222222
             2222222222222222222222222222222281111111111111111
            111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
           11111111118222281111181111111828222222222222222822222
          2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222822
         222222222281111111111                 1111111111111111111
        1111111111111111111                      11111111111111111
       111111111111111111                          1111822222222222
      222222222228111111                            118111111111118
      2222222222222222                               222222222222222
     2222222222222222                                 22222222222222
    2222222222222222                                   22222228111111
    111111111111111                                    11111111111111
   111111111111111                                      1111111111111
   11822222222222                                        2222222222222
   2222222222222                                         2222222222222
  22222222222222                                         2811111111111
  1111111111111                                           111111111111
 1111111111111                                            1111111111111
 1111111111111                                             118222281111
 181111111828                                              222222222222
 222822222222                                              222222222222
 222222222222                                              222222222222
2222222222282                                              2222222222222
8111111111111                                              1111111111111
1111111111111                                              1111111111111
1111118111111                                              1111111111111
1118111111822                                               222222222222
2222222222222                                               222222222222
2222222222222                                               222222222222
2222222222222                                               222222228111
1111111111111                                              1111111111111
1111111111111                                              1111111111111
1111111111811                                              1111118111118
2222222222222                                              2222222222222
 222222222222                     2222                     2222222222222
 2222222222222                  22281111                   111111111111
 1111111111111                 1111111111                 1111111111111
 11111111111111                11111111111                8222222222222
  2222222222222               2222222222222              22222222222222
  22222222222222              22222222222222            22228111111111
   1111111111111              111111111111111           11111111111111
   11111111111111             1111111822282222         81111111111111
    11118222222222             2222282222222222      2222222222222222
    222222222222222            22222222222222222    2222222222811111
     111111111111111            11111111111111111  1111111111111111
     1111111111111111           11111111181811111822222222222281811
      11182222222222222          222222222222222222222222222222222
       22222222222222222          2222222282222222811111111111111
       1111111111111111111         11111111111111111111111111111
        1111111111111111111111111118222222222222222222228111111
         11111111182222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
          222222222222222222222222222222222222222281822811111
           1111111182222222222222811111111111111111111111111
            111111111111111181111111111111111111111181111111
             111822822228222222222222222222222222222222222222
               22222222222222222222222222222222281111111111111
                11111111111111111111111111111111111118111111111
                  1111118181111111811111818111111118222222222222
                   2281111111111181111118222222222222222222222222
                      22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
                        222222281111111111111    1111111111111181111
                            111111111111          1111111811811111111
                                                    822222222222222222
                                                     222222222222222222
                                                      222222222222222222
                                                       222222222222222222
                                                        222281111111111111
                                                         111111111111111111
                                                           1111111111111111
                                                            111811111111111
                                                             11111111111111
                                                               11118222222
                                                                2222222811
                                                                 11111811
                                                                   1118
```

Output is quote 71:

```
"Wait a minute, wait a minute. You ain't heard nothin' yet!" - Jakie Rabinowitz/Jack Robin
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40900/32353): `"#&'()*+,-./037;<=>@[\]^_ deopsvxXyz{|}~`

---

CaneCode is a just another BF derivative, with the mapping:

- 1 → +
- 2 → -
- 3 → <
- 4 → >
- 5 → [
- 6 → ]
- 7 → ,
- 8 → .

---

Just a note: The remaining characters are:

- Symbols: `!` `$` `%` `:` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `12` `456` `89`
- Uppercase: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP` `RSTUVW` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `fghijklmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

Comment: I'm quite sure I see a Q in there

Answer (score 14):

## 6. [Subskin](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Subskin) (uses no `K`)

Line 9 in the following program is replaced with something testable. It has 2 trailing newlines, and exactly 64 newlines in total.

```
a
a
cc

88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888c
cc
cc
cc
8c6ec6862e611a909aefef7133fc410dff7e22f63f7493b2f8e452888467b057b57bea88a311cadb514028e5cdc7397ab03a55e312d5a0a7d93b880f26cfd6c679f780c1f1ce3691cc9d92c228b0159a5f0f0c6a1a7dddec2791621b1782567e16273ff2019feb3d44320fec1073a536acc0b06462
cc
4
a
a8

a
ac
ac
a
aa
aa
a
aa
ac
aa
ac
aa
aa
c8
8
a8
cc
c8
aa
ca
a8
8
a8
4
ca
4
c8
cc
cc
ac
aa

a
c8
4
c
aa
c
8
a8
c4
a8
c8
8
c4
c8
a8
ac
aa
```

To make it satisfy the criteria, line 9 should be replaced with the following big number. I think this should be valid just like those Unary variants.

- It has 654735956090596524969487305034951423963889232095233272969286710339641355902659268643472907068639271108820740393436106590773296263764644599368304778650025965599516462256150998007466867979237499446604136790740902258939239161694474806322070709923126730285884312696992964524737041784270695028341148581679653336449286721542786198445367766535356729715169565865920807607678630613900722713788172744051264360952312631564221349669353392544934890489839735971199450478008441573743823732948121884000213925749437653114738930413235370596262201712167849715302400000000000000234 digits.
- Every digit that has 4109527714173620014271192135615819980149748934951677499623857818618801276212206327654950831404071330954232878836395346962954202538476535987403920483325378835064959624187891476909072253512354662379230835497647226755470473642747146485760293230336401802073590883942400000000000000000 * k digits to its right is an `a`. So the last digit is an `a` where k = 0, and there are 159321460184447640588063043795531819638245990121854536131792918542864566418397339281153516086677425424423723475531974684547855358001230183547851703274577276601612622258171727288003902331619018508731805969660163575803761844794365403871421372122820829226554024584224464882571689865777 of them.
- Every digit that is not on those positions is an `8`.

Note that the constructed number is in base 16 (but numbers in the above description is in base 10). If my calculation is correct, it should be the same as the original number in the program mod 8*(16^234-1)/15. Any number large enough and satisfy this criterion should work, but I don't know how to construct a shorter one with only `4` `8` `a` `c`.

Output is quote 1:

```
"Frankly, my dear, I don't give a damn." - Rhett Butler
```

with a leading and a trailing newline.

Previously forbidden:

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./01235679:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJklLmMnNoOpPqQrRstTuUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters: `4` `8` `S` `a` `c` `w`.

#### Explanation

Subskin is an OISC where the instruction is to subtract, and skip the next instruction if the result is negative. The first 3 fields in the memory is mapped to the instruction pointer, output, and input. The instruction pointer can be used as "goto", and reading it can yield some numbers that aren't otherwise available using the only usable characters.

At first I tried to compress the code into the digits in some base. But I couldn't golf it into 64 lines. So I switched to the modulus approach which removed a level of loop.

It is basically just the greatest common divisor algorithm. A/B is extracted at each step. Then set A = B and B = A mod B and continue.

More accurately, when A>B it increments the current data, otherwise it swaps the numbers and moves the pointer. After that the smaller number is subtracted from the greater number.

Finally the self-extraction code overrides something in the loop and breaks it, and it continues to the extracted code. The extracted code is quite straight-forward.

#### Code

```
a       Start execution at 10.
a       The first byte of output cannot be suppressed without the minus character.
        But fortunately it can still output a leading newline,
        and this is allowed in the question.
cc      Input, not used.
0       Only used in the extracted code.
A  (*4) Data number A + 4, or the accumulator at run-time.
cc
cc
cc
B  (*8) Data number B.
cc
4  (*a) Start execution here. It moves A to *a8 at the first time,
        and the accumulator - 4 to the current position at later times.
a       Minus 4, which is the smallest addressable number defined at the beginning.
a8 (*c) The pointer for self-extraction. Initially it point to the position of A
        at run-time, and this instruction moves *4 there. Then it is decremented,
        and the memory before *a8 is used for storing the extracted code.
        Constant definitions:
0       *ac = current address - 4 = 9.
a
ac
ac      *aa = 5.
a
aa
aa      *aa = 1.
a
aa
ac      *ac = 8.
aa
ac
aa      *c8 = 0.
aa
c8
8       Check if B > A. True at the first time so the initializations could be done.
a8
cc
c8        If yes, *ca = -1 (just another constant), and skip the next instruction.
aa
ca
a8        If no (B <= A), A -= B.
8
a8
4       Increment the accumulator. It has no effects if B > A.
ca
4
c8      If B < A (before the A -= B if that is executed):
cc
cc
ac        Go back to the starting position.
aa
0
a       Reset the accumulator to 4 (which means 0 when writing to the target position).
c8
4
c       Decrement the pointer for extraction.
aa
c
8       Swap A and B and A -= B.
a8
c4
a8
c8
8
c4
c8
a8
ac      Go back to the starting position.
aa
0       Finally the extraction code overrides this field and change it to 4,
        making it a no-op, so the execution continues.
6e      Jump to the beginning of extracted code.
aa
0
(29 times 0, not used.)
a6(*60) The pointer for output. And this just output the character at the pointer.
3
1
60      Decrement the pointer for output.
aa
60
60      Check if there is still data to output.
6d
4
6e        If yes, continue the output loop.
aa
0
a9        If no, access the undefined address *a9 to end the program.
6f(*6d) The position of the end of output.
5e(*6e) The starting position of the output loop.
(The reversed data.)
X       The junk data at the beginning of the extraction.
A (*a8) Number A at run-time.
```

#### Generation

Assume A and B after the extraction progress to be n and m. It is easy to reverse this progress and get A and B (before the useful data begins) in terms of n and m. And A = an + bm, B = cn + dm. Set A to an arbitrary number that is large enough, and can make n and m both positive (and uses only the available characters). n and m can be calculated using modular inversion. Then B is determined by n and m.

But it isn't easy to make B also consist of only those characters. I used an extra step that should only extract some harmless junk data. So the new B would be kA + B where k is a positive integer. It's easy to see such a k exists. But I'm not sure whether it is possible to find one that is short enough to be testable. And I used Fermat's little theorem to find one that works in theory.

I have only one #2 language left.

Answer (score 13):

## 78. Mathematica, uses no `@`

```
2986092695862452869648821144242466624048554924749885449420879769410086580524-10000011000000001010001000000000000000000000000000000001//#/87790498804444451827485960720854800964024844465254951684711241427814652487~Subtract~100001101000000000000000000000000001010000001000000000000000001000000&//ContinuedFraction//FromCharacterCode
```

Output is quote 76:

```
"Hasta la vista, baby." - The Terminator
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40604/4558) `py3\" ';({s[)<+.`

Generated like so:

```
str = "\"Hasta la vista, baby.\" - The Terminator";
chrs = ToCharacterCode @ str;
fraction = FromContinuedFraction @ chrs;
n = Numerator @ fraction;
d = Denominator @ fraction;
ndiff = Boole[# == 3]& /@ IntegerDigits @ n // FromDigits;
ddiff = Boole[# == 3]& /@ IntegerDigits @ d // FromDigits;
n2 = n + ndiff;
d2 = d + ddiff;
```

The program is then:

```
n2 - ndiff // # / d2 ~ Subtract ~ ddiff & // ContinuedFraction // FromCharacterCode
```

with values inserted for `n2`, `ndiff`, `d2` and `ddiff` and all spaces removed.

---

My original idea was to use `ToString`, `FromDigits`, `IntegerDigits`, `Partition` and `FromCharacterCode`. However both `FromDigits` and `IntegerDigits` has an `s` in them which I hadn't noticed.

Comment: Damn, was working on a Befunge one.

Answer (score 12):

## 72. x86_64 assembly (nasm), uses no `*`

```
BITS    64
extern  _exit
global  main

q:  dd  21111642486/11
    dd  7621846918/14
    dd  44456111856/24
    dd  572619118
    dd  21141585696/17
    dd  5982995755/11
    dd  49922657928/26
    dd  27216242192/16
    dd  11&~1

main:
    dd  89851824/6
    db  255
    db  255
    db  255
    db  72
    db  184
    dq  q
    db  72
    db  274/2
    db  198
    dd  2416/2
    db  2
    dd  87241517818/26
    dd  17268/2
    db  2/4
    db  15
    db  5

    db  49
    db  255
    call    _exit
```

Uses 61 tabs and 36 newlines.

Output is quote 68:

```
"Here's Johnny!" - Jack Torrance
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40614/4558) `py3\" ';({s[)<+.@=-,X0`

This uses a `write` system call with the number `0x2000001`, which probably only works on OS X.
Assembling, linking and running:

```
nasm -f macho64 codegolf.asm
ld -e main codegolf.o -lc
./a.out
```

Comment: Best. Quote. Ever. Kudos!

Answer (score 12):

## 71. GolfScript, uses no `/`

```
:?546]84]616]869]121]295]114]1125]288]872]2149]882]2661]289]1826]544]45]1568]67]97]2162]111]876]1824]65]622]878]2917]2592]582]2418]4197]4965]1644]617]1646]615]?^
```

Output is quote 69:

```
"They're here!" - Carol Anne Freeling
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40622/8478) `py3\" ';({s[)<+.@=-,X0*`

Thanks to Peter Taylor letting me in on some GolfScript quirks for constructing the string. First, I can get an empty string without using quotes, by assigning the (empty) STDIN contents to a variable (`?` in this case). Then I'm constructing a nested array of numbers which, taken mod 256, are the desired code points. By adding multiples of 256 I can avoid duplicates and numbers containing `0` and `3`. Lastly I push the empty string with `?` and take the symmetric set difference. This flattens the array and coerces it into a string, where GolfScript only cares about the remainder mod 256.

[Test it here.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Oj81NDZdODRdNjE2XTg2OV0xMjFdMjk1XTExNF0xMTI1XTI4OF04NzJdMjE0OV04ODJdMjY2MV0yODldMTgyNl01NDRdNDVdMTU2OF02N105N10yMTYyXTExMV04NzZdMTgyNF02NV02MjJdODc4XTI5MTddMjU5Ml01ODJdMjQxOF00MTk3XTQ5NjVdMTY0NF02MTddMTY0Nl02MTVdP14%3D)

Answer (score 10):

## 95. Python

```
print('"I\'m the king of the world!" - Jack Dawson')
```

Output is quote 100:

```
"I'm the king of the world!" - Jack Dawson
```

None forbidden.

Comment: The difference in votes between this answer and [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40377/26997) is the enigma that is Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 10):

## 91. [Marbelous](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/), uses no `\`

```
6D......69
72726F7169
+1+1......
7460204261
......+1..
4C6E726574
2121202D20
6F65206974
206E757420
22526E6170
..+1......
```

Output is quote 96:

```
"Snap out of it!" - Loretta Castorini
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40569/29611): `py3`

Answer (score 10):

## 73. AppleScript, uses no `0`

(All the "spaces" are "tabs", as permitted by OP. There are 25 tabs and 8 newlines.)

```
Set c   to  146/2&115&2*16&525/5&116&2*16&115&97&51*2&1111/11&126/2&2*17&2*16&45&2*16&68&114&46&2*16&67&2*52&114&525/5&115&116&525/5&97&2*55&2*16&166/2&122&1111/11&2*54&2*54
Set e   to  2*17
Set d   to  aScii   character   of  e
rePeat  with    i   in  c
Set d   to  d&aScii character   of  i
end rePeat
diSPlaY alert   d
```

Output is quote 70:

```
"Is it safe?" - Dr. Christian Szell
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40610/21487): `py3\" ';({s[)<+.@=-,X`

---

Here we first construct the variable `c` which is a list of ASCII codes of the quote. In AppleScript, `number & number` produces the 2-element list `{number, number}`, and `list & number` appends the number to the list, so it allows us to avoid using `{` or `,`. Additionally, `&` has lower priority than `*` and `/`, so we can create the whole list in one line, avoiding the `(` or creating variables (which wastes 3 tabs).

After that, we convert the list of numbers `c` into the string `d`. Again we use `&` here, since `string & string` is concatenation. AppleScript is case-insensitive, so we could use `diSPlaY` to workaround the `pys` characters.

Comment: Ah, I tried making an AppleScript answer too, but I didn't know that the keywords were case-insensitive, so I couldn't use `set` and failed. I had answer for quote #62, but I can't use that now ;P

Answer (score 10):

## 57. [Burlesque](http://mroman.ch/burlesque/) (uses no `|`)

New lines are for clarification only, but the tabs are necessary. There are 4 tabs.

```
??9!!JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
?iJ
?iJJ
?i?i?i?i?iJJ
?i?i?i?i?iJJ
?i
61118256541846584114424692216989142925962811646445822862641986546895526246185888152124859614142688
    41224222121111121111121111211111111114221112222112121211424411124111124222222211114424211211111121
$$6tdfCtiB!
j54ia
j5ia
j29ia
j9ia
j41?d?d?d?dia
j1?dia
j59ia
j59ia
j8?dia
j14ia
j21?dia
j24ia
j26ia
j41?d?d?d?dia
j41ia
j48ia
j52ia
j55ia
j61?dia
j65ia
j68?dia
j69?i?i?i?i?iia
j69?i?i?i?i?i?i?iia
j82ia
86
    29B!ZZ1!!1ia
61
    21B!ZZ1!!81?d?d?dia
48
    26B!ZZ1!!85ia
Q
```

Output is quote 87:

```
"Sawyer, you're going out a youngster, but you've got to come back a star!" - Julian Marsh
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40813/32353): `"'&()*+-,./\037;<=>@_[sovy pezxX]^{}~`

---

Burlesque is similar to GolfScript, but usually each command is 2-character long. The construction is like this:

1. Burlesque supports arbitrary-precision integer, and also allows conversion to base 36. So we first encode all the lower case characters in base 36:

   ```
      awyeryouregoingoutayoungsterbutyouvegottocomebackastarulianarsh₃₆
   == 3379063095879820583038345369081212641008420750861587542962343112066870047037314854758539\
      9600704049₁₀
   ```
2. Unfortunately, this number contains too much 0, 3 and 7, and all arithmetic symbols (`+-*/`) are banned... Usually we could use modulus, but Burlesque uses the sequence `.%` which the dot is also unavailable. Fortunately, the xor operator is strangely `$$`, so we could try to construct this by xor-ing two numbers free of 0, 3, 7. This is the reason of the huge number 41224222….
3. Finally we insert the remaining symbols like `,`, , etc back into the string. The bad news is the "chr" function uses the sequence `L[` which is again forbidden! The good news is there are various ways to construct an existing string (e.g. `??` creates the version string `"Burlesque - 1.7.3"` which contains a "space"), and then extract (`!!`) a character from it.
4. The increment and decrement operators also use the forbidden characters `.+`, `.-`, nevertheless there are alternatives `?i`, `?d` that have the same effect. Thus we could generate the whole ASCII spectrum from this.

Answer (score 10):

## 34. 6502 machine code + Apple II System Monitor (uses no `b`)

(Uses 1 tab)

```
262G    a!mwfl%mDmqli!flqlPmqljjPfuGf!T%wGK!96H4wGH4K2O!R!F%w9uGwGr?wGi299D!H2T%wGw%K2K!K!96F!9%jjjjjflPwP!fmjjjjjPwfmfm6m%lHjjPwflflflflclclclclfljclflclVljHHjjPqPDClflClflflclclclclclclflflflflflflflflflflflflflflflflflflflflflfljj6mP6
```

Output is quote 41:

```
"We rob banks." - Clyde Barrow
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41802): `"#$&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ ABdeEghIJLMNopQksUvWxXyYzZ{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `4` `6` `89`
- Uppercase: `CD` `FGH` `K` `OP` `RST` `V`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

Run on Apple //e (or emulator). Make sure the tab character is copied as a tab and not spaces.

---

This is a combination of the ideas of the [80386 machine code + DOS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40771) answer and my earlier [Applesoft BASIC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40807) answer.

For those unfamiliar, the System Monitor on Apple II computers is a very low-level interpreter/debugger that allows you to modify memory and run code (if you're running a BASIC interpreter, you can enter the System Monitor by doing `CALL -151`). The usual way to enter machine code in the System Monitor would be `<addr>: <hex_byte> <hex_byte> ...`, and running code is done by `<addr>G` (G for "Go"). Entering code in the usual way uses forbidden characters; however, the input buffer for entering a line of text starts at memory 0x200. So, the one-liner tells the System Monitor to jump to 0x262, and then embedded code as ASCII follows.

Despite not being an esoteric language, the restrictions on usable opcodes make the code more closely resemble a brainfuck derivative. All that's available: reading memory (but not writing), incrementing & decrementing memory, subtracting from the accumulator, and branching on not 0. Only a couple instructions were patched up: a call to the Monitor routine that outputs a character, and the return to end the program.

Disassembly. Note that all characters input get their high bit set:

```
; Branch here when done to return (patched from E1)
0205-   60          RTS
;
; Output loop: at this point, $EC-$ED points to the beginning of the
; phrase, which starts at 0x21F. Each character is encoded as 2 bytes.
; The ASCII value (with high bit set) is determined by doing:
; 2 - Byte1 - 0xA1 - Byte2, where subtraction with borrow is used (and
; borrow is always set for the first subtraction).
;
; Monitor routine to output (patched from A1 ED F7)
0206-   20 ED FD    JSR   $FDED
0209-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
020B-   A5 ED       LDA   $ED
020D-   C4 ED       CPY   $ED
020F-   F1 EC       SBC   ($EC),Y
0211-   E9 A1       SBC   #$A1
0213-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
0215-   F1 EC       SBC   ($EC),Y
0217-   D0 ED       BNE   $0206
; Computed value 0. We're done, so branch to the return instruction.
0219-   F1 EC       SBC   ($EC),Y
021B-   EA          NOP   
021C-   EA          NOP   
021D-   D0 E6       BNE   $0205
;
; Encoded string resides from 0x21F-0x25C
;
025D-   EA          NOP   
025E-   EA          NOP   
025F-   EA          NOP   
0260-   EA          NOP   
0261-   EA          NOP
; Execution begins here
; First, set up $EC-$ED to point to 0x200. No writes, so
; increment until the values are 0, then increment MSB twice.
0262-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
0264-   D0 F7       BNE   $025D
0266-   D0 A1       BNE   $0209 ; Boing!
0268-   E6 ED       INC   $ED
026A-   EA          NOP   
026B-   EA          NOP   
026C-   EA          NOP   
026D-   EA          NOP   
026E-   EA          NOP   
026F-   D0 F7       BNE   $0268
0271-   E6 ED       INC   $ED
0273-   E6 ED       INC   $ED
; Zero out A, X, Y registers
0275-   B6 ED       LDX   $ED,Y
0277-   A5 EC       LDA   $EC
0279-   C8          INY   
027A-   EA          NOP   
027B-   EA          NOP   
027C-   D0 F7       BNE   $0275
; Patch up tab character to make it a return so Monitor doesn't
; parse anything after the "262G"
027E-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
0280-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
0282-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
0284-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
; "isc" is undocumented instruction that increments memory then
; subtracts the result from accumulator.
0286-   E3 EC       isc   ($EC,X)   
0288-   E3 EC       isc   ($EC,X)   
028A-   E3 EC       isc   ($EC,X)   
028C-   E3 EC       isc   ($EC,X)   
028E-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
0290-   EA          NOP   
; Patch up RTS and JSR instructions at 0x205 and 0x206
; This loop adds 0x80 to the original values to get close
0291-   E3 EC       isc   ($EC,X)   
0293-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
0295-   E3 EC       isc   ($EC,X)   
0297-   D6 EC       DEC   $EC,X
0299-   EA          NOP   
029A-   C8          INY   
029B-   C8          INY   
029C-   EA          NOP   
029D-   EA          NOP   
029E-   D0 F1       BNE   $0291
02A0-   D0 C4       BNE   $0266 ; Boing!
; Finish patching RTS and JSR
; "dcp" undocumented "decrement then compare"
02A2-   C3 EC       dcp   ($EC,X)
02A4-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02A6-   C3 EC       dcp   ($EC,X)
; Patch address of character output call F7ED -> FDED
02A8-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02AA-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02AC-   E3 EC       isc   ($EC,X)   
02AE-   E3 EC       isc   ($EC,X)   
02B0-   E3 EC       isc   ($EC,X)   
02B2-   E3 EC       isc   ($EC,X)   
02B4-   E3 EC       isc   ($EC,X)   
02B6-   E3 EC       isc   ($EC,X)   
; Move pointer up to start of encoded string
02B8-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02BA-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02BC-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02BE-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02C0-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02C2-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02C4-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02C6-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02C8-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02CA-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02CC-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02CE-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02D0-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02D2-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02D4-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02D6-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02D8-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02DA-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02DC-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02DE-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02E0-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02E2-   E6 EC       INC   $EC
02E4-   EA          NOP   
02E5-   EA          NOP   
02E6-   B6 ED       LDX   $ED,Y
; Setup done, bounce our way up to the output loop at 0x209
02E8-   D0 B6       BNE   $02A0
```

Answer (score 10):

## 14. PDP-11 machine code, uses no `O`

```
4
rar
raw
rrrlratarltararltararltararlratarltararlratarlratarltararlratarlratarltararlratarltararlratarltararlratarltararlratarltararlra4cw
rrrlratarlratarltararlratarlratarlratarltararltararlratarlratarlratarltararlra8cw
rrrltararlratarlratarlratarltararltararltararlratarlratarltararlratarlratarltararltararltararlralaw
rrrlratarltararlratarltararltararlratarltararltararlratarltararlratarltararlratarlratarltararlratarltararlratarltararlranaw
rrrltararltararltararltararltararltararlratarltararlratarlratarltararlratarlratarltararltararlrarcw
rrrltararltararltararltararlratarltararlratarltararltararlratarlratarlratarltararltararltararlratcw
rrrlratarltararltararltararlratarlratarltararlratarltararltararlratarlratarltararlratarltararlratarltararlra449nlarc9nnatcrl4K4KDcDcDcDc    u444444DuS4S4S4SaS4S4S4S4SaDuc4cac4c4c4c4caKac4caDuSaKaKaSaSaS4KaSaS4S4SaKaSaDuc4c4cacacaKac4c4cac4DuS4S4S4S4S4S4S4S4S4Ducac4c4c4c4c4caKacacaKaDuKaSaKaSaKaSaKaKaSaS4S4S4S4KaSaw
rrrl4K4Kw
rrw
rruulnau8DK
KcScu
wrl48494444SD44K44D4n44SD44K44D4l84KD484D9K4DD4449D444D9K444D44DDD44DDD44K4884444DD944SDD8

r8wt44ucD8
uK8Scnn wuKwK4uauK4luwKwKu4wcnn wuKwK4uauK4lwwKwKr8wa8uSu44DcDrnurwrwlKwlltuwaKcltwwwnSwrDrturwrwlKwlKatwtKwlulwtnnwnDltrrnuntKwlcnwtcDcrDKnlSKrllluwtwwwDltwannwn8na
```

Output is quote 28:

```
"Play it, Sam. Play 'As Time Goes By.'" - Ilsa Lund
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42068/25315):

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFfgGhHiIjJkLmMNopPqQRsTUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters:

- Numbers: `4` `8` `9`
- Uppercase: `D` `K` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `l` `n` `r` `t` `u` `w`

---

A few technical details:

- All linebreaks use unix style (1 byte 0x0a)
- There is no linebreak at the end of the file (though it shouldn't matter)
- There are 3 tab characters
- File size is 1260 bytes

To verify this code, I used the [Ersatz-11](http://www.dbit.com/) simulator. To run the code, write the code into a file `test.pdp`, run the simulator, and enter:

```
load test
go
```

The result:

```
...
E11>load test
E11>go
"Play it, Sam. Play 'As Time Goes By.'" - Ilsa Lund

%HALT
...
```

Source code (all numbers are in octal notation):

```
clr 60562(r4)
;
com 60562(r2)
com 71162(pc) ; nop
;
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = ffff b = ffff
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = fffe b = ffff
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = fffd b = ffff
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = fffc b = ffff
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = fffc b = fffb
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = fff7 b = fffb
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = fff7 b = fff2
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = fff7 b = ffe9
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = ffe0 b = ffe9
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = ffe0 b = ffc9
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = ffe0 b = ffa9
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = ff89 b = ffa9
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = ff89 b = ff32
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = febb b = ff32
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = febb b = fded
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = fca8 b = fded
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = fca8 b = fa95
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = f73d b = fa95
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = f73d b = f1d2
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = e90f b = f1d2
add 60562(r1), 61464(r2) ; contains patch1
com 71162(pc)
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = e90f b = dae1
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = e90f b = c3f0
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = acff b = c3f0
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = acff b = 70ef
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = acff b = 1dee
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = acff b = caed
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 77ec b = caed
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 42d9 b = caed
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 42d9 b = 0dc6
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 42d9 b = 509f
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 42d9 b = 9378
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = d651 b = 9378
add 60562(r1), 61470(r2) ; contains patch2
com 71162(pc)
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 69c9 b = 9378
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 69c9 b = fd41
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 69c9 b = 670a
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 69c9 b = d0d3
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 3a9c b = d0d3
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 0b6f b = d0d3
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = dc42 b = d0d3
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = dc42 b = ad15
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = dc42 b = 8957
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 6599 b = 8957
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 6599 b = eef0
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 6599 b = 5489
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = ba22 b = 5489
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 0eab b = 5489
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 6334 b = 5489
add 60562(r1), 60554(r2) ; contains addr of patch1
com 71162(pc)
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 6334 b = b7bd
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 1af1 b = b7bd
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 1af1 b = d2ae
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = ed9f b = d2ae
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = c04d b = d2ae
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = c04d b = 92fb
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 5348 b = 92fb
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = e643 b = 92fb
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = e643 b = 793e
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 5f81 b = 793e
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 5f81 b = d8bf
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 3840 b = d8bf
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 3840 b = 10ff
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 3840 b = 493f
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 817f b = 493f
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 817f b = cabe
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 4c3d b = cabe
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 4c3d b = 16fb
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 6338 b = 16fb
add 60562(r1), 60556(r2) ; contains addr of patch2
com 71162(pc)
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 7a33 b = 16fb
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 912e b = 16fb
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = a829 b = 16fb
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = bf24 b = 16fb
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = d61f b = 16fb
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = ed1a b = 16fb
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = ed1a b = 0415
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = f12f b = 0415
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = f12f b = f544
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = f12f b = e673
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = d7a2 b = e673
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = d7a2 b = be15
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = d7a2 b = 95b7
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 6d59 b = 95b7
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 0310 b = 95b7
add 60562(r1), 61562(r2) ; contains addr of cmd1
com 71162(pc)
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 98c7 b = 95b7
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 2e7e b = 95b7
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = c435 b = 95b7
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 59ec b = 95b7
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 59ec b = efa3
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 498f b = efa3
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 498f b = 3932
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 82c1 b = 3932
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = bbf3 b = 3932
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = bbf3 b = f525
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = bbf3 b = b118
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = bbf3 b = 6d0b
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 28fe b = 6d0b
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 9609 b = 6d0b
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 0314 b = 6d0b
add 60562(r1), 61564(r2) ; contains addr of cmd2
com 71162(pc)
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 0314 b = 701f
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 7333 b = 701f
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = e352 b = 701f
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 5371 b = 701f
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 5371 b = c390
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 5371 b = 1701
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 6a72 b = 1701
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 6a72 b = 8173
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = ebe5 b = 8173
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 6d58 b = 8173
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 6d58 b = eecb
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = 6d58 b = 5c23
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = c97b b = 5c23
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = c97b b = 259e
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = ef19 b = 259e
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; a = ef19 b = 14b7
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; a = 03d0 b = 14b7
add 60562(r1), 32064(r2) ; contains value of r3
add @60554(r0), @61562(r1)
add @60556(r0), @61564(r1)
;
add 45464(r1), 45464(r2) ; nop
add (r5), r4
add (r5), r4
add (r5), r4
add (r5), r4
ash (r1), r4
;
; must be at address 0x310 (01420)
.word 32064 ; patch it with 0xe90f - it becomes...
            ; mov 32064(r5), r3
.word 32064
.word 32064 ; patch it with 0xd651 - it becomes...
            ; inc r5
;
; patch the patcher
;
ash r4, r5
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
add r5, (r3)+ ; [3] = 0x443c
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
add r5, (r3)+ ; [8] = 0x727b
ash r4, r5
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
add r5, -(r3) ; [7] = 0x0a85
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
add r5, -(r3) ; [2] = 0x7571
add r5, (r3) ; [2] = 0x7581
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
add r5, -(r3) ; [0] = 0x7585
ash r4, r5
add r5, (r3)+ ; [0] = 0x75c5
add r5, (r3) ; [1] = 0x6eac
add r5, (r3) ; [1] = 0x6eec
add r5, (r3)+ ; [1] = 0x6f2c
add r5, (r3)+ ; [2] = 0x75c1
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
add r5, (r3) ; [4] = 0x0a8b
add r5, (r3)+ ; [4] = 0x0acb
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
add r5, (r3)+ ; [7] = 0x0ac5
add r5, (r3) ; [8] = 0x72bb
add r5, (r3)+ ; [8] = 0x72fb
ash r4, r5
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
add r5, -(r3) ; [6] = 0x6453
add r5, -(r3) ; [5] = 0x644b
add r5, -(r3) ; [4] = 0x0bcb
add r5, (r3) ; [4] = 0x0ccb
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
add r5, -(r3) ; [1] = 0x702c
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
ash r4, r5
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
ash r4, r5
add r5, -(r3) ; [8] = 0x82fb
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
bit (r1)+, -(r3)
add r5, -(r3) ; [2] = 0x85c1
add r5, (r3) ; [2] = 0x95c1
add r5, -(r3) ; [1] = 0x802c
add r5, -(r3) ; [0] = 0x85c5
add r5, (r3) ; [0] = 0x95c5
ash r4, r5
add r5, (r3) ; [0] = 0xd5c5
add r5, (r3)+ ; [0] = 0x15c5
add r5, (r3) ; [1] = 0xc02c
add r5, (r3)+ ; [1] = 0x002c
add r5, (r3) ; [2] = 0xd5c1
add r5, (r3)+ ; [2] = 0x15c1
add r5, (r3) ; [3] = 0x843c
add r5, (r3) ; [3] = 0xc43c
add r5, (r3)+ ; [3] = 0x043c
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
bit (r1)+, (r3)+
add r5, (r3) ; [8] = 0xc2fb
add r5, (r3)+ ; [8] = 0x02fb
;
com 71162(pc)
add 45464(r1), 45464(r2) ; nop
com 71162(pc)
com 71162(pc)
;
; ------------------------
; must be at address 0x3d0 (01720)
.word 072565
.word 067154
.word 072541
.word 042070
.word 005113
.word 061513
.word 061523
.word 005165
.word 071167
; After patching, this code becomes...
; mov #51, r5
; mov #002074, r1
; patch_loop:
; asl (r3)
; add (r1)+, (r3)
; add (r1)+, (r3)+
; dec r5
; bne patch_loop
;
.byte 154, 064
.byte 070, 064
.byte 071, 064
.byte 064, 064
.byte 064, 123
.byte 104, 064
.byte 064, 113
.byte 064, 064
.byte 104, 064
.byte 156, 064
.byte 064, 123
.byte 104, 064
.byte 064, 113
.byte 064, 064
.byte 104, 064
.byte 154, 070
.byte 064, 113
.byte 104, 064
.byte 070, 064
.byte 104, 071
.byte 113, 064
.byte 104, 104
.byte 064, 064
.byte 064, 071
.byte 104, 064
.byte 064, 064
.byte 104, 071
.byte 113, 064
.byte 064, 064
.byte 104, 064
.byte 064, 104
.byte 104, 104
.byte 064, 064
.byte 104, 104
.byte 104, 064
.byte 064, 113
.byte 064, 070
.byte 070, 064
.byte 064, 064
.byte 064, 104
.byte 104, 071
.byte 064, 064
.byte 123, 104
.byte 104, 070
;
; After patching, this code becomes...
; mov #32, r1
; mov #002006, r0
;out_loop:
; tstb @#0177564
; bpl out_loop
; mov (r0),@#0177566
; swab (r0)
;out_wait:
; tstb @#0177564
; bpl out_wait
; mov (r0)+,@#0177566
; dec r1
; bpl out_loop
; halt
; "Play it, Sam. Play 'As Time Goes By.'" - Ilsa Lund
;
.byte 12, 12 ; linebreaks for "readability"
.byte 162, 070
.byte 167, 164
.byte 064, 064
.byte 165, 143
.byte 104, 070
.byte 012, 165
.byte 113, 070
.byte 123, 143
.byte 156, 156
.byte 011, 167
.byte 165, 113
.byte 167, 113
.byte 064, 165
.byte 141, 165
.byte 113, 064
.byte 154, 165
.byte 167, 113
.byte 167, 113
.byte 165, 064
.byte 167, 143
.byte 156, 156
.byte 011, 167
.byte 165, 113
.byte 167, 113
.byte 064, 165
.byte 141, 165
.byte 113, 064
.byte 154, 167
.byte 167, 113
.byte 167, 113
.byte 162, 070
.byte 167, 141
.byte 070, 165
.byte 123, 165
.byte 064, 064
.byte 104, 143
.byte 104, 162
.byte 156, 165
.byte 162, 167
.byte 162, 167
.byte 154, 113
.byte 167, 154
.byte 154, 164
.byte 165, 167
.byte 141, 113
.byte 143, 154
.byte 164, 167
.byte 167, 167
.byte 156, 123
.byte 167, 162
.byte 104, 162
.byte 164, 165
.byte 162, 167
.byte 162, 167
.byte 154, 113
.byte 167, 154
.byte 113, 141
.byte 164, 167
.byte 164, 113
.byte 167, 154
.byte 165, 154
.byte 167, 164
.byte 156, 156
.byte 167, 156
.byte 104, 154
.byte 164, 162
.byte 162, 156
.byte 165, 156
.byte 164, 113
.byte 167, 154
.byte 143, 156
.byte 167, 164
.byte 143, 104
.byte 143, 162
.byte 104, 113
.byte 156, 154
.byte 123, 113
.byte 162, 154
.byte 154, 154
.byte 165, 167
.byte 164, 167
.byte 167, 167
.byte 104, 154
.byte 164, 167
.byte 141, 156
.byte 156, 167
.byte 156, 070
.byte 156, 141
```

---

It's easier to explain how this works from the beginning to the end. The output part is like this (each iteration outputs 2 bytes):

```
mov #32, r1
mov #002006, r0
out_loop:
 tstb @#0177564
 bpl out_loop
 mov (r0),@#0177566
 swab (r0)
out_wait:
 tstb @#0177564
 bpl out_wait
 mov (r0)+,@#0177566
 dec r1
 bpl out_loop
 halt
 ----- "Play it, Sam. Play 'As Time Goes By.'" - Ilsa Lund
```

This code contains many forbidden bytes, both in the code and in the output message. To fix that, the code is scrambled: each word (16 bits) is represented as a sum of 3 numbers:

```
code = 2 * a + b + c
```

Patching (unscrambling) code:

```
 mov #51, r5
 mov #002074, r1
patch_loop:
 asl (r3)
 add (r1)+, (r3)
 add (r1)+, (r3)+
 dec r5
 bne patch_loop
```

This code itself contains forbidden bytes, but it is much shorter (9 words). The patcher that descrambles this code only uses permitted bytes (it's under the "patch the patcher" comment in the source), so it has a very limited set of operations (basically, just "add"), so patching many bytes would be too much code.

Using this patcher is not straightforward. To patch large amounts of data with simple code, I needed instructions like `add r5, (r3)+` and `add r5, -(r3)` - and the only registers that could be used like this were `r3` and `r5`. Unfortunately, no allowed commands can be used to initialize these registers, so I had to patch instructions that did that:

```
mov 32064(r5), r3
inc r5
```

This required patching only 2 words.

I have searched for quite some time for a way to do the patching; the only way I came up with was using the infamous "indirect" mode:

```
... (much preparation here)
add @60554(r0), @61562(r1)
add @60556(r0), @61564(r1)
```

To run these two instructions, quite a bit of preparation is needed:

- Store a patching value (`patch1`) in memory
- Store a pointer to the patching mask in memory
- Store a pointer to the instruction to be patched in memory

To generate all these constants, I used the following instructions:

```
add 60562(r1), 60564(r2) ; add a to b
add 60564(r1), 60562(r2) ; add b to a
```

They use words at addressed 060562 and 060564 as temporary variables; a right arrangement of these two instructions can generate any value in 10-20 steps.

---

Instructions used in this code (excluding any that are patched):

```
clr offset(rN)    - a no-op; its machine code is used to obtain the number 2
com offset(rN)    - used to obtain the number -1
add offset1(rN), offset2(rM) -  used for arithmetic
add @offset1(rN), @offset2(rM)
com offset(pc)    - a no-op (it actually writes junk to memory)
add (r5), r4      - one of a few "sane" instructions!
ash r4, r5        - another useful sane instruction
bit ...           - used for its only side effect - increment or decrement
add r5, (r3)+     }
add r5, (r3)      } By luck, all of these commands can be used!
add r5, -(r3)     }
```

Answer (score 10):

## 7. [23](http://web.archive.org/web/20060717035053/http://www.philipp-winterberg.de/software/23e.php), uses no `l`

```
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
```

With the trailing linefeed (that *must* be present), there are exactly 64 linefeeds in this code.

Executing it prints the second quote:

```
"I'm gonna make him an offer he can't refuse." - Vito Corleone
```

*Thanks to @jimmy23013 for pointing me to this challenge.*

#### Verification

Since this above code works in the [online interpreter](http://web.archive.org/web/20070213142054/http://www.philipp-winterberg.de/software/23inte.php), uses no spaces (**pure 23**), no **x**s (**23.ixsy**) and no commas (**23.dezsy**), I assume it's valid **23.easy** (undocumented), which just takes line length into account.

The code (read backwards) is equivalent to the following **23.dezsy** code:

```
17,62,34,73,39,109,32,103,111,110,110,97,32,109,97,107,101,32,104,105,109,32,97,110,32,111,102,102,101,114,32,104,101,32,99,97,110,39,116,32,114,101,102,117,115,101,46,34,32,45,32,86,105,116,111,32,67,111,114,108,101,111,110,101
```

`17,62` instructs the interpreter to print the **62** integers that follow as characters.

The interpreter seems to require one more character on each line than it should. I assume this is to account for Windows-style newlines. To make the code work according to the spec (or in a browser that introduces carriage returns), remove one `K` from each line.

To test the code, paste it in the **Source** area, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the trailing linefeed, type `23` in the **Console** area (to switch from the default **23.dezsy** notation to auto-detection) and click <kbd>Run Interpreter!</kbd>.

Answer (score 9):

## 66 - Pyth, uses no `e`

```
DSGRjkmCdGJC96P:Sj4142h118J:Sj9927h112J:Sjt11641t112J:Sj11154t115J:SjxT14142t122J:Sj4128h125J:Sj11154t115J:Sj4128h125J:Sj11196t112J:Sjt14254t122J:Sj12195t112J:Sj12752t114J:Sj5248h111J:Sj4142h118J:Sj4128h125J:Sj5181h112J:Sj4128h125J:Sj9116t111J:Sj12528h111J:Sj14126h121J:Sj11154t115J:Sj4128h125J:Sj8566t111J:Sj12528h111J:Sj11976t111J:Sj11646t111J:Sj12416h111J:Sj11711t116JJ
```

Output is quote 62:

```
"What a dump." - Rosa Moline
```

Uses the characters `12456789:CDGJPRSTdhjkmtx`.

Previously forbidden: `z" &'()*+,-./03;<=>@X[\]psy{`

It's based on a series of regex substitutions - `:` in pyth, each replacing `, the backtick character, with a two character string containing a new character followed by a backtick.

The substitutions are all applied to an original string of just ` (J).

The two letter strings are generated by using the base changing function, `j`, on a number and a base to generate an list entry of numbers, which are then ASCII encoded into a 2 character string by the newly defined `S` function.

Explanation:

```
DSGRjkmCdG                 define S, which makes a string out of a list of ASCII numbers
JC96                       J = "`"
P                          print all but the last character of
:Sj4142h118J               "` <- `
:Sj9927h112J               W` <- `
:Sjt11641t112J             h` <- `
:Sj11154t115J              a` <- `
:SjxT14142t122J            t` <- `
:Sj4128h125J                ` <- `
:Sj11154t115J              a` <- `
:Sj4128h125J                ` <- `
:Sj11196t112J              d` <- `
:Sjt14254t122J             u` <- `
:Sj12195t112J              m` <- `
:Sj12752t114J              p` <- `
:Sj5248h111J               .` <- `
:Sj4142h118J               "` <- `
:Sj4128h125J                ` <- `
:Sj5181h112J               -` <- `
:Sj4128h125J                ` <- `
:Sj9116t111J               R` <- `
:Sj12528h111J              o` <- `
:Sj14126h121J              s` <- `
:Sj11154t115J              a` <- `
:Sj4128h125J                ` <- `
:Sj8566t111J               M` <- `
:Sj12528h111J              o` <- `
:Sj11976t111J              l` <- `
:Sj11646t111J              i` <- `
:Sj12416h111J              n` <- `
:Sj11711t116J              e` <- `
J                          Starting with `
```

Comment: You forgot the omission of `z` from 66 in your chart. This breaks the chain as the next entry is on the second page.

Answer (score 9):

## 60. Forth (uses no `^`)

(There are 54 new lines and 51 tabs.)

```
116 114 115
HEx
22  EMIT
41  EMIT
SPACE
62  EMIT
6F  EMIT
DECIMAL 121 EMIT
81  42  MOD EMIT
DUP EMIT
SPACE
98  EMIT
HEx 65  EMIT
DUP EMIT
2   PICK    EMIT
SPACE
66  EMIT
OVER    EMIT
69  EMIT
65  EMIT
6E  EMIT
64  EMIT
SPACE
69  EMIT
DUP EMIT
SPACE
68  EMIT
69  EMIT
DUP EMIT
SPACE
6D  EMIT
6F  EMIT
2   PICK    EMIT
68  EMIT
65  EMIT
OVER    EMIT
2E  EMIT
22  EMIT
SPACE
2D  EMIT
SPACE
4E  EMIT
6F  EMIT
OVER    EMIT
6D  EMIT
61  EMIT
6E  EMIT
SPACE
42  EMIT
61  EMIT
2   PICK    EMIT
65  EMIT
DUP EMIT
BYE
```

Output is quote 56:

```
"A boy's best friend is his mother." - Norman Bates
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40771/32353): `"'&()*+-,./\037;<=>@X_[sovy pez]{}`

Answer (score 9):

## 59. Applesoft BASIC, uses no `~`

(Uses 11 newlines)

```
1HOME:PRINT:PRINT:CALL2111:END
2REMWARNING!ABUSEOFLANGUAGEBELOW!!!!!!
4VTAB#PR#STOREONERREEEDELEIEIADELFPR#RETURNEDELGEGIENDDELHEHITANDELIDEFP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
5VTABLPR#EGHGREGRVTABLPR#EGHGREGRVTABAPR#EGHGREGRVTABHPR#EHHGREGRGRDEFP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
6VTABEPR#EGHGREGRVTABIPR#EGHGREGRVTABNPR#EGHGREGRVTABNPR#EGHGREGRDEFP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
8VTABAPR#EHHGREGRGRVTABMPR#EIHGREGRGRVTABBPR#EIHGREGRVTABNPR#EIHGREGRDEFP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
9VTABAPR#EGHGREGRVTABDPR#EGHGREGRVTABMPR#EIHGREGRVTABEPR#EGHGREGRDEFP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
11VTABEPR#EGHGREGRVTABDPR#EGHGREGRVTABMPR#EIHGREGRVTABAPR#EGHGREGRDEFP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
12VTABLPR#EGHGREGRGRVTABLPR#EIHGREGRVTABAPR#EGHGREGRVTABDPR#EGHGREGRDEFP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
14VTABMPR#EIHGREGRVTABEPR#EGHGREGRVTABEPR#EGHGREGRVTABDPR#EGHGREGRDEFP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
15VTABMPR#EIHGREGRVTABAPR#EGHGREGRVTABLPR#EHHGREGRVTABBPR#EIHGRE`
```

Output is quote 55:

"La-dee-da, la-dee-da." - Annie Hall

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40775/32522) `"'&()*+-,./\037;<=>@X_[sovy pez]^{}`

Runs on an Apple //e (or emulator).

Short explanation: After clearing the screen, the "CALL 2111" jumps to the embedded 6502 machine code in lines 4-15, which writes each character directly onto the text page.

Details:

- Line 1: Clear screen, print 2 newlines so command prompt doesn't overwrite quote, call embedded machine code that begins at Line 4, and exit.
- Line 2: Applesoft programs are normally stored starting at address 0x0801 (2049), but I have to add padding here to make embedded machine code start at 0x83F (2111) since '0' is a forbidden character.
- Lines 4-15: Machine code can consist only of bytes that are printable ASCII. Tokenizer will convert reserved words to single bytes that are encoded with MSB set (e.g. "VTAB"=0xA2) but it will convert lower case to upper.

Disassembly:

```
; Body of line 4: set up zero-page constants and index
; Y = offset from start of text page to current character
; Quote drawn right-to-left; start at offset 35 (0x23)
083F-   A2 23       LDX   #$23
0841-   8A          TXA   
0842-   A8          TAY
; Z-page 0x45-0x46 points to start of text page (0x0400)
0843-   A5 45       LDA   $45
0845-   45 45       EOR   $45
0847-   85 45       STA   $45
0849-   49 45       EOR   #$45
084B-   49 41       EOR   #$41
084D-   85 46       STA   $46
; This TXA effectively a no-op to prevent incorrect tokenization
; ("FRETURN" would get tokenized as "FRE TURN", not the desired "F RETURN")
084F-   8A          TXA   
; All characters stored as uppercase ASCII. To display correctly, MSB
; must be set, so uppercase is XORed with 0x80. To transform to lowercase,
; XOR with 0xA0; To transform to symbol, XOR with 0xE0.
;
; Store constant 0xA0 at memory 0x47 (loading A from somewhere on text
; page which had just been cleared to all 0xA0)
0850-   B1 45       LDA   ($45),Y
0852-   85 47       STA   $47
; Store constant 0x80 at memory 0x48
0854-   45 47       EOR   $47
0856-   49 80       EOR   #$80
0858-   85 48       STA   $48
; Store constant 0xE0 at memory 0x49
085A-   45 48       EOR   $48
085C-   49 E0       EOR   #$E0
085E-   85 49       STA   $49
; Embedded code too big to fit on one line (~255 char input limit) so must
; jump to body of next line. But smallest offset that can be encoded is
; 0x21 (ASCII '!') so do that and pad out rest of line with more '!'
0860-   B8          CLV   
0861-   50 21       BVC   $0884

; Body of line 5: draw last 4 characters (right-to-left)
; A = 0x4C (ASCII 'L')
0884-   A2 4C       LDX   #$4C
0886-   8A          TXA
; XOR with constant 0xA0 stored at 0x47, which shows up as 'l'   
0887-   45 47       EOR   $47
; Write to text page (0x400 + 0x23)
0889-   91 45       STA   ($45),Y
; Move 1 char to the left
088B-   88          DEY   
; Next char'l', same process (could optimize here)
088C-   A2 4C       LDX   #$4C
088E-   8A          TXA   
088F-   45 47       EOR   $47
0891-   91 45       STA   ($45),Y
0893-   88          DEY   
; Next char 'a'
0894-   A2 41       LDX   #$41
0896-   8A          TXA   
0897-   45 47       EOR   $47
0899-   91 45       STA   ($45),Y
089B-   88          DEY  
; Next char 'H' 
089C-   A2 48       LDX   #$48
089E-   8A          TXA   
089F-   45 48       EOR   $48
08A1-   91 45       STA   ($45),Y
08A3-   88          DEY   
; Decrement index an extra time since next char is a space
08A4-   88          DEY   
; Jump to body of next line after padding
08A5-   B8          CLV   
08A6-   50 21       BVC   $08C9

; ... Lines 6-14 similar ...

; Body of line 15
; '-'
0A64-   A2 4D       LDX   #$4D
0A66-   8A          TXA   
0A67-   45 49       EOR   $49
0A69-   91 45       STA   ($45),Y
0A6B-   88          DEY   
; 'a'
0A6C-   A2 41       LDX   #$41
0A6E-   8A          TXA   
0A6F-   45 47       EOR   $47
0A71-   91 45       STA   ($45),Y
0A73-   88          DEY   
; 'L'
0A74-   A2 4C       LDX   #$4C
0A76-   8A          TXA   
0A77-   45 48       EOR   $48
0A79-   91 45       STA   ($45),Y
0A7B-   88          DEY   
; '"'
0A7C-   A2 42       LDX   #$42
0A7E-   8A          TXA   
0A7F-   45 49       EOR   $49
0A81-   91 45       STA   ($45),Y
; Return from CALL
0A83-   60          RTS
```

Machine code could certainly be optimized, but some quirks are due to encoding restrictions, for example:

- Phrase is drawn right-to-left since decrementing Y is easier to encode that incrementing Y.
- Lots of "LDX imm ; TXA" sequences because the opcode for "LDA imm" (0xA9) maps to the reserved word "COLOR=" which contains illegal char '='.

Answer (score 9):

## 1. [Progressive Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary#Progressive_Unary) (uses no `4`)

The program consists of exactly 2130691772666389774389011818129432977526724054595685774072956807220340187754304344216170850474741825084738264024483125639102366732655921717750240644490284886585962997427932957194151233773238138826867657234233319542153892729223723713050148830827990932577158473558351770035220237198845372011140540236617061039134694993085927484693315515564905404685624754504677002990899546806981073411560009765942646584748262443625075334590374146800896620084838828846593051116848347417777214960627252153699850863043331541162486725625476864531564012190733203044734594521962297876104066432536535668411493346287828832810901078480818727197899744852589810133773624066622420226015624219902142535668225959682605837151376445379519636 `8`s (2.13 × 10<sup>705</sup> bytes):

```
88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888…
```

Output is quote 32:

```
"Round up the usual suspects." - Capt. Louis Renault
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124753/32353):

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./01235679:;<=>@[\]^_` aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters: `8`

---

**Progressive Unary** is a variant of Unary proposed by esolangs user Quintopia [on 2010 Sept 3rd](https://esolangs.org/w/index.php?title=Unary&diff=prev&oldid=18704). Unlike Unary which only permits the character `0`, Progressive Unary *requires* arbitrary character used as its "one" character, as long as it is distinct from other programs on the same tape. The point of the requirement was to effectively find the length of the program in O(log n) steps on the random-access tape. So it is equivalent to [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage), except it is *not* designed for this challenge, loopholing around the loophole (it also uses a different encoding than Lenguage).

---

The [equivalent brainfuck program](https://tio.run/##jZLRCsMwCEXf@yvBfEHJj4w9tIPBGOyhsO/P6rTuatJ2PonJvR5N5mV6vO7v27PWkjguNCaJch0pD1KFMte3slXlruR5IAlLvnlJFqtMy6uOBXAWCDa3HT0BTE@OCAp0QHIKwiPC7AYAIu/xv796G2TAVqlKlOdwFGocsHe4QM2L7j1zsGGjZmyHEhp1OvmvFgh6tMjQ7rS78PiWrhf@3tPV@JF@slzrBw) is:

```
>+++++[-<+++++++>]<-.
>++++++[-<++++++++>]<.
>+++++[-<++++++>]<-.
++++++.
-------.
----------.
>++++++++++[-<------->]<++.
>++++++++++++[-<+++++++>]<+.
-----.
>++++++++++[-<-------->]<.
>++++++++++++[-<+++++++>]<.
------------.
---.
>++++++++++[-<------->]<+.
>++++++++++++[-<+++++++>]<+.
--.
++.
>+++++[-<---->]<.
+++++++++++.
>+++++++++++[-<------->]<+.
>++++++++++++[-<+++++++>]<-.
++.
--.
---.
-----------.
--.
>++++[-<++++>]<+.
-.
>++++++++++[-<------->]<+.
------------.
--.
+++++++++++++.
-------------.
>+++++[-<+++++++>]<.
>+++++[-<++++++>]<.
+++++++++++++++.
++++.
>++++++++++[-<------->]<.
--------------.
>+++++[-<+++++++++>]<-.
>+++++[-<+++++++>]<.
++++++.
------------.
++++++++++.
>++++++++++++[-<------->]<+.
>+++++++[-<+++++++>]<+.
>+++++[-<++++>]<-.
+++++++++.
-------------.
>+++++[-<++++>]<.
---------.
++++++++.
```

Python 3 generator:

```python
# Cost of factorization of N to A*B+C is "7+A+B+|C|"
#
# {#, Minimize[{7 + a + b + Abs[c], # == a b + c && a > 0 && b > 0}, {a, b, c}, Integers]} & /@ {17, 19, 20, 29, 30, 34, 35, 44, 48, 50, 68, 69, 70, 76, 80, 83, 84, 85}

BF_FACTORIZATIONS = {
    17: (4, 4, 1),
    19: (5, 4, -1),
    20: (5, 4, 0),
    29: (5, 6, -1),
    30: (5, 6, 0),
    34: (5, 7, -1),
    35: (5, 7, 0),
    44: (5, 9, -1),
    48: (6, 8, 0),
    50: (7, 7, 1),
    68: (10, 7, -2),
    69: (10, 7, -1),
    70: (10, 7, 0),
    76: (11, 7, -1),
    80: (10, 8, 0),
    83: (12, 7, -1),
    84: (12, 7, 0),
    85: (12, 7, 1),
}

BF_DELTA_CONSTS = {0: ''}
for i in range(16):
    BF_DELTA_CONSTS[i] = '+'*i
    BF_DELTA_CONSTS[-i] = '-'*i
for n, (a, b, c) in BF_FACTORIZATIONS.items():
    BF_DELTA_CONSTS[n] = '>' + '+'*a + '[-<' + '+'*b + '>]<' + BF_DELTA_CONSTS[c]
    BF_DELTA_CONSTS[-n] = '>' + '+'*a + '[-<' + '-'*b + '>]<' + BF_DELTA_CONSTS[-c]

bf = ''
init = 0
for c in map(ord, '"Round up the usual suspects." - Capt. Louis Renault'):
    (delta, init) = (c - init, c)
    bf += BF_DELTA_CONSTS[delta]
    bf += '.\n'

num = '1' + bf.translate({
    ord('>'): '0',
    ord('<'): '1',
    ord('+'): '2',
    ord('-'): '3',
    ord('.'): '4',
    ord(','): '5',
    ord('['): '6',
    ord(']'): '7',
    ord('\n'): '',
})

print(bf)
print(int(num, 8))
```

Answer (score 8):

## 41. [ADJUST](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ADJUST) (uses no `L`)

(There must not be any trailing new lines)

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`8``8``F``RK``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````n```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`F`````8````F````F```RF``K````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`F``RF```8````F````RK```````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`RF``````F`````F````RF```F``RK```````````````A```````````````K`AF``RF`RF``8```K```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````n``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````n````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````n```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`AF````F```8``RF``RK```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`RF`````F````F```RF``F`FK```````````````````A````````````````````````K`A8``F``F```RF````RK```````````````````````````````A`````````````````````````````````K`AtF``8```tK````````````````````````````````````K`AF````tF```8````RK``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````n```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````n````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`AtF``F```F````RF`````RK```````````````````````````````A````````````````````````````K`AF``F`F``8```tK````````````````````````````````````````````````K`A8``````F``````F`````8````K`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`ARF`````tF``````RF`````RK``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````n`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`RF```F``RF```RF````RK````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````A``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`AF`````tF``````F`````8````K`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`ARF`````8````RF````RK``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`F``F```F````8`````F`````RK````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````n````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````n```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````C
````````````K`RF`F``8```RF```K``````````````````````````A`````````````````````````K`AF````tF`````tF``````RK`````````````````````````````K`F`````RF``````tF```````tK``````K````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`AF````F```RF````tF```RK```````````````````````````````````````````````````K`8```F```RF````RF```K``````````````````````````````````K`tF```8``F``RK```````````````````````````K`F````8```RF```F``RK````````````````````````````A``````````````````````````````K`AF```8````tF````RK```````````````````````````````````````````````````K`F``F```F````F`````8``````RK`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`8``````F``````RF`````tK```````````A`
```````````n```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````n`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````n```````````````````````````````````````````````````````n`````````````````````````````````````````n``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````n`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````n``````````````````````````````````````
``````````A````````````````````K`A8```F```tF````F`````K`````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`A8````F````tF```RK``````n`````````````````````````````K`AK````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`ARF`````8````8````K```````````````````````````A````````````````````````K`AF`````F````8```RF```RK``````n`````````````````K`ARF``8```RF```RK``````n```````````````````````K`AF``F`F``F```8````F````K`````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`ARF````F```8``F``RK```````````````````````````A```````````````````````````````K`ARF`````tF````8`````K```````````````````````````````A```````````````````````````K`Ai````````
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
K`8F8`F`K````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`AK`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`AF```F````8`````8`````K````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`AK``````````````````````````````````````K`AK``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`AF``F`F``8```F```F````K`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````K`A8``````F``````F`````8````K`````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Output is quote 50:

```
"Houston, we have a problem." - Jim Lovell
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41635/32353): `"#$&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ BdeEghJNopQksvWxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `46` `89`
- Uppercase: `A` `CD` `FGHI` `K` `M` `OP` `RSTUV` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

---

ADJUST is a 2D language with 1 register and 2 stacks. The code pointer starts from the lower-left corner, then walks in the northeast direction. Instructions are based on the prime factorization of the current character code, e.g. `Z` = 90 = 5×3×3×2, so the character `Z` will perform the action "5" once, "3" twice, and then "2" once. This allows us to have several ways to perform one function and avoid the forbidden characters.

The basic idea of the program is:

1. perform enough "5" (flip last bit) and "2" (rotate right by 3 bits) to make the accumulator contain the correct ASCII code to print
2. perform "3" (push to lighter stack and do a complicated turn) until stack #2 contains the accumulator
3. perform "13" (pop stack 2 and print) to print that code
4. because "3" will turn the code pointer in some complicated way, if we don't go forward horizontally we will easily break the 64-new-lines limit. So we need to do more "3"s until the direction is correct.

In step 1 we will use these letters to provide the 2 and 5's:

- `F` (7×5×2)
- `R` (41×2)
- `t` (29×2×2)
- `8` (7×2×2×2)

There are some 7, 29, 41 but these won't affect the final result. In step 2 we will use `K` (5×5×3) to provide a "3". Note that a pair of "5" is no-op.

In step 3 we choose `A` (13×5). In step 4 we will use `n` (11×5×2) to control the stack size and `K` to adjust the direction.

Generally, if step 1 does not contain any `R`, we use `KAnK` to print the character and move up by 4 lines. Otherwise, we use `KKA` to print and move down by 2 lines. Occasionally there is also a `KnnK` to forcefully move up by 4 lines, as the starting point must be at the lower-left corner.

If anyone is interested, [here is a working environment](https://gist.github.com/kennytm/9b884f187fe7621431b8) to produce the code above. There is no automated generator.

Answer (score 8):

## 23. [Glypho](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Glypho), uses no `%`

```
2248242424422424244224242442242424422248244224242442244422482424244224242442242424422248244224242442242424422424244222482442244422482424244224242442242424422424244224242442244422482424244222482442242424422248244224242442242424422248244224242442224824422424244222482442244422482424244222482442242424422424244224242442242424422424244222482442244422482424244222482442242424422424244222482442242424422248244224242442224824422424244224442248242424422248244224242442224824422424244224242442224824422424244224242442244422482424244224242442242424422424244224242442244422482424244222482442242424422248244224242442242424422248244224242442242424422444224824242442224824422424244224242442224824422424244222482442242424422248244224242442224824422444224824242442242424422424244224242442242424422444224824242442224824422424244224242442242424422424244222482442242424422444224824242442224824422424244224242442242424422248244224242442242424422248244224442248242424422424244224242442242424422424244224442248242424422248244224242442242424422424244224242442242424422248244224442248242424422248244224242442242424422248244224242442224824422424244224242442244422482424244222482442242424422424244222482442242424422248244224242442224824422424244222482442244422482424244222482442242424422424244222482442242424422248244224242442224824422424244224442248242424422248244224242442242424422424244222482442242424422424244222482442244422482424244224242442224824422424244222482442242424422248244224242442244422482424244224242442242424422424244222482442242424422444224824242442242424422424244224242442242424422444224824242442242424422248244224242442224824422424244224242442224824422444224824242442242424422424244224242442242424422444224824242442242424422424244224242442224824422424244222482442242424422248244224442248242424422248244224242442224824422424244224242442242424422248244224242442244422482424244222482442242424422248244224242442242424422248244224242442242424422248244224442248242424422248244224242442224824422424244224242442242424422248244224242442224824422444224824242442224824422424244224242442224824422424244224242442242424422248244224442248242424422248244224242442242424422248244224242442224824422424244222482442242424422444224824242442224824422424244222482442242424422424244224242442224824422424244222482442244422482424244222482442242424422424244222482442242424422424244222482442242424422248244224442248242424422248244224242442242424422424244224242442242424422248244224442248242424422248244224242442224824422424244222482442242424422424244224242442224824422444224824242442224824422424244224242442242424422424244224242442224824422444
```

Output is quote 30:

```
"I want to be alone." - Grusinskaya
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41961/194): `` !"#$&'()*+,-./013567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFghIjJkLMNopqQRsTUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~ ``

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `?`
- Numbers: `2` `4` `89`
- Uppercase: `D` `GH` `K` `OP` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `i` `lmn` `r` `tu` `w`

Note that this works with the [Java interpreter](http://esoteric.voxelperfect.net/files/glypho/impl/), but that disagrees with the esolangs page on the coding of `[` and `+`. However, the design of Glypho is such that the full instruction set is available as long as you have four distinct characters, and everything apart from loops is available if you have three, so this is a minor detail.

I had previously picked a quote that I like from a film that I've actually seen, but apparently I overlooked a rule. :(

Comment: Well, there goes everybody's favourite modulus tactic :P

Comment: You cannot use quote 6: there's that rule "The quote number you choose must not be more than 5 below your answer number"

Comment: @anatolyg, I missed that rule. Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 8):

## 20. [Subleq](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Subleq) (uses no `m`)

(It has 30 newlines and 63 tabs.)

```
28  42  4
9999    48  29
44  9999    42
222 8   48
24  22  9
9   9   9
9   9   9
9   48  222
2   29  44
9999    222 8
9999    222 222
44  9   9
9   9   9
9   9   9
84  9   49
222 8   9
9   29489   9429
49429   28  8
8929    444 998
849 849 8929
848 28  8929
4882    24  428
289 28  429
8929    9429    24
2929    2929    428
924 29489   8929
84  8929    9289
24  429 992
24  849 8929
9429    24  2929
2929    428 4949    4829
```

Output is quote 16:

```
"They call me Mister Tibbs!" - Virgil Tibbs
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41973/25180):

`` ?!"#$%&'()*+,-./013567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFgGhIjJkLMNopqQRsTUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~ ``

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: none
- Numbers: `2` `4` `89`
- Uppercase: `D` `H` `K` `OP` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `i` `l` `n` `r` `tu` `w`

[Tested here](http://mazonka.com/subleq/online/hsqjs.cgi). Click `ASQ -> SQ` to compile and `execute SQ` to run. It will compile to exactly the same code with different spacing so it doesn't matter if you run it without compiling.

Subleq is a Turing complete language with only one instruction: *subleq*. It takes three numbers *a*, *b* and *c*, subtract *a* from *b* and jumps to *c* if the result in *b* is zero or negative. Subtracting from address `-1` will output a character, and jumping to a negative address will end the program.

It doesn't have to jump to addresses which are multiples of 3 or starting a line. And it doesn't matter how you arrange the code. But the compiler will compile it to something different if there are less than 3 numbers in a line.

Explanation:

```
addr0: 28 42 4 9999           # Get 84 - 222 = -138.
addr4: 48 29 44 9999          # Get 8 - 9 = -1.
addr8: 42 222 8               # Repeatedly add 138 until positive.
addr11: 48 24 22              # Make sure the jumping target address to end the program is negative.
addr14: 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9       # Useless.
addr22: 48 222 2              # Subtract by 9 and end the program if negative.
addr25: 29 44 9999            # Increase the data pointer.
addr28: 222 8 9999            # Output the character.
addr31: 222 222 44            # Zero the character register.
addr34: 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 84 9  # 84 is for storing the divisor 138, negated.
addr44: 49 222 8 9 9          # Subtract the character register by the data. The last 9 is for getting -1.
addr49: 29489 9429 49429 28 8 8929 444 998 849 849 8929 848 28 8929 4882 24 428 289 28 429 8929 9429 24 2929 2929 428 924 29489 8929 84 8929 9289 24 429 992 24 849 8929 9429 24 2929 2929 428 4949 4829
```

9999s and all 9s except the last one are useless. They can be any numbers.

For each number `x` on the last line, the character code from the original string is `(-x - 9) % 138`, ended with `-8`.

Comment: I tried [Fission](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fission) before realizing both `A` and `Y` are blocked, which seemed making this impossible.

Answer (score 8):

## 3. [Udage](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Udage) (uses no `c`)

There must *not* be any trailing new lines.

```
a8aaaa844484aaaaa8484844aaaaa8848888aaaaa8884844aaaaa8848888aaaaa848844aaaaa844444aaaaa8448448aaaaa844888aaaaa8884884aaaaa8844848aaaaa844444aaaaa8844448aaaaa844444aaaaa8844884aaaaa8844848aaaaa8844848aaaaa8848844aaaaa8848448aaaaa8848884aaaaa8844888aaaaa844444aaaaa8884888aaaaa8844848aaaaa844888aaaaa8884484aaaaa8844848aaaaa844444aaaaa8848884aaaaa8848888aaaaa8884844aaaaa844444aaaaa8848448aaaaa8848884aaaaa844444aaaaa8448488aaaaa8844448aaaaa8848884aaaaa8884488aaaaa8844448aaaaa8884488aaaaa844444aaaaa8844448aaaaa8848884aaaaa8888448aaaaa8848848aaaaa8848888aaaaa8884484aaaaa8844848aaaaa848884aaaaa844484aaaaa844444aaaaa848848aaaaa844444aaaaa8444844aaaaa8848888aaaaa8884484aaaaa8848888aaaaa8884844aaaaa8848444aaaaa8888448aaaaa844444aaaaa8444888aaaaa8844448aaaaa8848844aaaaa8844848a
```

Output is quote 4:

```
"Toto, I've a feeling we're not in Kansas anymore." - Dorothy Gale
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80902/32353):

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./01235679:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters: `4` `8` `a`

---

Udage can be written in any symbols which makes it perfect for this challenge (Glypho used in answer 23 is similar). The length of each run of symbol determines the operation:

- A single character `x` toggles the bit value of the variable *x* (0 ↔ 1)
- If `x` is 1, the sequence `xxxx…x` will output the character composed by the binary digits in the "…". For instance, if `y == 1` and `z == 0`, then `xxxxyzzyzyx` will print 0b100101 i.e. `'%'`.

Therefore the structure of the program is simply:

1. `a8` — set `a` to 1 to allow output, set `4` to 0 and `8` to 1 for the binary digits
2. `aaaa844484a` — prints the character `"`
3. `aaaa8484844a` — and so on…

Generator (Python 3):

```
quote = '''"Toto, I've a feeling we're not in Kansas anymore." - Dorothy Gale'''
print('a8', end='')
for char in quote:
    digits = bin(ord(char))[2:].translate({0x30: '4', 0x31: '8'})
    print('aaaa', digits, 'a', end='', sep='')
```

Answer (score 8):

## 2. [Bueue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bueue), [first version](https://esolangs.org/w/index.php?title=Bueue&oldid=35456) (uses no `a`)

It works only in the interpreter in [this revision](https://esolangs.org/w/index.php?title=Bueue&oldid=35456) of the esolangs page, which has a bug that can end the program with an error. It prints the quote with an infinite stream of garbage in the latest interpreter.

```
84848484848488488484848848488484848888488848888848488484848484848884848484884888488484848488848488488488848484848848884848848484848848884848484884848484848488848884884888484848488488848848884888484884884848848484848484888488848848888848488484884848484848488848488484848884848484884888884848848488488884848488484848848484884848484848484884888488484884848484848488484884848484888484848488488884848848488884848848488888484884848848484848484884848484888488848484848848884888484848884888484848884848484884888488484848488848484848848884888848484848488488444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888484448888888884448
```

Output is quote 6:

```
"Go ahead, make my day." - Harry Callahan
```

Previously forbidden:

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./01235679:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters: `4` `8`

#### Generator

This program is generated using the following CJam program. Unfortunately I got it by trial and error and there are some hardcoded numbers that works only for this quote. It won't work if you replace the quote with something else.

```
"\"Go ahead, make my day.\" - Harry Callahan
":Q{i256+2b1>}%s0'1t'0/"06"*si
4/"1390"Q,*1>W<+si4*'1"06"6*+\+si4/
"02"'7275*"65139027777777639"]si32*
```

#### Explanations

The following subprograms are evaluated:

```
84848484848488488484848848488484848888488848888848488484848484848884848484884888488484848488848488488488848484848848884848848484848848884848484884848484848488848884884888484848488488848848884888484884884848848484848484888488848848888848488484884848484848488848488484848884848484884888884848848488488884848488484848848484884848484848484884888488484884848484848488484884848484888484848488488884848848488884848848488888484884848848484848484884848484888488848484848848884888484848884888484848884848484884888488484848488848484848848884888848484848488488444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448444844484448888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888484448888888884448
```

The first `8` does nothing because the queue is empty. The first `4` causes an error and quits this subprogram.

```
42424242424244244242424424244242424444244424444424244242424242424442424242442444244242424244424244244244424242424424442424424242424424442424242442424242424244424442442444242424244244424424442444242442442424424242424242444244424424444424244242442424242424244424244242424442424242442444442424424244244442424244242424424242442424242424242442444244242442424242424244242442424242444242424244244442424424244442424424244444242442424424242424242442424242444244424242424424442444242424442444242424442424242442444244242424244424242424424442444424242424244244222422242224222422242224222422242224222422242224222422242224222422242224222422242224222422242224222422242224222422242224222422242224222422242224222422242224222422242224444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444242224444444442224
```

The first `4` causes an error and quits this subprogram.

```
21212121212122122121212212122121212222122212222212122121212121212221212121221222122121212122212122122122212121212212221212212121212212221212121221212121212122212221221222121212122122212212221222121221221212212121212121222122212212222212122121221212121212122212122121212221212121221222221212212122122221212122121212212121221212121212121221222122121221212121212122121221212121222121212122122221212212122221212212122222121221212212121212121221212121222122212121212212221222121212221222121212221212121221222122121212122212121212212221222212121212122122111211121112111211121112111211121112111211121112111211121112111211121112111211121112111211121112111211121112111211121112111211121112111211121112111211121112111211121112222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222121112222222221112
```

It simply pushes a lot of `1`s and ignore all the `2`s.

```
1060606060606
10610606061060610606061110611061111060610606060606061106060606106110610606060611060610610611060606061061106061060606061061106060606106060606060611061106106110606060610611061061106110606106106061060606060606110611061061111060610606106060606060611060610606061106060606106111106061060610611106060610606061060606106060606060606106110610606106060606060610606106060606110606060610611106061060611106061060611110606106061060606060606106060606110611060606061061106110606061106110606061106060606106110610606060611060606061061106111060606060610610
55605560556055605560556055605560556055605560556055605560556055605560556055605560556055605560556055605560556055605560556055605560556055605560556055605560556055605560556111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111060556111111110556
```

The second line encodes the quote. `1` pushes 1. `06` pushes 0 and changes something that doesn't matter. The first line pushes something else so that the actual code in the final subprogram begins exactly when the quote is at the front of the queue.

```
5303030303030530530303053030530303055530553055553030530303030303055303030305305530530303030553030530530553030303053055303053030303053055303030305303030303030553055305305530303030530553053055305530305305303053030303030305530553053055553030530305303030303030553030530303055303030305305555303053030530555303030530303053030305303030303030305305530530305303030303030530305303030305530303030530555303053030555303053030555530305303053030303030305303030305530553030303053055305530303055305530303055303030305305530530303030553030303053055305553030303030530527802780278027802780278027802780278027802780278027802780278027802780278027802780278027802780278027802780278027802780278027802780278027802780278027802780278027802780278055555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555530278055555555278
```

`5` rotates an element, and `3` causes an error and quits this subprogram.

```
265151515151526526515152651526515152776527652777651526515151515152765151515265276526515151527651526526527651515152652765152651515152652765151515265151515151527652765265276515151526527652652765276515265265152651515151515276527652652777651526515265151515151527651526515152765151515265277765152651526527765151526515152651515265151515151515265276526515265151515151526515265151515276515151526527765152651527765152651527776515265152651515151515265151515276527651515152652765276515152765276515152765151515265276526515151527651515152652765277651515151526526
39013901390139013901390139013901390139013901390139013901390139013901390139013901390139013901390139013901390139013901390139013901390139013901390139013901390139013901390
277777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777651390
27777777639
```

The first line does something random: it removes, rotates and pushes some elements. After that, everything pushed before the actual code is either removed from the queue, or rotated to the end of the queue.

The second line is for printing the data. `01` pushes something at the end of the queue, but doesn't matter. `3` could trigger a loop but that never happens because the first bit of every character in the quote is 0. `9` dequeues and prints 8 bits as a character.

The third line removes elements in a loop. It would repeat if the front of the queue is 1 after an iteration. I made it remove so much things in one iteration so that it only needs to run for 3 iterations, to make it more likely that I could find a program that the front of queue always happens to be the right value. The `9` after the loop does nothing because there are less than 8 elements in the queue at that point.

In the fourth line the `7`s clear the queue, and the `3` causes an unchecked error when the queue is empty, which quits the whole program.

Answer (score 7):

## 67. Plain TeX, uses no `z`

```
^^5clet~^^5crelax
^^5cedef^^5cPARSEo^^7b~^^5cmeaning^v^^7d
^^5cdef^^5cPARSEii#1#2v^^7b^^5cdef^^5c1^^7b#1^^7d^^7d
^^5cdef~#1#2^^7b^^5cdef^^5c2^^7b#1^^7d^^5cPARSEii^^7d
^^5cPARSEo
^^5cwrite1^^7b^^22Mother^^Iof^^Imerc^^79^^2c^^Ii^^5c2^^Ithi^^5c2^^Ithe^^Iend^^Iof^^IRico?^^22^^I^^2d^^ICe^^5c2are^^IEnrico^^I^^22Rico^^22^^IBandello^^7d
``Mother^^Iof^^Imerc^^79^^2c^^Ii^^5c2^^Ithi^^5c2^^Ithe^^Iend^^Iof^^IRico?^^22^^I^^2d^^2d^^2d^^ICe^^5c2are^^IEnrico^^I``Rico^^22^^IBandello
^^5cb^^79e
```

Output is quote 73:

```
"Mother of mercy, is this the end of Rico?" - Cesare Enrico "Rico" Bandello
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40667) `py3\" ';({s[)<+.@=-,X0*/&]>`

I both `\write` the text to the console (and the log file), and typeset it.

TeX allows any character to be represented with `^^` followed by a hexadecimal code. This replacement is performed before lexical analysis. This allows most forbidden characters to be bypassed, but not those whose hexadecimal representation requires the forbidden digits `0` or `3`, so some other solution is needed for `p` and `s` (`p` turned out not to be needed for this quote). I extract them from the meaning of `^`. Here's the program with hexadecimal escapes replaced (and `^^I`, which TeX parses as a tab which is equivalent to a space).

```
\let~\relax
\edef\PARSEo{~\meaning^v}
\def\PARSEii#1#2v{\def\1{#1}}
\def~#1#2{\def\2{#1}\PARSEii}
\PARSEo
\write1{"Mother of mercy, i\2 thi\2 the end of Rico?" - Ce\2are Enrico "Rico" Bandello}
``Mother of mercy, i\2 thi\2 the end of Rico?" --- Ce\2are Enrico ``Rico" Bandello
\bye
```

I'd be curious to see a LaTeX solution.

Comment: LaTeX without { or \ seems difficult; then again, I don't know much high-level (or is it low-level?) LaTeX...

Comment: @archaephyrryx `\ ` has been forbidden for a very long time. That's not a problem thanks to `^^`. The real difficulty is actually the lack of `s`!

Comment: Just realized that we should have made a program out of the sequence of forbidden characters, perhaps something like [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38667/prolific-perfect-pangram-programs-pertaining-to-printable-ascii) or [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35787/whats-the-shortest-contiguous-subset-of-ascii-you-need-to-output-the-rest)

Answer (score 7):

## 49. [l33t](http://esolangs.org/wiki/L33t) (uses no `:`)

(Uses 55 newlines)

````
I`C222
D84D`P888Pll22Z!
in`Y44r
Drim2Z?
wH4il2
YOu2Z
aw8K?
D2aD
PPl5
li4K5
iN`6raVZ?
iN`cOffiN52Z?
w4lKin62`4r8unD5
li4K
r5GuLaR
P222Pl!
tH42Y
DOn`5t
C22
64cH
O4tHr!
tH88Y`9nlY`C666
wHAt2Z
tH8888Y`w4n9t`2`C222!`th8888Y
D888nt`Kn999w`th88Y`4r
D8884D!`H99w`9ft8n`D8
Y2u
C88`tH8888m?`4ll`t666H
Ti444m!`th8888Y`4r`8V8rYwH52r!

Y9u`Kn999w`t8H`a66iD65nt
uP`tH8888r?`Y5588h?`SOm6On6
gOt2Z
H664rt!`tH8888Y`D88D?`4`L4DY!`5H5
Di58D!`OM6!`wH4444t`c444n`Y8u`C88
H6r?`Y88885!`wH4888rZ5`i5
5H6?`5t4nDiN9999`N88%t`2`m44i
w88n6OW55!`cOl666`Y888u`4r
5c4Rin99`m66!`tH8888Y
Sc4r66
Mi4
2
5OmTim55!
tH2Y?
6H885t55!

Y99u`6V6r`f9888L`t666H
Pr8Kl5Y`tH8888nG5`8n`t6H`68cK
8f`Y99999r`n666cK?
Y2S!
4nD`t66h`T888nY`h44iR5
8n`Y8888r`4Rm`Y9u`Kn99w
wH888n`tH8888Y`5t4nD2
u9?`tH8888t5`tH688m!`wH88n
tH888Y`86tZ`m4D`iT`86tZ`cOlD!```5tOP9`l88Kin9`4t`m6!`i`D8888N`t`l44iK`P888Pl`L88Kin9`4t`m6`l44iK`tH888t
!!!
````

Output is quote 44:

```
"I see dead people." - Cole Sear
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41414/32522): `"#&'()*+,-./0137;<=>@[\]^_ deEhopQksvxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `$` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `456` `89`
- Uppercase: `ABCD` `FGHIJKLMNOP` `RSTUVW` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `fg` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

You can run it with a [C](http://web.archive.org/web/20051102205243/http://linuxfire.dhis.org/~alecs/code/l33t.c) or [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~yanick/Language-l33t-1.0.0/lib/Language/l33t.pm) interpreter.

---

l33t is a BF-like language with the following features:

- Opcodes are numbers 0-10 obtained by summing the digits in each word of the input; all non-digits are ignored but the programmer will be considered "teh sUxX0r" if they're left out.
- Increment, decrement, and pointer move instructions take an argument.
- Code and data share the same memory space, allowing for self-modifying code. This was used since some opcodes (1 and 3 for output and 'if') could not be coded directly due to character restrictions.

"Disassembly" of the program:

```
; Patch WRT (opcode 1)
BAK 40(+1)
DEC 2(+1)
; Patch IF (opcode 3)
BAK 2(+1)
DEC 2(+1)
; Move mem ptr to start of string
FWD 9(+1)
IF
  ; Output each char; stored as ASCII-30 (mod 256)
  INC 29(+1)
  WRT
  FWD 6(+1)
  BAK 5(+1)
EIF
END
; String starts here...
```

Comment: This is really great!

Answer (score 7):

## 42. [Beatnik](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beatnik) (uses no `$`)

(Newlines are only for poetic effect)

```
Man`Fail`but`will`Summit`

man`attain`but`attract`
man`bill`but`flaunt`
man`call`but`attract`
man`aim`but`act`
man`fan`but`inflict`
man`quit`but`jab`
man`calm`but`jam`
man`quit`but`climb`
man`mimic`but`inflict`
man`affirm`but`climb`
man`cram`but`jab`
man`quit`but`maim`
man`cut`but`bar`
man`quit`but`mimic`
man`affirm`but`jam`
man`affirm`but`inflict`
man`maul`but`jab`
man`calm`but`quit`
man`jam`but`flaunt`
man`ram`but`nab`
man`cram`but`trim`
man`taunt`but`rub`
man`built`but`train`
man`attract`but`win`
man`flaunt`but`quit`
man`inflict`but`climb`
man`affirm`but`mimic`
man`act`but`jab`
man`fall`but`quit`
man`affirm`but`climb`
man`aim`but`quit`
man`cut`but`bar`
man`maim`but`quit`
man`jam`but`nab`
man`affirm`but`quit`
man`quit`but`mimic`
man`affirm`but`inflict`
man`mimic`but`climb`
man`affirm`but`jab`
man`quit`but`jam`
man`rub`but`ram`
man`fill`but`attain`
man`climb`but`inflict`
man`mimic`but`jab`
man`affirm`but`climb`
man`maintain`but`crawl`
man`flit`but`taunt`

FIGHT!`LASH!
ATTACK!`THRASH!
ASSAULT!`MARCH!
GUARD!`SLAY!`FAST!
Man`AVIDLY`Can`CLASH!
FAST`LURCH!`Panic!
PATCH!`DISPATCH!`CRAZY!

MOST`DIPLOMATIC?
```

Output is quote 48:

```
"Well, nobody's perfect." - Osgood Fielding III
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41604/32522): `"#&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ BdeEghJNopQksvWxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `46` `89`
- Uppercase: `A` `CD` `FGHI` `KLM` `OP` `RSTUV` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

You can run it with [this Perl interpreter](http://paste.lisp.org/display/2571). Some other interpreters may not work correctly since they explicitly look for whitespace, even though the [spec](http://cliffle.com/esoterica/beatnik.html) says that words may be "separated by any sort of punctuation."

---

Beatnik is a stack-based language whose operations are determined by the Scrabble score of each word. For instance, "man" scores 5 points, and the corresponding operation pushes the score of the next word onto the stack.

- The title of the poem generates a 0 on the stack so the display loop knows when to end.
- The first verse pushes the characters on in reverse order. Each character is represented by 2 values in the range of 5-14.
- The second verse is the display loop. Each character is generated from its values by `ASCII = 32 + (top_value-5)*10 + (bottom_value-5)` and is output.
- The final line empties the stack and ends the program.

Answer (score 6):

## 94. JavaScript, uses no `p`

```js
document.write('"I\'ll get you, my &#112;retty, and your little dog, too!" - Wicked Witch of the West');
```

Output is quote 99. (Run the snippet.)

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40563/32376) *none*

Answer (score 6):

## 88. CJam, uses no `'`

```
24A+77_;121S112_))101_((105_;111_;117_((46_;24A+S45S71_;111_(((_117_;109]:c
```

Output is quote 85:

```
"My precious." - Gollum
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40579/8478) `py3\"<space>`

Answer (score 6):

## 70. [Gibberish](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Gibberish) (uses no `&`)

(Newlines are for clarification only. They are not necessary.)

```
e
289amgteq
725mmgteq
7867amagteq
6991aamgteq
4956amagteq
2956amagteq
4147mamgteq
48mgteq
5145mamgteq
4147mamgteq
456amgteq
48mgteq
289magteq
8899maagteq
8956amagteq
2956amagteq
456amgteq
48mgteq
5145mamgteq
4147mamgteq
956magteq
5744mamgteq
48mgteq
479magteq
867amgteq
5145mamgteq
2556ammgteq
8899maagteq
4147mamgteq
7867amagteq
789amgteq
2556ammgteq
159magteq
289amgteq
48mgteq
59mgteq
48mgteq
489magteq
8899maagteq
789amgteq
6991aamgteq
2956amagteq
2556ammgteq
956amgteq
2956amagteq
48mgteq
699magteq
8899maagteq
269mmgteq
5744mamgteq
867amgteq
```

Output is quote 74.

```
"Forget it, Jake, it's Chinatown." - Lawrence Walsh
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40634/32353): `py3\" ';({s[)<+.@=-,X0*/`

The interpretor on http://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Marinus/Gibberish_interpreter is used to verify the result.

---

Gibberish is a stack machine. Every digit 0–9 pushes that number onto the stack, `m` is multiplication, `a` is addition (e.g. `289am` means `(9+8)×2 = 34`), and `gteq` pops a number and prints the corresponding ASCII character. So every line in the program prints a single character of the quote.

Answer (score 6):

## 44. [Dupdog](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Dupdog) mod 257 (uses no `g`)

There are 13,141 characters in the source code, it consists only of the characters `a` and `?`:

```
a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a???????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????a??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

or as this base64-encoded zlib-compressed data:

```
eJzt2LENxDAMQ9HRMov3XyJVuhQ2YJuU+N8CJiUFONx4Mgx1AITKvbw6zeskXaVupn5/VpWcq7r2
Anbr/q107+dOP399Ap3k7pinuxMutD92nI3918CeTmK6ORx+T93KwF37Yje52P1dSfNO6vpPPQH1
+3NqpOyJ2X9SJ5Ha2412Dydfr3BhDhk9LsBhEvdltgaS1PjKHf4Xzk2Ag14Edqi8
```

The SHA-1 sum should be 5f4eb39aa6c8d5d904d0dfc8c7f20619c8099874. There shouldn't be any trailing new lines.

Output is quote 54:

```
"There's no crying in baseball!" - Jimmy Dugan
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41569/32353): `"#&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ BdeEhJopQksvWxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `$` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `46` `89`
- Uppercase: `A` `CD` `FGHI` `KLMNOP` `RSTUV` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

---

Dupdog is a thing that looks like a self-modifying language. It works like this:

1. Read the first character from the code string, and then feed it to the `mfit` interpreter:

   - If the character is `~`, duplicate the source code
   - Else if the character is `?`, and the length of the source code is odd, do nothing. Otherwise, rotate the characters `?` → `!` → `~` → `?`.
   - Otherwise, print out the length of the source code mod 257 as an ASCII character. The modulus is customizable but I follow the example from esolang which is 257.
2. Remove that character from the code string.
3. Read the first character from the remaining code string, and then feed it to the `shanty` interpreter:

   - If the character if `!`, duplicate the source code.
   - Else if the character is `?`, reverse the source code.
   - Otherwise, print out the length of the source code as an integer, then stop the program.
4. Remove that character from the code string.
5. Repeat from step 1.

There is a Hello world example from esolang, which one could easily see the pattern:

- print character
- series of `rev;nop;rev;nop;...` to pad the code length.
- print character
- ...

So here is a highly inefficient compiler to generate the dupdog source code above:

```python
def compile_quote(quote):
    # Determine the positions where the character needs to be printed.
    lengths = []
    for c in reversed(quote):
        code = ord(c)
        if lengths:
            delta = (code - lengths[-1]) % 257
            if delta == 0:
                delta = 257

            code = delta + lengths[-1]
            if code % 2 == 0:
                code += 257
        else:
            if code % 2 == 0:
                code += 257
        lengths.append(code)

    print(lengths)

    # Build up the source code.
    final_code = ''
    for length in lengths:
        while len(final_code) < length-1:
            if len(final_code) % 2 == 1:
                final_code = '?' + final_code[::-1]
            else:
                final_code = '?' + final_code
        final_code = 'a' + final_code

    return final_code
```

Comment: There are so many crazy languages I've never heard of being showcased here. Awesome.

Comment: I wonder if there are any non-esoteric languages left that can compete in the challenge at this point.

Comment: @gone_native I highly doubt it. The banning of `(` is pretty fatal for non-esoteric languages. Even esoteric languages are hard to find these days.

Comment: If there's ever a chance, I'm guessing either some BASIC variant or other old-school imperative language, or another "machine code in ASCII" like the [80386 answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40771/32522). I looked into 8051 until I found the code memory isn't modifiable.

Answer (score 6):

## 13. [Villmark](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Villmark) (uses no `u`)

```
caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8caDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDanDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDr8cDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDan
```

Output is quote 10:

```
"You talking to me?" - Travis Bickle
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42089/25180):

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFfgGhHiIjJkLmMNoOpPqQRsTUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters:

- Numbers: `4` `8` `9`
- Uppercase: `D` `K` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `l` `n` `r` `t` `w`

I don't know how it works exactly... and there is no easy way to debug this code.

`caDDD....an` or `cDDD...an` outputs the character 2*number of `D`s + number of `a`s, assuming the current, previous and next cell are all zero at the beginning.

After output, the three cells will be messed up which I don't know how to fix using the available characters. Instead I just changed the memory position (and cleared them) using `r8`. Villmark has only 256 bytes of memory so I tried to move as short as possible.

The current memory cell after output will be the outputed character if there were one `a`, or the character negated if there were two (I guessed). Each `D` will decrease it by 4. I decreased it a few times so it will be a number from 1 to 4 (or from -255 to -252) before `r8`. But I don't really know how many times the current cell value the pointer will move.

Repeat the `caDDD....anDDD...r8` to output other characters.

I didn't get those numbers right after rereading the documentation a few times. So I just tested and saw what has happened.

#### Generator (in CJam)

It works for shorter strings. But it need some workaround (by removing some `D`s) to print this quote.

```
q{'c\i_(2md_'a*@'D*@{@255\-}{@(}?4/'D*"an"\"r8"}/
```

Comment: How does the generator work (I don't understand CJam)?

Comment: @anatolyg Added some explanation.

Comment: [Ashtol](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ashtol) looks like a good language for this challenge. But now it is too late for that...

Answer (score 6):

## 11. [BSM](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BSM) (uses no `r`)

It begins with:

```
9taKSlS48SlS48SlS48SlS48SlS48SlS48SlS48SlS48SlS48SlS48SlS48SlS48S...
```

and ends with:

```
...atwK4cacla9taKSlS48SlS48SlS48SlS48SlS48SlS48SlS48SlS48449SatwK4aa
```

bzip2 base64:

```
QlpoOTFBWSZTWdZ9lFcAFjZPgAAQBGAACAgAKAQEgDABWUiCT1VQwmEA000BSVTCaad8SHciUnMh
3IZJVJzLrVL2Q0h+kSk8kPKFt0q1ttFMSNisVJqqIbKI2KVmJbSm1stlErYg22olsBbS2UbLa20W
xtrRbFajQQVo1Y1otaLYxaqNGSioxsUWNaGaNqBmkzWyznkh7IeekPZD4Q6IfJEpOCHkhxIdSH8X
ckU4UJDWfZRX
```

Or see it here: http://pastebin.com/G15g57P4

Output is quote 7:

```
"All right, Mr. DeMille, I'm ready for my close-up." - Norma Desmond
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42121/25180):

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdDeEFfgGhHiIjJkLmMNoOpPqQRsTuUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters:

- Numbers: `4` `8` `9`
- Uppercase: `K` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `l` `n` `t` `w`

I gave up working on [VTL](http://esolangs.org/wiki/VTL). I think it should be possible in VTL. But it is not easy to golf the program into 256 bytes... And it should be a bad idea using esoteric binary languages. There should be much more useful instructions in a real machine code...

Explanations later. I wrote a program to search for solutions. And it generated this code with the `SlS48` pattern.

Now I have 3 usable languages left, including one for answer 1 and one for answer 2. And the 3rd one won't be likely unusable soon. I'm not sure I should post them. I have a 4th one which can print the quote, but will exit with an error. I'm not sure I can use it...

Comment: I don't understand what the code is. The answer specifies only the beginning and the end, and omits the middle. Is there any kind of repeating pattern in the middle? If yes, what is it, and how many times is it repeated? If not, maybe you should describe how the code can be generated. (I see that this answer was upvoted; did I miss something?)

Comment: @anatolyg It was in the base64 encoded bzip2 file. Now I added a pastebin link.

Comment: If it weren't for an interpreter bug, I'd finally have a VTL solution now. :(

Comment: @gone_native What's the bug then?

Comment: @user23013 It's in the "Stop executing instructions" instruction (0xCF)-- the interpreter enters a loop, waiting for the current instruction to be a "Start" (0xCE), at which point it will resume execution. The problem is the Program Counter doesn't change in the loop, so the interpreter just hangs on the instruction following a Stop. I can't absolutely confirm that the intent was to increment the PC, searching for a Start, but the current behavior makes Start and Stop instructions useless.

Comment: (cont'd) The VTL solution using Start/Stop has 3 sections of code: (1) Initial patching, which tweaks a few values in Section 3, then enables only Section 2, (2) Patching loop, which sets up all of the character output instructions in Section 3; at the end of the loop, the Stop instruction before Section 3 gets turned into a no-op, (3) Output, when executed, consisting of just increment, decrement, and output instructions. I've tried the same approach just using Jumps, but the patching process for that uses too much memory.

Comment: @gone_native Just to be clear - did you disassemble the VTL interpreter to discover what it does?

Answer (score 5):

## 92. C++, uses no `3`

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void){
    std::cout << "\"M\x79 mother thanks \x79ou. M\x79 father thanks \x79ou. M\x79 sister thanks \x79ou. And I thank \x79ou.\" - George M. Cohan" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is quote 97:

```
"My mother thanks you. My father thanks you. My sister thanks you. And I thank you." - George M. Cohan
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40567/18671): `py`

Comment: Remove `return 0;` and `void` for me please. It makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: @nwp although the `void` is redundant in C++, I like to write it nevertheless, to make the program more C-compliant, so it's a matter of taste, I guess. What's wrong with `return`ing `0` though?

Comment: `return 0;` from `main` has no meaning just like the `void`. It technically does not matter, but somehow meaningless code bothers me.

Comment: @nwp We may be able to argue about the `void`, but `return 0;` is actually important if you want to write sandards-compliant code! `main` is of type `int`, so that's what you should be returning; `0` generally being used to indicate a successful computation. The only reason you can omit `return 0;` inside `main` is because your compiler is being nice and does it for you :)

Comment: Actually the reason you can omit `return 0;` in `main` is because the C++ standard says so in `§ 3.6.1.5`: _If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;_

Comment: @Flonk No `return 0` and `void`, please?

Comment: @nwp Seems like you're right! This even appears to be true for C99 and C11. I was under the firm belief that some standard required you to return either EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE.

Comment: @nwp Got it, it's C89 - I cooked up an example where omitting the return statement gave an errorlevel of 12. It probably never hurts to be explicit, although you're probably right when you say that it's pretty useless.

Answer (score 5):

## 86. [Unary](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary), uses no `(`

The program is just zeroes, where there are

```
3370971879267571102231643973781960767867550138500652727650351697850864913411545006931190734691180553937006013507681275962201778225289692044082143520288261965332265972154319968050788756511250725103270946807157425544153602650433669066963868896995130901490782639979913121839366119236608463113517743139855522117600450690578894187500712399026355375661695529787727754868007581380838269928497117227554954220591057529108858620184618835905762023825471169929147497610275266918823110420309701824429054183904188114619210248612265864818110705898215160364915125191320132175721938926287431875255258020269868850949033884281079645023697188921092389981998559383107732
```

of them.

Output is quote 86:

```
"Attica! Attica!" - Sonny Wortzik
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40583/21487) `py3\" ';`

Corresponding BF:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++..-----------.------.--.----------------------------------------------------------------.-.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++..-----------.------.--.----------------------------------------------------------------.+.--.+++++++++++++.-------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-..+++++++++++.-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++.++.++++++.-----------------.++.
```

Comment: You can't use quote 9

Comment: @Mig Sorry, I seem to have missed the part in the spec concerning that. Is it good now?

Comment: That paren is killing me! Now I have to deal with 3 in my hex strings!

Comment: I would say that's a big number.

Answer (score 5):

## 83. [ABC](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ABC) (uses no `[`)

```
$aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacbbbbbbbbcbbbbbbcbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcbcaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacbbbbbbbbcbbbbbbcbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcacbbcaaaaaaaaaaaaacbbbbbbbbbbbbbcaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacbbbbbbbcaaaaaacbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaacbcbbbbbcbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcbbcaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaacbcbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacacbbbbbbbbcaaaaaaaaaaaaaac
```

Output is quote 82:

```
"Toga! Toga!" - John "Bluto" Blutarsky
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40587/19759): `py3\" ';({s`

Sadly, all implementations at [esolangs wiki's ABC page](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ABC) are not available. But I used [4chan's Scheme implementation (#59 at link)](http://dis.4chan.org/read/prog/1217371234) to confirm.

You can test this code by pasting below code into Scheme REPL:

```
(define (abc source)
  (define accumulator 0)
  (define ascii #f)
  (define (interpret i)
    (cond ((char-ci=? i #\a) (set! accumulator (+ 1 accumulator)))
          ((char-ci=? i #\b) (set! accumulator (- 1 accumulator)))
          ((char-ci=? i #\c) (display (if (eq? #t ascii) 
                                          (integer->char accumulator) 
                                          accumulator)))
          ((char-ci=? i #\d) (set! accumulator (* (- 1) accumulator)))
          ((char-ci=? i #\r) (set! accumulator (random accumulator)))
          ((char-ci=? i #\n) (set! accumulator 0))
          ((char-ci=? i #\$) (set! ascii (not ascii)))
          ((char-ci=? i #\l) (run))
          ((char-ci=? i #\;) (display accumulator)
                             (display (integer->char accumulator)))))
  (define (run)
    (for-each interpret (string->list source))
    (newline))
  (run))
```

and run:

```
(abc "$aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacbbbbbbbbcbbbbbbcbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcbcaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacbbbbbbbbcbbbbbbcbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcacbbcaaaaaaaaaaaaacbbbbbbbbbbbbbcaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacbbbbbbbcaaaaaacbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaacbcbbbbbcbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcbbcaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaacbcbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacacbbbbbbbbcaaaaaaaaaaaaaac")
```

Answer (score 5):

## 80. [DNA#](http://esolangs.org/wiki/DNA-Sharp), uses no `+`

```
ATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATGCATGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCAT
```

Output is quote 79:

```
Striker: "Surely you can't be serious." Rumack: "I am serious...and don't call me Shirley." - Ted Striker and Dr. Rumack
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40595/21487) `py3\" ';({s[)<`

Corresponding BF:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.--.---------.++.------.+++++++++++++.--------------------------------------------------------.--------------------------.++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.---.-------------.+++++++.+++++++++++++.-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.----------.++++++.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.--.+++++++++++++.-----------------------------------------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++.---------------------------------------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.--------------.+++++++++++++.---------.++++++.++++++.--.---------------------------------------------------------------------.------------.--.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.--------.------------.++.++++++++.-------------------------------------------------.--------------------------.++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-----------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++.-----------------------------------------------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.--------------.+++++++++++++.---------.++++++.++++++.--.---------------------------------------------------------------------...+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++.----------.--------------------------------------------------------------------.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++.-.-----------------------------------------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.--.+++++++++++..----------------------------------------------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.--------.---------------------------------------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++.+.+++++++++.------.-------.++++++++++++++++++++.---------------------------------------------------------------------------.------------.--.+++++++++++++.-------------.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++.-.--------------------------------------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.--.---------.++.------.+++++++++++++.----------------------------------------------------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++.----------.--------------------------------------------------------------------.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.--------------------------------------------------------------------.--------------.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.--------.------------.++.++++++++.
```

<strike>...and that rules out half the BF derivatives.</strike> (Edit: Actually it doesn't - in hindsight I should have picked `.`)

Comment: Where'd you get the interpreter for this? I've looked previously but couldn't find one...

Comment: @BetaDecay There's one at the bottom of the esolang page, but it doesn't seem to work for me. In any case, I've only used 3 BF symbols, and since the BF worked and DNA-sharp is just a symbol substitution for those, I figured it'd be okay.

Comment: @Sp3000 The actual name of the language is **DNA#**. [*The title of this article is incorrect because of technical limitations. The correct title is DNA#.*](http://esolangs.org/wiki/DNA-Sharp)

Comment: @mbomb007 Edited

Answer (score 5):

## 77. J, uses no `=`

```
u:77-/~111,155,188,109,196,182,191,178,109,181,174,187,180,178,191,192,121,109,178,195,178,191,110,111,109,122,109,151,188,174,187,109,144,191,174,196,179,188,191,177
```

Output is quote 72:

```
"No wire hangers, ever!" - Joan Crawford
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40606/4020) `py3\" ';({s[)<+.@`

Answer (score 5):

## 53. [evil](http://esolangs.org/wiki/evil) (no `1`)

Whitespace unnecessary.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawaaaaaaaaaawaaaaaaaawaaaaaaaaaaawuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuwaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuwaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawuuuu
waaaaawaaaaaaawuwuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuwuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuwuuuuuuuuuuuuwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuwaaaaaaaawaaaaaaaaaaawuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawuuuuwaaaaawaaaaaaawuwuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuwuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuwuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawaaaaaawuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawaaaaaaaawaaaaawuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuwaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaawuuuwuuuuwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawuuuuuuuuuuuuuuwuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawawaaaaaw
uuuuuuuuuuuuwawaaaaawuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuwuuuuuuuwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuwawuuwaaaaaaaaaaaaawuuuuuuuuuuuuuwaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawaaaaaaaa
aawuuwuuuuwuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaawawaaaaaaawaaaaawawaaaaaaaawuuuuuuuuuuuuuuwaaaaaaaaaaawaaaaaawu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawaawaaaaaaaawu
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaawuuuuuuuuuuuuuwaaaaaaawaaaaaw
```

Output is quote 67 `"Of all the gin joints in all the towns in all the world, she walks into mine." - Rick Blaine`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `$` `%` `:` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `456` `89`
- Uppercase: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP` `RSTUVW` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `fghijklmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

Comment: Surely you could golf that down further. ;)

Answer (score 5):

### 18. [ferNANDo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ferNANDo) (Uses no `2`)

```
w w
D
l
u D
c u u
H l i
r n n
S u n
K S S
t n H
f t t
H H
O O
a f w a a f O f
a t n H c S c r
a K w a u r S a
a u n r K u K K
a K w a w w t f
O n
n D
i i
l i
l
D D
D
```

*(58 tabs, 24 newlines)*

Output is quote 15:

```
"E.T. phone home." - E.T.
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42001/4098):

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./013567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFgGhIjJkLmMNopPqQRsTUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: none
- Numbers: `4` `8` `9`
- Uppercase: `D` `H` `K` `O` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `i` `l` `n` `r` `t` `u` `w`

An interpreter written in Python can be found at the link in the title.

---

**ferNANDo** is an esoteric language that only supports one variable type, boolean, and only one operator, NAND. The above program loops 5 times, printing a different 5 characters every time. Each of the 'print statements' (lines with 8 variables) encode for 5 bytes of output. Not quite as trivial as it might sound, although the hardest part was reducing the number of necessary tabs below 64.

Comment: I think you could still do it with only one unique character. And this was another candidate for answer 1. But it was surprising knowing ferNANDo works in this challenge, with only 64 tabs.

Comment: @user23013 ahh yes, using the variables `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, etc. The tab restriction is fairly hard, though. Any output longer than ~30 bytes would be nigh impossible.

Answer (score 5):

## 4. [1L_a105](http://esolangs.org/wiki/1L_a) (uses no `S`)

Bzip2 base64:

```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==
```

Or see it here: http://pastebin.com/083XbrLW

Note that the trailing newline is required.

This image does the same thing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdWDE.png

And to demonstrate, this program outputs `"Love means`:

```
c8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888c8
c8cc888ccc88888ccc888888888888888888ccc888888888888888888ccc88888ccc888888888888888888ccc888888888888888888ccccccccccc88888cccc88ccc88888ccc888888888888888888ccc88888ccc888888888888cccc88ccc88888ccc88888888888888888ccccccccccc8888888888ccc8888888888888888888ccc88888ccc88888888888888888ccc88888ccc888888888888cccc88ccccccccccc8888888888ccc88888ccc888888888888cccc88ccccccccccc8888888888ccc888888888888888888ccccccccccc8888888888ccc888888888888888888ccccccccccc88888cccc88ccccccccccc88888cccc88ccc88888ccc888888888888888888ccc888888888888888888ccc88888ccc88888888888888888ccc88888ccc88888888888888888ccccccccccc8888888888ccc8888888888888888888ccc88888ccc888888888888cccc88ccccccccccc88888cccc88ccccccccccc8888888888ccc888888888888888888ccccccccccc88888cccc88ccccccccccc88888cccc88ccccccccccc8888888888ccc888888888888888888ccc88888ccc88888888888888888ccccccccccc88888cccc88ccccccccccc8888888888ccc8888888888888888888ccc88888ccc88888888888888888ccc888888888888888888ccccccccccc8888888888ccc88888ccc888888888888cccc88ccc88888ccc888888888888888888ccc88888ccc88888888c8
c8cccc8c8c88888c8c888888888888cccc88c8c88888888888888ccc8c8c88888c8c888888888888cccc88c8c88888888888888ccc8cccc888888c88888c88c88c8c88888c8c888888888888cccc88c8c88888c8c888888888888c88c88c8c88888c8c8888888888888ccc8cccc888888c888888ccc8c8c8888888888888cccc88c8c88888c8c8888888888888ccc8c8c88888c8c888888888888c88c88cccc888888c888888ccc8c8c88888c8c888888888888c88c88cccc888888c888888ccc8c8c88888888888888ccc8cccc888888c888888ccc8c8c88888888888888ccc8cccc888888c88888c88c88cccc888888c88888c88c88c8c88888c8c888888888888cccc88c8c88888888888888ccc8c8c88888c8c8888888888888ccc8c8c88888c8c8888888888888ccc8cccc888888c888888ccc8c8c8888888888888cccc88c8c88888c8c888888888888c88c88cccc888888c88888c88c88cccc888888c888888ccc8c8c88888888888888ccc8cccc888888c88888c88c88cccc888888c88888c88c88cccc888888c888888ccc8c8c88888888888888ccc8c8c88888c8c8888888888888ccc8cccc888888c88888c88c88cccc888888c888888ccc8c8c8888888888888cccc88c8c88888c8c8888888888888ccc8c8c88888888888888ccc8cccc888888c888888ccc8c8c88888c8c888888888888c88c88c8c88888c8c888888888888cccc88c8c88888c8c88888888c8
c88c8c8c8c88888c8ccc8888888888c88c88c8c888888888cccccccc8c8c88888c8ccc8888888888c88c88c8c888888888cccccccc888c8888888c88888c88c88c8c88888c8ccc8888888888c88c88c8c88888c8ccc8888888888c88c88c8c88888c8ccc888888cccccccc888c8888888c8cccccccc8c8c8888888888888c88c88c8c88888c8ccc888888cccccccc8c8c88888c8ccc8888888888c88c8888c8888888c8cccccccc8c8c88888c8ccc8888888888c88c8888c8888888c8cccccccc8c8c888888888cccccccc888c8888888c8cccccccc8c8c888888888cccccccc888c8888888c88888c88c8888c8888888c88888c88c88c8c88888c8ccc8888888888c88c88c8c888888888cccccccc8c8c88888c8ccc888888cccccccc8c8c88888c8ccc888888cccccccc888c8888888c8cccccccc8c8c8888888888888c88c88c8c88888c8ccc8888888888c88c8888c8888888c88888c88c8888c8888888c8cccccccc8c8c888888888cccccccc888c8888888c88888c88c8888c8888888c88888c88c8888c8888888c8cccccccc8c8c888888888cccccccc8c8c88888c8ccc888888cccccccc888c8888888c88888c88c8888c8888888c8cccccccc8c8c8888888888888c88c88c8c88888c8ccc888888cccccccc8c8c888888888cccccccc888c8888888c8cccccccc8c8c88888c8ccc8888888888c88c88c8c88888c8ccc8888888888c88c88c8c88888c8ccc888888c8
cccccc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8ccc8ccccc8c8ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8ccc8ccccc8c8ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc888ccccc8ccc8ccc8c88cc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8ccc8ccccc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8ccc8c88cc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8cc8c8ccc888ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8ccc8ccc8ccccc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8ccc8c88cc888ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8ccc8c88cc888ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc888ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc888ccccc8ccc8ccc8c88cc888ccccc8ccc8ccc8c88cc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8ccc8ccccc8c8ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8cc8c8ccc888ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8ccc8ccc8ccccc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8ccc8c88cc888ccccc8ccc8ccc8c88cc888ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc888ccccc8ccc8ccc8c88cc888ccccc8ccc8ccc8c88cc888ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8cc8c8ccc888ccccc8ccc8ccc8c88cc888ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8ccc8ccc8ccccc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc888ccccc8ccc8cc8c8ccc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8ccc8c88cc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8ccc8ccccc8c8ccccc8c888c8cccc8c8
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
88c8888888888c8cccccccccc888c8c88888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8cccccccccc888c8c88888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8c88888c8c88888888888c8cccccccccc888c8c88888888888c8cccccccccc888c8c88888888888c8cccccccccc8888c8c888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8c88888c8c88888888888c8cccccccccc8888c8c888888888c8cccccccccc888c8c88888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8cccccccccc888c8c88888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8c88888c8c88888888888c8c88888c8c88888888888c8cccccccccc888c8c88888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8cccccccccc8888c8c888888888c8cccccccccc8888c8c888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8c88888c8c88888888888c8cccccccccc888c8c88888888888c8c88888c8c88888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8c88888c8c88888888888c8c88888c8c88888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8cccccccccc8888c8c888888888c8c88888c8c88888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8c88888c8c88888888888c8cccccccccc8888c8c888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8c888888c8c888888888c8cccccccccc888c8c88888888888c8cccccccccc888c8c88888888888c8cccccccccc8c8
88cccccccccccc8888888cccccccc8ccccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8888888cccccccc8ccccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8ccccccc8ccccccccccccc8888888cccccccc8ccccccccccccc8888888cccccccc8ccccccccccccc8888888ccccccccc8ccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8ccccccc8ccccccccccccc8888888ccccccccc8ccccccccccc8888888cccccccc8ccccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8888888cccccccc8ccccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8ccccccc8ccccccccccccc8ccccccc8ccccccccccccc8888888cccccccc8ccccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8888888ccccccccc8ccccccccccc8888888ccccccccc8ccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8ccccccc8ccccccccccccc8888888cccccccc8ccccccccccccc8ccccccc8ccccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8ccccccc8ccccccccccccc8ccccccc8ccccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8888888ccccccccc8ccccccccccc8ccccccc8ccccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8ccccccc8ccccccccccccc8888888ccccccccc8ccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8cccccccc8ccccccccccc8888888cccccccc8ccccccccccccc8888888cccccccc8ccccccccccccc8888888cccccc8
8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
```

And the image version which only outputs `Love`:

[image]

Output is quote 13:

```
"Love means never having to say you're sorry." - Jennifer Cavilleri Barrett
```

Previously forbidden:

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./01235679:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRstTuUvVwWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters: `4` `8` `a` `c`

#### Generator (in CJam)

```
q{i2b8Ue[~}%ee2af.%2aa..+
{~
[["888888888888888888888888
888888888888888888888888
888888888888ccc888888888
8888888cccccccc888888888
8888888cc8c8ccc888ccccc8
88c8888cc8c8c888888888c8
88c8888888c8c888888888c8
88ccccccccc8ccccccccccc8
888888888888888888888888"
"8888888888888888888888888
88888888888cccc8888888888
88888888888c88c8888888888
88888888888c88c8888888888
8888888ccc8c88cc888ccccc8
88c8888ccccccccc8888888c8
88c888888c8c88888888888c8
88cccccccc8ccccccccccccc8
8888888888888888888888888"
"8888888888888888888888888
8888888888888888888888888
88888888888cccc8888888888
88888888888c88c8888888888
8888888ccc8ccccc888ccccc8
88c8888cccccc8cc8888888c8
88c888888c8c88888888888c8
88cccccccc8ccccccccccccc8
8888888888888888888888888"]
["8888888888888888888888
ccc88888ccc88888888888
c8c88888c8c88888888888
c8c88888c8ccc888888888
c8888888c888c888cccc88
ccccccccccccc888888c88
88888888cccccccccccc88
8888888888888888888888
8888888888888888888888"
"8888888888888888
ccc8888888888888
c8c8888888888888
c8c8888888888888
c888888888ccc888
ccccccccccccc888
8888888888888888
8888888888888888
8888888888888888"
"8888888888888888
ccccccccccccc888
cccc88888888c888
88c888888888c888
8888888888ccc888
8888888888888888
8888888888888888
8888888888888888
8888888888888888"]
["c88888888888888
c8cc88888888888
c8cccc888888888
c88c8c888888888
cccccc888ccccc8
88cc888888888c8
88c8888888888c8
88cccccccccccc8
888888888888888"
"c888888888888888
c888888888888888
c8cccc8888888888
c8c88c8888888888
c8c88c8888ccccc8
c8c88ccc888888c8
cccccccc888888c8
88ccccccccccccc8
8888888888888888"]]
@=T@:T-=}%
_,
["88888888c8
88888888c8
88888888c8
88888888c8
88888888c8
88c88888c8
88c88888c8
88ccccccc8
8888888888"
"88c
88c
88c
88c
888
888
888
888
888"]=a+
Nf/{1$z,8-S*f{\+}..e>}*
z{_2$=1$'ce=1=&{;}*}*]zN*N
```

My last language to use.

Comment: Yay! Looks like we can finally complete this.

Comment: @kennytm Now your turn.

Answer (score 4):

## 93. Ruby, uses no `y`

```
$><< '"Nobod' + "\u{79} \u{70}uts Bab\u{79}" + ' in a corner." - Johnn' + "\u{79} Castle"
```

Output is quote 98:

```
"Nobody puts Baby in a corner." - Johnny Castle
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40566/32045) `p`

Answer (score 4):

## 74. [Deadfish~](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish~), uses no `X`

```
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciciiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiicciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiciciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciiiiiiiiiic
```

Output is quote 75:

```
"I have always depended on the kindness of strangers." - Blanche DuBois
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40610/21487) `py3\" ';({s[)<+.@=-,`

Not a BF variant! Works with the Python interpreter on esolang wiki, but it only prints out the first few characters before it blows the stack (!?)

Comment: `X`? lame... ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I'm sniping :P http://esolangs.org/wiki/Puzzlang

Comment: I think `0` would snipe a lot more. ;)

Answer (score 4):

## 68. [WASD](http://esolangs.org/wiki/WASD) (uses no `>`)

I wrote <s>a Haskell program to generate</s> this. This is my first time doing actual coding in a BF derivative/equivalent. This is a coup de grâce to most future BF-derivatives, as now all `[].,+-<>` are all forbidden.

```
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwedwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwed
```

Output is quote 65:

`"Elementary, my dear Watson." - Sherlock Holmes`

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40664/31387): `py3\" ';({s[)<+.@=-,X0*/&]`

Here is [my interpreter](https://github.com/archaephyrryx/WASD/blob/master/wasd.py), which is mostly identical to the one linked on the Esolangs page, except that it prints chars on the same line.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Fixing it now!

Answer (score 4):

## 63. [Rexx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rexx) (uses no `v`)

```
CALL    d2c 48
PARSE   VAR RESULT  Z
CALL    d2c 51
PARSE   VAR RESULT  T
CALL    x2c 224C697||T||74656E2||Z||746F2||Z||7468656D2E2||Z||4||T||68696C6472656E2||Z||6F662||Z||7468652||Z||6E696768742E2||Z||576861742||Z||6D757||T||696||T||2||Z||746865792||Z||6D616B652E222||Z||2D2||Z||4||T||6F756E742||Z||4472616||T||756C61
SAY RESULT
```

Output is quote 83.

```
"Listen to them. Children of the night. What music they make." - Count Dracula
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40718/32353): `"'&()*+-,./\03;<=>@X[soy pez]{}`

---

I used the interpreter in http://www.compileonline.com/execute_rexx_online.php.

Answer (score 4):

## 56. [URSL](http://esolangs.org/wiki/URSL) (uses no `#`)

```
i1i1a91m11m11m19a19w1a21m29a29a29a29i2w2a41a42c4c4c4c4c4c4c4c4w4w4a59a51a52i5w5c1c1w1a65a69a69a69a69i6w6q6c5w5q5c6c6c6c6w6q6a59i5w5q5w1i4w4w5a49i4w4c4c4c4c4w4c5c5c5c5w5c4w4a59a59i5w5w1c4w4q4a49a49a49a49i4w4q4a49i4w4q4w5q5n45a49w4q4a89i8m89m89a81w8w1c4c4c4w4a59w5c5w5w1k5w5k5w5k5w5k5w5w1a49i4w4c5c5c5c5w5w4c5w5c5c5c5c5w5w4c6c6w6w1k4w4k4w4k4w4k4w4k4w4c6w6a89w8a19w1c1c1w1c8w8w1a29w2w5c4c4w4c5w5c4c4w4a49a49w4a59a59w5w1m19n12a19i1w1a18c1w1w6w5w4w1c1w1w4
```

Output is quote 58:

```
"Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Michael Corleone
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40822/30164): `"'&()*+-,./\037;<=>@_[sovy pezxX]^{}~|`

Writing this by hand was quite the job. I could've done it with a script to only use `i1`, `c1` and `w1`, but wanted to make at least a little optimized version. It even uses the queue to store repeated bits.

In case someone is interested, here is my work text file:

```
i1 i1 a91 m11 m11 m19 a19 w1         //  -  34  -  -   -   -   -  -  -  2 "
a21 m29 a29 a29 a29 i2 w2            //  -  34 75  -   -   -   -  -  -  2 "K
a41 a42 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 c4 w4   //  -  34 75  - 101   -   -  -  -  2 "Ke
w4                                   //  -  34 75  - 101   -   -  -  -  2 "Kee
a59 a51 a52 i5 w5                    //  -  34 75  - 101 112   -  -  -  2 "Keep
c1 c1 w1                             //  -  32 75  - 101 112   -  -  -  2 "Keep 
a65 a69 a69 a69 a69 i6 w6 q6         //  -  32 75  - 101 112 121  -  -  2 "Keep y
c5 w5 q5                             //  -  32 75  - 101 111 121  -  -  2 "Keep yo
c6 c6 c6 c6 w6 q6                    //  -  32 75  - 101 111 117  -  -  2 "Keep you
a59 i5 w5 q5                         //  -  32 75  - 101 114 117  -  -  2 "Keep your
w1                                   //  -  32 75  - 101 114 117  -  -  2 "Keep your 
i4 w4                                //  -  32 75  - 102 114 117  -  -  2 "Keep your f
w5                                   //  -  32 75  - 102 114 117  -  -  2 "Keep your fr
a49 i4 w4                            //  -  32 75  - 105 114 117  -  -  2 "Keep your fri
c4 c4 c4 c4 w4                       //  -  32 75  - 101 114 117  -  -  2 "Keep your frie
c5 c5 c5 c5 w5                       //  -  32 75  - 101 110 117  -  -  2 "Keep your frien
c4 w4                                //  -  32 75  - 100 110 117  -  -  2 "Keep your friend
a59 a59 i5 w5                        //  -  32 75  - 100 115 117  -  -  2 "Keep your friends
w1                                   //  -  32 75  - 100 115 117  -  -  2 "Keep your friends 
c4 w4 q4                             //  -  32 75  -  99 115 117  -  -  2 "Keep your friends c
a49 a49 a49 a49 i4 w4 q4             //  -  32 75  - 108 115 117  -  -  2 "Keep your friends cl
a49 i4 w4 q4                         //  -  32 75  - 111 115 117  -  -  2 "Keep your friends clo
w5 q5                                //  -  32 75  - 111 115 117  -  -  2 "Keep your friends clos
n45 a49 w4 q4                        //  -  32 75  - 101 115 117  -  -  2 "Keep your friends close
a89 i8 m89 m89 a81 w8                //  -  32 75  - 101 115 117  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close,
w1                                   //  -  32 75  - 101 115 117  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, 
c4 c4 c4 w4                          //  -  32 75  -  98 115 117  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, b
a59 w5                               //  -  32 75  -  98 117 117  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, bu
c5 w5                                //  -  32 75  -  98 116 117  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, but
w1                                   //  -  32 75  -  98 116 117  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, but 
k5 w5 k5 w5 k5 w5 k5 w5              //  -  32 75  -  98 114 117  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, but your
w1                                   //  -  32 75  -  98 114 117  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, but your 
a49 i4 w4                            //  -  32 75  - 101 114 117  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, but your e
c5 c5 c5 c5 w5                       //  -  32 75  - 101 110 117  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, but your en
w4                                   //  -  32 75  - 101 110 117  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, but your ene
c5 w5                                //  -  32 75  - 101 109 117  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enem
c5 c5 c5 c5 w5                       //  -  32 75  - 101 105 117  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemi
w4                                   //  -  32 75  - 101 105 117  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemie
c6 c6 w6                             //  -  32 75  - 101 105 115  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies
w1                                   //  -  32 75  - 101 105 115  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies 
k4 w4 k4 w4 k4 w4 k4 w4 k4 w4        //  -  32 75  - 101 105 115  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies close
c6 w6                                //  -  32 75  - 101 105 114  - 44  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer
a89 w8                               //  -  32 75  - 101 105 114  - 46  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer.
a19 w1                               //  -  34 75  - 101 105 114  - 46  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer."
c1 c1 w1                             //  -  32 75  - 101 105 114  - 46  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." 
c8 w8                                //  -  32 75  - 101 105 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." -
w1                                   //  -  32 75  - 101 105 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - 
a29 w2                               //  -  32 77  - 101 105 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - M
w5                                   //  -  32 77  - 101 105 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Mi
c4 c4 w4                             //  -  32 77  -  99 105 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Mic
c5 w5                                //  -  32 77  -  99 104 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Mich
c4 c4 w4                             //  -  32 77  -  97 104 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Micha
a49 a49 w4                           //  -  32 77  - 101 104 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Michae
a59 a59 w5                           //  -  32 77  - 101 108 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Michael
w1                                   //  -  32 77  - 101 108 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Michael 
m19 n12 a19 i1 w1                    //  -  64 77  - 101 108 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Michael C
a18 c1 w1                            //  - 111 77  - 101 108 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Michael Co
w6                                   //  - 111 77  - 101 108 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Michael Cor
w5                                   //  - 111 77  - 101 108 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Michael Corl
w4                                   //  - 111 77  - 101 108 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Michael Corle
w1                                   //  - 111 77  - 101 108 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Michael Corleo
c1 w1                                //  - 110 77  - 101 108 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Michael Corleon
w4                                   //  - 110 77  - 101 108 114  - 45  2 "Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer." - Michael Corleone
```

Answer (score 4):

## 55. [Grass](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Grass) (uses no `d`)

It is here: http://pastebin.com/Cm6iiVb4

Bzip2|base64:

```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```

Output is quote 52:

```
"You had me at "hello."" - Dorothy Boyd
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40875/25180): `"#'&()*+-,./\037;<=>@_[sovy pezxX]^{}~|`

Tested in the Python interpreter. (The Ruby one is broken in the current Ruby version and can be fixed by adding a `.ord`.)

It can probably be golfed better by copying `Out` and making the main function do different things (like increase by 16) by checking a condition.

Generator script in CJam:

```
"wWWWwwww"254,{4+'W*'w+}%255q{256+'wm256%_-4?\)_)'W*\@1$\-'w*\}/;
```

The input should be the string to output.

Answer (score 4):

## 47. [A0A0](http://esolangs.org/wiki/A0A0) (uses no `5`)

(Uses 60 newlines)

```
P89988898
P88988999
P98998898
P89989989
P89989989
P89989988
P98898988
P88889888
P99888998
P89989999
P98998898
P88889888
P99898988
P89889889
P98988899
P89889899
P88889888
P89989999
P99888998
P88889888
P89889889
P88889888
P98988898
P89989989
P89999988
P89999988
P89989989
P98998898
P88889888
P99898999
P89989999
P98998898
P89989988
P98898988
P88889888
P98998889
P98998899
P88889888
P99888999
P89989999
P89989999
P89989988
P88989998
P89988898
P88889888
P98898989
P88889888
P88988999
P89989999
P98998898
P89989988
P89989999
P89989998
P88889888
P88988999
P89989989
P89889899
P89889899
P89989999
P89989898
```

Output is quote 57:

```
"Greed, for lack of a better word, is good." - Gordon Gekko
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41513/32522): `"#&'()*+,-./0137:;<=>@[\]^_ deEhopQksvWxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `$` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `46` `89`
- Uppercase: `ABCD` `FGHIJKLMNOP` `RSTUV` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `fg` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

You can run it with [this interpreter](https://gist.github.com/dc6914d587bed8fa8d5e). The language has some interesting features, but I'm only using the boring old P (for 'print') operator.

Comment: Interesting. Every number can be written as a series of 8 and 9 mod 256?

Comment: Yeah, I wrote a little Perl script to try to generate them and it worked. There are only 256 8-digit numbers consisting of only 8 and 9, so there must only be one such representation for each number. I'm sure there's some nifty mathematical proof in there, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: @gone_native Yes.  Take a number 0≤n≤255.  If it even then pick 8 as your last digit, otherwise 9.  Compute $((n-8)/2)/5$ or $((n-9)/2)/5$ accordingly, where the division by 2 is usual integer division and the division by 5 is modulo 128.  Let that be your new n.  Repeat: if odd, the (next to) last digit is 9, otherwise 8; divide (mod 64, then mod 32, etc); repeat.

Answer (score 4):

## 39. [Farm](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Farm) (uses no `M`)

(New lines are not necessary.)

```
COCORICO!
COT!
arf!arf!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
miau!miau!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
miau!miau!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
miau!
Grunt!
COT!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
Grunt!
miau!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
miau!miau!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
miau!
Grunt!
COT!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
miau!miau!miau!
Grunt!
miau!miau!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
miau!miau!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
arf!
Grunt!
arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
arf!arf!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
miau!miau!miau!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!miau!
Grunt!
CHIRP!
Grunt!
arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!arf!
Grunt!
COT!
arf!arf!
Grunt!
HOUUU!
```

Output is quote 36:

```
"Badges? We ain't got no badges! We don't need no badges! I don't have to show you any stinking badges!" - "Gold Hat"
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41678/32353): `"#$&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ ABdeEghJLNopQksvWxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `4` `6` `89`
- Uppercase: `CD` `FGHI` `K` `OP` `RSTUV` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

---

Farm is yet another BF variant. It uses animal onomatopoeia for the commands. The interpreter ignores all non-letters, so I used `!` to separate the commands (avoiding the spaces). Often one command can be expressed with multiple words (e.g. all of "ouah", "waf", "wau", "bark", "arf", "woof", "ouaf" mean the same, `+`), so we could choose the ones that avoid the forbidden characters.

Generator:

```python
def encode(quote):
    cur_val = 0
    yield 'COCORICO!'
    for c in quote:
        code = ord(c)
        commands = [
            (cur_val, ''),
            (97, 'CHIRP!'),
            (32, 'COT!'),
        ]
        (cur_val, x) = min(commands, key=lambda c: abs(code - c[0]))
        if x:
            yield x
        if code > cur_val:
            yield 'arf!' * (code - cur_val)
        elif code < cur_val:
            yield 'miau!' * (cur_val - code)
        cur_val = code
        yield 'Grunt!'
    yield 'HOUUU!'
```

Answer (score 4):

## 33. [Golunar](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Golunar) (uses no `R`)

```
669462294962848822248248244228296882646669992624242666826898466926684229429292294492449229682282994698862864968426884482668689446299229226896864488982669864948424826282462944666466496292428626669298994892864484946962928968289896948829894249649689929492294269826842924992282866282264296692228284222499698446469929889968244896649946628492424448644494949964942269962949442222662926468848682284998498286998468886942869666429694222282246644292682644422626444848926848682268229462884642964686268864469949648868246429989262466888942686226824986248998926828926244489248448269966262294668246999842894249496984644282998429228284224464969224684892269499494684264694286692262268444892628996499888982289696886989294242289242264649694848989669869846688862422989889642289282848942264829498948828482924486884849286898422226482226422926848498642966828998684242892862422669948962699248998888224829998289882682999284282482884249468944246288898894486926292246246429244269284922884826898826982682446969446244648696424846964892224422626994464464692282288994492622898262229866942624668644998688286669889224696968964826969666848464246686924644962449664468622494982984624989929664899622622886428649248266962482484466628462842624986424944982898284462292264698489862989624926246944996482969866664946949228249892494628928484698489492986824482498226924946648969484422492649249962242662929269422669949894464899962829942942426629892286696646996826296492468682666626286268892662266429969629689428644492882926884889996892442924466984944644948868449948929899966924466829264288484649296642228996899686649989982299844626426266986224286884948664289489489294662922246962692848944444692692466986866498864946264484822898468446642449462882282294268644868964668282262964889942224698448862266292664246662444699864898662688422884982928644884969849846824884928249482988849884229829622962849994624246646262266282864892494649299698242662922482626244994248968848882224626648844996888229464648848268849882922829288444249446286449942822224892268288698964882689946964668986886499266628469866984246822466248999884896426446696864896696669282968466284264428849428422298242988299484948986989468642642468962698848446846842296688694988244426869296946248994629648686222884929849468689922646226882228484426244869898624629288286898924486484688299984924984846262942482682224948922486444469499444644886492288442629469268644966698299996944469296498269842468246249942444442982266294884662629962284242844899689892292286626286642224824946489469689949429226996964668229926844826448899694624828496864629898448669628624826826469228462496686488269942444992299664866428696669484646862962449892896948442268292282898694944688428424288228484892246992929969422969948949629444699489966994429294286489944846496994468996648686298826829448664622488484494462649482968289829426282249299288648692484226689264226268986294649294822894244699848622248288692696964422869999949949849824946998469889968489669269628269629829289424626249244492848299826699244428988944262822222644984228449229449466429949666699446896826666226948662944468942946692286988682492966896469998298698842862896898446229292696842896942268692428448822898268449849984846998684262999944824669498666968282664298992626826488424246666642498886448846828262848844226682464992462829969986689426896468969826426244984698424942268644429692824682298298846468484264442968996628262844992842968824486666829426962699848982444289498666648664624489269288996228262494648699864462226844696944684924298828942244842862682964982968496249498499649298699829929994289886946846949466896989424948884984298889829444689688282684499629222946444928949869298868286244982444222626422886892842229868899448268946486826822688448648448968864662846298882822884668849822448884989496266944222866449222864889869494242282826866448962924948486992282486446242682494428646968496446222999689884668229642288822428622288484422966844886296996489894924448982692298262489988442424222922226626642468828692862949846624449842949244498449246298422989294288892494992624848989666864966222842266262869469482694896242646929482884266964984996228842486686498446689429222898429266428668898889822428229282248468268894944298466288824264826448249482464468462294648984626688262686842642829828299229292898248698624682846224868224629868292999684469696646998882669868288896428644822668466269829442646249924242829962646496622226662448282484699828646962228944864644699864626968689668294624992829694249926946692262422426849224622826966248982442424648989446222882698924264489922696824866464422498622289229968848989466498688248442622289882864692626282262442294694492666942286269442894492466249298242492669488464246268289289888448429884844998886688944486944629229692996848226928889269498249688889449494824898422826292422468949986889289444462464244266444982224864688898948444648296882696842992642444898222266996962669689628964696849246962426266828892628284682662686694664998499286692688494998946296299242829469446249962669924899486999298699862896882428822996642284669642948868968228242884928262269626886688896248248284889489446299869296442229429626689692692429964949489949294468298899426486642686944622244884629486284662824862988242244629999422984896444942846949826992224998869464694829898249968889499942924996648229649228942444494449994462842969982946468842968482692894229664962888444628968622964899689992296442949949949942884486889498698624898699468949266664944464682496229986689298496989962699828846884844866969682464289284996482648924422426862946944929896822449468242869469829986969228686884442626242484999992482988964929928888999484824846964622486282248664992888496946289229282888986992489496894699228242844948282964292429464698922886422492626294486426298862922466429894668266468929448926969929826968499946929286892492462868298682299499964662266488999624686492668462948928694649884689464482428944888846494969849464996644988699984849249426864268244498829424862629644669889244969986492264826698442892469494264968469229992668968694494286948868969268924288988666989944464266224868968966498694886964684422664689298842828498666699984294996892998846442888829466269444689698294299466892464982826822896282922688922824946246829229264998866624688499284822962282469298948899966462982294964924686649686664842288869899889994892896822282964294449449642928224498849296894892699898224286429489826284696664892994669462494424246884999888429249898869462226224299684822964984694662466862994464868924292426489642686999896929984988968442989868926928426424824448649484822449896482864268288694829488849992882649449294468249948244662269496869698286269249842846694662689828648499462229842249669248898989846642248624492689249299862894922469994964942442869246692989694262466822869464422822868696922222886864289426866494669444629299629829262986484469922826986884669262424698946426869629686469696268822884444669626968422886969298698898486822466486486444869869849984689929692499926688896949684489286226499464946969299449986229644964428668622228899664699498294669992466662822484668688862688926822869424498966296622448422624246886296424424982948626266446992629448896969466986249462246486644649828896966996868688499266964262298926688984448624884488989699942699962686999998444942999642866644998942896826988296242248688694429466862692296992484246464222969666892686886269992944269926948986829869994444629869668668299866986248666849826229984694848884282866499244288949424469229982696689444962492499988464699698888928964962946224829266468968926229444896628644226988848864669698492942626284296288624824648689642469962966886696649266424696249486949694294482998686642846424844988492449944488689944986924994684628898646282989986499482994849926262884289428868642946989442829986688229969686428826689426688846492686848699462894969828962648646626286948928649292622864649292469884629682268826298468224646868229464999662492699488824286629644228684226868249849282824948494646988699888429246699896992846644894942994426869846696224984292269994266629682924624666498489994649299662884488488298666648442422269492668294969944988262689694646646999499948896426962929469449942299642269842988999284642686844222444664288696649448842884222982249942949689624262228449966682684899686996822966996688296862649922248424986984229826682666886989844498262992448488222699422464996464242892646968644499948226848622282998869442299646689668894929868629846294489684422488968868292824486484464866498842896669996462962692288664288482244692884946488849222228969968649868688992892698964698228686644296442468664689992449966442426966482288896996449249442628622298484429688669269842264928489864499966226824996886824222449698929984646424428944242686629994664422248466486469886449949294928992964944869682444268299242624424224666929492242984962286966626282492989626894896864689846999468966442442944264269964844284924942268282624948948964662899886666882682422642682948629996882446682242849462969996686424299266986628229424826269226884849869892988292622882464994864482462928264624868869294489426826644926629428292262626622294424969944996824948292668994968969224962294892622289296698962926462889829964692999842422848664496228442249246828492224446624482948446222966622494849486642999646946664646288
```

Output is quote 38:

```
"Today, I consider myself the luckiest man on the face of the earth." - Lou Gehrig
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41812/25180): `"#$&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ AbBdeEghIJLMNopQksUvWxXyYzZ{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `46` `89`
- Uppercase: `CD` `FGH` `K` `OP` `ST` `V`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

A Golunar program is the number of zeros in the equivalent Unary program, written in decimal. So the Unary program with that number of zeros should also output this quote.

I didn't find an interpreter. But the above program is exactly what the translator generated using the following Brainfuck program (gzip base64):

```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```

Which looks like this:

```
+[[+[++[+++++[[[[+[+[+++[[+++++[+[+[+[+[[+[[++++++[++++[[.+[+[[[+[+[++[[[+[ ...
>>>>]]]]]]>>]>>]>]>]]>]>]]]]]]>>>>]]]>]]]]]]>>>>]]>>>>>]]]]]]>>>]>]>>>>]]>] ...
++>+>+++>>+>->--+>++>+>-++--+>>++--+>+++++>---+>+++-->-++++>++++---+++>>>++ ...
>>>+---+>>>>-+++-+++++>>-++>
```

The `[`s in the first group and the `>`s in the second group are all no-ops. And the instructions after those two groups are completely useless.

There are many programs doing the same thing with those no-ops. I just brute-forced one which has only `24689` in its decimal representation.

#### Golunar to Brainfuck compiler (in CJam)

```
ri8b(("ERROR"@"><+-.,[]"f=?
```

#### Generator

I have generated the program using the following C++ code. The input is a number which is the expected length of the output (but I didn't remember what does it mean exactly, so just try some random values), and a Brainfuck program 
satisfying some criteria. For example a Brainfuck program that consists of only `+-.` and never makes the first cell zero.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int base=1000000000;

int p10[9]={1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000};

struct bignum{
    int s[2000];
    int l;
    int bit(int x){return x/9>=l ? 0 : s[x/9]/p10[x%9]%10;}
};
ostream &operator<<(ostream& o, bignum& x){
    for(int i=x.l-1;i>=0;i--)
        for(int j=base/10;j>0;j/=10)
            o<<((x.s[i]/j)%10);
    return o;
}

void bnset(int a, bignum &b){
    b.s[0]=a;
    b.l=a!=0;
}

void bnmul(bignum& a, int b, bignum& c){
    long long x=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<a.l||x;i++){
        x+=(i<a.l?a.s[i]*(long long)b:0);
        c.s[i]=x%base;
        x/=base;
    }
    while(i>=0 && c.s[i]==0)
        i--;
    c.l=i+1;
}
void bnadd(bignum& a, bignum &b, int f, bignum&c, int carry=0){
    long long x=carry;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<a.l||i<b.l||x;i++){
        x+=(i<a.l?a.s[i]:0) + (i<b.l?b.s[i]*(long long)f:0);
        c.s[i]=x%base;
        if(c.s[i]<0)
            c.s[i]+=base;
        x=(x-c.s[i])/base;
    }
    while(i>=0 && c.s[i]==0)
        i--;
    c.l=i+1;
}

bignum _min[20001],_max[20001],power[20001];
int _right[20001];
string s;
int charmap[256];
const char*const chars="><+-.,[]";
bool avail[10]={false,false,true,false,true,false,true,false,true,true};

void dfstry(int pos,int spos,int bcnt,char value);

void dfs(int pos,int spos,int bcnt,bool begin=false){
    if(pos==-1){
        cout<<_min[pos+1]<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(spos<s.length()){
        dfstry(pos,spos+1,bcnt,s[spos]);
        if(!begin)
            dfstry(pos,spos,bcnt+1,'[');
    }
    else if(bcnt>0){
        dfstry(pos,spos,bcnt-1,']');
        dfstry(pos,spos,bcnt,'>');
    }
    else {
        dfstry(pos,spos,bcnt,'+');
        dfstry(pos,spos,bcnt,'-');
        dfstry(pos,spos,bcnt,'>');
        //dfstry(pos,spos,bcnt,'<');
    }
}

void dfstry(int pos,int spos,int bcnt,char value){
    cerr<<pos<<" "<<spos<<" "<<bcnt<<" "<<value<<" "<<_right[pos+1]<<endl;
    if(pos>=s.length()-spos+bcnt){
        bnadd(_min[pos+1],power[pos],charmap[value],_min[pos]);
        //cerr<<_min[pos]<<endl;
        //cerr<<power[pos]<<endl;
        bnadd(_min[pos],power[pos],1,_max[pos],-1);
        //cerr<<pos<<" "<<spos<<" "<<bcnt<<" "<<value<<endl;
        bool f=true;
        for(_right[pos]=_right[pos+1];_right[pos]>=0 && _min[pos].bit(_right[pos])==_max[pos].bit(_right[pos]);_right[pos]--)
            if(!avail[_min[pos].bit(_right[pos])]){
                f=false;
                break;
            }
            //else cerr<<_min[pos].bit(_right[pos])<<" ";
        //cerr<<endl;
        if(!f || (_right[pos]>=0 && _min[pos].bit(_right[pos])==0 && _max[pos].bit(_right[pos])==1)){
            //if(pos==0)
                //cerr<<_min[pos]<<endl;
            return;
        }
        //cerr<<_min[pos].bit(_right[pos+1])<<endl;
        dfs(pos-1,spos,bcnt);
    }
}

int main(int argc,char**argv){
    int start;
    cin>>start;
    getline(cin,s);
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        charmap[chars[i]]=i;
    getline(cin,s);
    s+='>';
    bnset(1,power[0]);
    for(int i=1;i<start;i++){
        bnmul(power[i-1],8,power[i]);
        //cerr<<power[i+1]<<endl;
        }
    cerr<<"start"<<endl;
    for(int i=start;;i++){
        bnmul(power[i-1],8,power[i]);
        bnmul(power[i],1,_min[i]);
        _right[i]=_min[i].l*9-1;
        dfs(i-1,0,0,true);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## 21. [FlogScript](http://esolangs.org/wiki/FlogScript) (uses no `G`)

(New lines are required. There are 41 new lines)

```
4898
Pc2899
Pc884
Pc9829
Pc2924
Pc2924
Pc4449
Pc289
Pc288
Pc2888
Pc9829
Pc889
Pc44
Pc288
Pc2899
Pc884
Pc9829
Pc2924
Pc2924
Pc4449
Pc289
Pc4898
Pc288
Pc22829
Pc288
Pc2899
Pc884
Pc4449
Pc22894
Pc2924
Pc9829
Pc889
Pc288
Pc84299
Pc229999
Pc282999
Pc4449
Pc2924
Pc22899
Pc8299
Pc22889
Pc
```

Output is quote 45:

```
"Stella! Hey, Stella!" - Stanley Kowalski
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41970/32353):

`` ?!"#$%&'()*+,-./013567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFghIjJkLMNopqQRsTUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~ ``

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: none
- Numbers: `2` `4` `89`
- Uppercase: `D` `H` `K` `OP` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `i` `lmn` `r` `tu` `w`

---

FlogScript is a stack-based programming language. The standard interpreter is written in PHP. The language itself is mostly undocumented.

This code uses the `Pc` command, which prints integer at the top of the stack as ASCII code. This uses the [PHP `chr()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php#41471), which automatically performs mod 256. So the encoder is pretty simple:

```python
def encode(quote):
    for char in quote:
        c = ord(char)
        while set(str(c)) - set('2489'):
            c += 256
        yield '{}\nPc'.format(c)
```

Answer (score 4):

## 16. [NUMPAD](http://www.kevinalbrecht.com/code/oldcode/numpad/readme.html) (uses no `i`)

(There are 61 lines)

```
OK
fun
ululu
caruncularunwarn
futwaalacaruncularlaw
ffanfluctuantwarran
facalfcaffacaruncularlatrant
warnt
lunulanurturalataunt
alffuralunnaturalnu
truant
artcurucucufuruncular
faclatfuruncularcult
taunt
arnutSarawantuatara
catalufaalftuarntruncal
flancarucaltaauntruantla
arrant
nafurcacartunwarrant
unfactlunulararnut
unnaturaluncurlfarfara
laKfurunculartartan
unflat
nurturaltaratantara
taratantaracannurtural
unfur
cawallfullfuruncular
faaulaunnaturalStan
Ottawaattractanttar
aflatflatarantulatarnal
tantaraunnaturalnaunt
cannulaDanaanfrafluctuant
truffSarawanurnful
flaunt
frawncuartarurufactual
futDuculaunlawfulull
uncut
lacarcaraultranatural
walnutunlunularull
unlawfulararaunaacrawl
Sulafatfuturaltartan
unwarranttututunna
caruncularOnaunartful
ultranaturalranular
unactualaccruallacunal
Oattracttaratantara
Outuruncutarantular
atlatlSafaruntactful
unlawful
untall
lacunar
Saturnal
fulcral
natalunfactual
faultulluntruant
nlawfactanttulwarraft
ultranaturaltarantula
alanacanautunnatural
laruralunwarrantafar
annualaaturwarDuranta
wat
```

Output is quote 11:

```
"What we've got here is failure to communicate." - Captain
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42021/32353):

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFgGhHIjJkLmMNopPqQRsTUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: none
- Numbers: `4` `8` `9`
- Uppercase: `D` `K` `O` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `l` `n` `r` `t` `u` `w`

---

In NUMPAD, all words are translated into an integer, by summing the numbers of the corresponding characters in the word (abc = 2, def = 3, etc, so `dec == 3 + 3 + 2 == 8` for example). Any non-letters are separators, so we could actually use `9` to delimit the words, but that makes the program ugly :).

The first line `OK == 11` means "print", then the second line `fun == 17` means "start of string". The last line `wat == 19` means "end of string". The other lines gives the ASCII code of each character. So the whole program is effectively just `print("that_quote")`.

Generator:

```python
import collections
import random

values = {
    'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'D': 3, 'f': 3, 'K': 5, 'l': 5, 'n': 6, 'O': 6, 'r': 7, 
    'S': 7, 't': 8, 'u': 8, 'w': 9
}

def classify_word(word):
    value = 0
    try:
        for char in word:
            value += values[char]
        return value
    except KeyError:
        return None

classes = collections.defaultdict(list)
for line in open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r'):
    word = line.rstrip()
    cls = classify_word(word)
    if cls and cls <= 127:
        classes[cls].append(word)

classes = dict(classes)

def encode(number):
    if number in classes:
        return random.choice(classes[number])
    else:
        while True:
            split_to = random.randrange(2, number)
            if split_to in classes:
                break
        return encode(split_to) + encode(number - split_to)

quote = '''PUT_THAT_QUOTE_HERE'''

print('OK\nfun')

for char in quote:
    print(encode(ord(char)))

print('wat')
```

Answer (score 4):

## 5. [Binaryfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Binaryfuck) (uses no `w`)

(new lines for clarification only)

```
8
448448c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c4S
448448c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c4S
... many similar lines ...
448448c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c48c4S
```

The whole program sans new lines is **39,790 bytes** long. You may find the full program in http://pastebin.com/ybaWpcZG. The program after bzip2 + base64 is:

```
QlpoOTFBWSZTWaAjCX8AGnyLAARACAAIADABlBsthJ6qMJqSAqao3COyMkrqivNZbMtWykCFNoNEGsW2
zSwljFURtTKINbGxG2ixrMNtVFFtFrRtiNRW2xqmaE2k2jFY0WotSVpNBiNWU2xjVamyhpbGpTFFKZpN
m2220QW1SVbIC2AmZbUpC2pawTaqmy2kbahTNjKYVmbUJVmq2LUmLYqaCYpJZi1USvcFBTyUkp8XckU4
UJCgIwl/
```

The SHA-1 sum after decompressing should be 9297a4c847aade08f93813dca66f79f8271bec45.

Output is quote 3:

```
"You don't understand! I coulda had class. I coulda been a contender. I could've been somebody, instead of a bum, which is what I am." - Terry Malloy
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66836/32353):

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./01235679:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRstTuUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters:

- `4` `8` `S` `a` `c`

---

Binaryfuck is a BrainFuck variant. The 8 instructions are encoded to 3 bits, and the whole bitstring is converted to a base-32 number (so it is similar to Unary).

The specification does not clarify the character set, but since the input is base-32 "number" I assume this means case-insensitive.

Every base-32 digit occupy 5 bits, so we analyze the commands produced every 3 digits (15 bits), where there are the following interesting instructions:

- `c48` = `<+>-+` i.e. increase the value of the previous cell
- `c4S` = `<+><.` i.e. move to the previous cell, increment and then output it
- `448` = `-+>-+` i.e. move to the next cell

We also start the program with a `8` i.e. 1000₂, as the 1 in the most-significant-digit tells the Binaryfuck compiler where is the start of the code.

Generator:

```
quote = r'''"You don't understand! I coulda had class. I coulda been a contender. I could've been somebody, instead of a bum, which is what I am." - Terry Malloy'''

print('8')
#print('+')
for c in quote:
    print('448448' + 'c48' * (ord(c) - 1) + 'c4S')
    #print('-+>-+' + '-+>-+' + '<+>-+' * (ord(c) - 1) + '<+><.')
```

Answer (score 3):

## 84. dc, uses no `s`

```
16i[Balboa]20[]79[Rock]20[-]20[]22[Adrian!]20[Yo,]22PPPPPPPPPPPPPP
```

Output is quote 80:

```
"Yo, Adrian!" - Rocky Balboa
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40586/30164) `py3\" ';({`

Comment: [Unlambda](http://www.madore.org/~david/programs/unlambda/) seems to be not welcome here anymore...

Answer (score 3):

## 82. Postscript uses no `)`

```
<22><7072696e74>cvx exec
<4C69><7072696e74>cvx   exec
<~Er~><7072696e74>cvx   exec
<74656e><7072696e74>cvx exec
<20><7072696e74>cvx exec
<746f><7072696e74>cvx   exec
<20><7072696e74>cvx exec
<7468656d2e><7072696e74>cvx exec
<20><7072696e74>cvx exec
<~6N~><7072696e74>cvx   exec
<68696c6472656e><7072696e74>cvx exec
<20><7072696e74>cvx exec
<6f66><7072696e74>cvx   exec
<20><7072696e74>cvx exec
<746865><7072696e74>cvx exec
<20><7072696e74>cvx exec
<6e696768742e><7072696e74>cvx   exec
<20><7072696e74>cvx exec
<57686174><7072696e74>cvx   exec
<20><7072696e74>cvx exec
<6d75><7072696e74>cvx   exec
<~Er~><7072696e74>cvx   exec
<69><7072696e74>cvx exec
<~@f~><7072696e74>cvx   exec
<20><7072696e74>cvx exec
<746865><7072696e74>cvx exec
<79><7072696e74>cvx exec
<20><7072696e74>cvx exec
<6d616b652e><7072696e74>cvx exec
<22><7072696e74>cvx exec
<20><7072696e74>cvx exec
<2d><7072696e74>cvx exec
<20><7072696e74>cvx exec
<~6N~><7072696e74>cvx   exec
<6f756e74><7072696e74>cvx   exec
<20><7072696e74>cvx exec
<447261><7072696e74>cvx exec
<~@f~><7072696e74>cvx   exec
<756c61>=
```

Had to get in there before all the brackets were gone. :)

The repeated code fragment `<7072696e74>cvx exec` is a hex string of the word `print` (since `p` was forbidden). Then `(` was forbidden, so all strings became hex strings, but that introduced a few `3`s. So those bytes whose hex representation contains a 3 are built with ASCII-85 strings.

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40589/2381): `py3\" ';({s[`

Outputs quote 83:

```
"Listen to them. Children of the night. What music they make." - Count Dracula
```

Answer (score 3):

### 75. [Spoon](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Spoon), Uses no `,`

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110010100111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110010100111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110010100111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111110010100111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110010100111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111110010100111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110010100111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111110010100111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110010100111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010011111111111111111111111111111111110010100111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110010100111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100101001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001010
```

Outputs Quote 77:

```
"Soylent Green is people!" - Det. Robert Thorn
```

Previously banned:

```
py3\" ';({s[)<+.@=-
```

Comment: There is an interpreter here (not mine) : http://fayedu39.1s.fr/brainfuck/spoon2.php

Answer (score 3):

## 64. [AlphaBeta](http://esolangs.org/wiki/AlphaBeta), uses no `}`

```
iiiggggDLCFiiiiiiiiggggDLCFiiiiiiiiigggggggDLCFkgggggggDLCFkgDLCFiiiggDLCFkiigDLCFkigDLCFkigggggggDLCFkiggggDLCFiiiggDLCFkigggggDLCFkiggggggDLCFkgggggDLCFkiDLCFkgggggggDLCFkgggggDLCFkiDLCFkgggDLCFiiiggDLCFkiggDLCFiiiiiiiiigggggggDLCFkigggggggggDLCFkigggggDLCFiiiggDLCFkigDLCFkggDLCFkggDLCFiiiggDLCFkgggggggggDLCFkgDLCFiiiiggggDLCFiiiggDLCFkiigDLCFkigDLCFkigggggggDLCFiiiggDLCFkDLCFiiiiiiiiigggggggDLCFkgggggggggDLCFkiDLCFkgDLCFkDLCFiiiggDLCFkDLCFkgggggDLCFkiggggDLCFkiggggggDLCFkiigDLCFiiiggDLCFiiiiiiiiigggggggDLCFkiggDLCFkgDLCFiiiiggggggDLCFiiiggggDLCFiiiggDLCFiiiigggggDLCFiiiggDLCFiiiiiiigDLCFkgDLCFkigDLCFkiggggDLCFkgggDLCFkgDLCFiiiggDLCFiiiiiiiiggggDLCFiiiiiiiiigggggggDLCFkiigDLCFkggggggggDLCFkigDLCFkiggggDLCF
```

Uses: `gikDLCF`

Output is quote 66:

`"Take your stinking paws off me, you damned dirty ape." - George Taylor`

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40686/31387): `"'&()*+-,./\03;<=>@X[soy pez]{`

I removed `}` because it's kind of useless if `{` is already forbidden, and any language that requires braces but doesn't require brace-matching is evil.

Answer (score 3):

## 50. [Tonoco](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Tonoco) (uses no `h`)

(New lines are not necessary.)

```
CaqCbq
Sa29Sa5
Sa85Sa2Sa99Sa2Sa99Sa9Sa99Sa9
Sq44
Sa28Sa4
Sa99Sa5Sa99Sa2Sa92Sa22Sa99Sa2
Sb295Sb5695
Sa89Sa26
Sa28Sa4Sa95Sa2Sa88Sa22Sa89Sa22Sa94Sa22Sa99Sa5Sa99Sa2Sa92Sa22
Sa28Sa4
Sa88Sa22Sa99Sa6Sq99Sa99Sa2
Sa28Sa4
Sa85Sa24Sa99Sa2Sa89Sa26Sa89Sa26
Sa28Sa4
Sa99Sa22Sa89Sa22Sa95Sa22
Sb295Sb5695
Sa96Sa22Sa99Sa2
Sa28Sa4
Sa99Sa4Sa89Sa22Sa94Sa22Sa94Sa22Sa99Sa2Sa88Sa22
Sa28Sa4
Sa85Sa24Sa99Sa2
Sa28Sa4
Sa99Sa6Sa88Sa22Sa94Sa22Sa89Sa22
Sa29Sa4
Sa29Sa5
Sa28Sa4
Sq45
Sa28Sa4
Sa55Sa24Sa99Sa9Sa99Sa6Sa96Sa22Sa99Sa2Sa92Sa22
```

Output is quote 60:

```
"Well, here's another nice mess you've gotten me into!" - Oliver
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41341/32353): `"#&'()*+,-./0137;<=>@[\]^_ deEopQksvxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `$` `%` `:` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `456` `89`
- Uppercase: `ABCD` `FGHIJKLMNOP` `RSTUVW` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `fg` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

---

Tonoco is a "network-based programming language". There are 26 "boxes" to perform various functions. We have used 2 instructions here:

- `Cxy`, connect two boxes, so all output of box `x` will be sent to box `y`
- `Sxn`, send the number `n` to the box `x`.

This program used 3 boxes:

- `q`, output ASCII character, functionality equal to `while(1){ recv(&x); putchar(x); }`
- `a`, perform addition, functionality equal to `while(1){ recv(&x); recv(&y); send(x+y); }`
- `b`, perform bitwise-and, functionality equal to `while(1){ recv(&x); recv(&y); send(x&y); }`

The `a` and `b` boxes are connected to `q` at the beginning, so there are 3 ways to output a character, all in order to avoid the numbers `0137`.

Answer (score 3):

## 46. [Fuck4](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fuck4) (uses no `J`)

(New lines are not necessary)

```
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffcfccccccc
fffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffcfccccccc
fffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffcfccccccc
fffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffcfccccccc
fcfccccccc
ffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
cfccccccc
ffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
fffffcfccccccc
fffffcfccccccc
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffcfccccccc
```

Output is quote 53:

```
"One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got in my pajamas, I don't know." - Capt. Geoffrey T. Spaulding
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41534/32353): `"#&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ deEhopQksvWxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `$` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `46` `89`
- Uppercase: `ABCD` `FGHI` `KLMNOP` `RSTUV` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `fg` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

---

Fuck4 is a brainfuck variant, which has an extremely limited memory space (8 cells) and integer range (0–127). This limitation allows the language to remove the decreasing instructions (`-` and `<` in BF), instead rely on wrap around. Additionally, input and output are performed by encoding special numbers into cell #1, and one could only read/print cell #0. This allows Fuck4 to shove to only 4 instructions. As a gimmick, Fuck4 uses `f`, `u`, `c` and `k` to replace `+`, `[`, `>` and `]` respectively (which makes it possible to participate here).

This is the encoder in Python to construct the code above:

```python
def encode(quote):
    memory = 0
    for c in quote:
        num = ord(c)
        count = (num - memory) % 128
        memory = num
        yield 'f' * count + 'cf' + 'c'*7
```

Answer (score 3):

## 45. [Gammaplex](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Gammaplex) (uses no `B`)

```
222w922%rw89%rw999%rw6999%rw6699%rw8998%rw989%rw698%rw2989%rw999%rw6998%rw698%rw6998%rw999%rw698%rw42499%rw4999%rw6989%rw698%rw9889%rw999%rw6999%rw4998%rw4999%rw989%rw996%rw2988%rw698%rw999%rw998%rw989%rw698%rw2999%rw6999%rw989%rw4999%rw6998%rw4989%rw999%rw998%rw946%rw698%rw6699%rw68%rw999%rw698%rw6289%rw698%rw2988%rw989%rw989%rw996%rw698%rw996%rw6999%rw99%rw6989%rw9889%rw2949%rw6699%rw698%rw6969%rw989%rw996%rw996%rw44%rw698%rw988%rw999%rw698%rw9889%rw42499%rw44%rw698%rw2998%rw6999%rw998%rw6989%rw2949%rw922%rw698%rw489%rw698%rw294%rw42499%rw4998%rw4998%rw9889%rw698%rw289%rw42499%rw996%rw996%rw42499%rw992%rw42499%rw998%rR2w%628G
```

Output is quote 51:

```
"You've got to ask yourself one question: 'Do I feel lucky?' Well, do ya, punk?" - Harry Callahan
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41542/25180): `"#&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ deEhJopQksvWxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `$` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `46` `89`
- Uppercase: `A` `CD` `FGHI` `KLMNOP` `RSTUV` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `fg` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

It opens a window and displays this quote. The standard way ending a Gammaplex program `E` is described as an infinite loop in the documentation. (It doesn't use the console. An infinite loop can keep a window open so people can see the displayed text. And unlike most languages, the infinite loop will not make the Gammaplex window stop responding.) So I think it is acceptable to just implement another infinite loop.

#### Generator (in C++)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

const int base=222;
const int factor=10;
const int num[]={2,4,6,8,9},n=5;
const int maxlen=822;
const int maxbase=822;

bool v[maxbase];
int q[maxbase],ql;
int b[maxbase],r[maxbase];
int pos;

int bfs(int ch,int base){
    memset(v,0,sizeof v);
    q[0]=0;
    ql=1;
    v[0]=true;
    b[0]=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<ql;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            int t=(q[i]*factor+num[j]) % base;
            if(!v[t]){
                v[t]=true;
                q[ql++]=t;
                b[t]=q[i];
                r[t]=num[j];
                if(t==ch)
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(v[ch])
            break;
    }
    int a=b[ch];
    b[ch]=-1;
    int k=ch;
    while(a!=-1){
        int x=b[a];
        b[a]=k;
        k=a;
        a=x;
    }
    if(b[0]==-1){
        cout<<0;
        pos++;
    }
    else
        for(int l=b[0];l!=-1;l=b[l]){
            cout<<r[l];
            pos++;
        }
}

int main(){
    char ch;
    pos=log(base)/log(10)+1;
    cin.get(ch);
    cout<<base;
    while(ch!='\n'){
        cout<<"w";
        bfs(ch,base);
        cout<<"%r";
        pos+=3;
        cin.get(ch);
    }
    cout<<"R";
    pos++;
    cout<<num[0]<<"w%"<<maxlen<<"wD";
    bfs(pos,maxlen);
    cout<<"%G"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I though for a moment that "Gammaplex" whould be the closing entry both for this and for "Hello World!" channenge.

Answer (score 3):

## 40. [Enema](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Enema) (uses no `A`)

```
???????????????????????????????????O????????????????????????????????????????OPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP?O??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????O?OPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP?O???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????O????OPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPO???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????OO???O?????????OPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPPPPPP?OP?O??????????????OPPPPPPO?????????????????????????????????????????????????????O?????????????????????OPOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPO?????????????????????????????????????????????????????O??????????????????O??????????????OPPOPP?O??????OPPPPPPO????????????????????OPPO????OPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP?OK
```

Output is quote 37:

```
"I'll be back." - The Terminator
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41640): `"#$&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ BdeEghJLNopQksvWxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `46` `89`
- Uppercase: `CD` `FGHI` `K` `M` `OP` `RSTUV` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

Ran using the [C++ interpreter](http://web.archive.org/web/20060505015519/www.glum.pl/enema/).

---

Enema is another stack-based language with mostly single-character keywords. All the math operators are forbidden except for modulo (`%`) which isn't terribly useful since only single-digit numbers can be pushed onto the stack.

What is useful is the `?` operator which pushes the current stack depth onto the stack. This can be used repeatedly to increment the value at the top of the stack until it contains the desired ASCII code to output (using `O`). Each `P` operation pops the stack twice (it does a memory write using these values, but memory isn't used here). Finally, the `K` is an undefined operation that ends the program.

Perl generator:

```
$quote = q("I'll be back." - The Terminator) . "\n";
$depth = 0;
$code = "";

for (split "", $quote)
{
    $ch = ord($_)+1;
    while ($depth > $ch)
    {
        $code .= "P";
        $depth -= 2;
    }
    while ($depth < $ch)
    {
        $code .= "?";
        $depth++;
    }
    $code .= "O";
    $depth--;
}
$code .= "K";

print $code;
```

Answer (score 3):

## 29. [Lazy K](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Lazy_K) (uses no `6`)

````
`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K```SS`K`K`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii``Si`K``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S``S`KSK``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKi``S`K``S``S`KSKii
````

Output is quote 24:

```
"I am big! It's the pictures that got small." - Norma Desmond
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41869/25180): `"#$&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ AbBCdeEFghIJkLMNopQRsTUvWxXyYzZ{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `4` `89`
- Uppercase: `D` `GH` `K` `OP` `S` `V`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

Lazy K is an [Unlambda](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Unlambda) variant. A Lazy K program is a function that takes a list of input characters as parameter, and returns a list of output characters. Both lists end with 256.

#### Generator (in CJam)

````
q:i256+{_
{2b(;'i\{"``s`k``s``s`kski"@+\{"``s``s`ksk"\+}*}%}"`sk"?
}%
W%("`k"\+\{"```ss`k`k"@+"``si`k"+\+}/]"`k"\+
s"sk""SK"er
````

The program is constructed using these basic elements:

- `` `sk `` Number 0. (Not used for this output.)
- `i` Number 1.
- ``` ``s``s`kskx ``` Number x+1.
- ``` ``s`kxy ``` Number x*y, where x is always 2.
- ```` ```ss`k`kl``si`kx ```` cons(x,l), for making a list.
- `` `k256 `` End of the output list according to the documentation.
- `` `kl `` Main function. Ignore the input and output `l`.

Answer (score 3):

## 28. [asdf](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Asdf) (uses no `` ` ``)

```
aSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaa
SSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaa
SSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSa
aSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSa
SaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSS
aaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaS
SSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaS
aaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSS
aaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSS
SaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaS
SSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaS
SSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaS
aaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSa
SaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSS
SaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaS
SSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaS
SSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSa
aSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaS
aaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSS
SaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaS
SSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaa
SSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaa
SaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSS
aaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaa
SSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSa
aSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaa
SaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSS
aaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaS
SSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaa
SSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSa
aSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSa
aSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaS
aaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaSaaSSSaaSaaSSSaa
SaaSSSaaSaaSSS
```

Output is quote 29:

```
"You can't handle the truth!" - Col. Nathan R. Jessup
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41887/32353): `"#$&'()*+,-./013567:;<=>@[\]^_ AbBCdeEFghIJkLMNopQRsTUvWxXyYzZ{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?`
- Numbers: `2` `4` `89`
- Uppercase: `D` `GH` `K` `OP` `S` `V`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

---

Generator:

```python
def encode(quote):
    yield 'aS'
    cur_bit = False
    for char in quote:
        c = ord(char)
        for i in range(7, -1, -1):
            is_on = bool(c & 1 << i)
            if is_on != cur_bit:
                yield 'aS'
            else:
                yield 'aaS'
            cur_bit = is_on
            yield 'aaSSS'
```

Answer (score 3):

## 25. [ETA](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ETA) (uses no `q`)

```
aaaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSSaaaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSaSS
OOaSOaSOaSOaSOOOaSOOOOaSOOaSOOOOaSOaSOOaSOaSOOOOaSOOOaSOaSOaSOOOaSOOaSOOaSOOOaSOOOaSOaSOaSOOaSOOaSOOOOOaSOaSOOOaSOOaSOOOOOaSOOOaSOaSOaSOOOOaSOaSOOaSOO
```

Output is quote 20:

```
"Louis, I think this is the beginning of a beautiful friendship." - Rick Blaine
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41935/25180): `` "#$&'()*+,-./013567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFghIjJkLMNopQRsTUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~ ``

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?`
- Numbers: `2` `4` `89`
- Uppercase: `D` `GH` `K` `OP` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `i` `lmn` `r` `tu` `w`

It used 3 commands:

- `A` Push the current line number +1. That is, push 2 on the first line and 3 on the second line.
- `S` Subtract.
- `O` Output.

#### Generator (in CJam)

```
LLqW%{i_1&@'O+1${"SA"+}*@@3*+2/"AS"*"AA"\+'S+@\+\}/N\W%]s"A""a"er
```

Answer (score 3):

## 22. [Nqubl](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Nqubl), uses no `?`

```
iOimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPiDiDiDiciPimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPimiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPiDiDiDiDiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPimimiciPimimiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPiDiDiDiciPimimiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPimimimimimimimiciPiDiDiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPiDiDiciPimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPimimimiciPiDiDiDiciPimimimimimiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimimiciPimimimimimimimimimimimiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciPiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiDiciP
```

Output is quote 23:

```
"There's no place like home." - Dorothy Gale
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41965):

`` !"#$%&'()*+,-./013567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFghIjJkLMNopqQRsTUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~ ``

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: none
- Numbers: `2` `4` `89`
- Uppercase: `D` `GH` `K` `OP` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `i` `lmn` `r` `tu` `w`

---

Nqubl is a language with 8 stacks and an instruction queue. Instructions are queued up until a (forbidden) `x` command is encountered, or an instruction may be immediately executed by preceding it with an `i`. Besides executing each instruction immediately, the program uses the following instructions:

- `O` pushes the stack depth, to get an initial 0 on the stack
- `m` increments top of stack by 1
- `D` decrements top of stack by 1
- `c` duplicates top of stack
- `P` pops and prints top of stack as ASCII character

Perl generator:

```
$quote = q("There's no place like home." - Dorothy Gale
);
$tos = 0;
print "iO";
for (split "", $quote)
{
    $ch = ord($_);
    if ($ch > $tos)
    {
        print "im" x ($ch-$tos);
    }
    elsif ($ch < $tos)
    {
        print "iD" x ($tos-$ch);
    }
    $tos = $ch;
    print "iciP";
}
```

Comment: Damn, how do people find these languages? Do they go do the esolangs site and search them all for one that can be used with the current available characters?

Comment: @RodolfoDias, I came across Glypho a few months ago when I was searching through esolangs for languages which would do really well in a challenge that was in the sandbox and which I thought was too exploitable. It took me a while to find it again, even though I remembered the key property I was looking for.

Comment: @RodolfoDias, yes, pretty much. I saw Glypho last night but Peter beat me to the answer. Seemed like Glypho was perfectly designed for this challenge, where Nqubl was just lucky.

Comment: I saw Glypho a few days ago but I thought it was still too early for that... which could be answer 3.

Comment: Damn, when I go look for languages I never seem to find one that could suit the challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## 19. [Pointy](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Pointy) (uses no `P`)

(Uses 50 newlines)

```
Out222242
Out284249
Out229999
Out248949
Out424999
Out224882
Out229989
Out224288
Out848999
Out229999
Out229998
Out229998
Out228449
Out224288
Out229998
Out229989
Out229989
Out229988
Out224288
Out228449
Out224288
Out249442
Out249449
Out848999
Out848999
Out229989
Out224882
Out224288
Out249442
Out229999
Out228449
Out224884
Out229422
Out222242
Out224288
Out242989
Out224288
Out228429
Out228449
Out224882
Out224884
Out249449
Out229998
Out224288
Out229442
Out224882
Out229999
Out229988
Out224889
Out229898
```

Output is quote 35:

```
"You're gonna need a bigger boat." - Martin Brody
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41976):

`` ?!"#$%&'()*+,-./013567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFgGhIjJkLMmNopqQRsTUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~ ``

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: none
- Numbers: `2` `4` `89`
- Uppercase: `D` `H` `K` `O` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `i` `l` `n` `r` `tu` `w`

Run with this [C interpreter](http://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Marinus/Pointy_interpreter)

---

Pointy is a Turing-complete language centered around pointer operations. The program relies on interpreter behavior that isn't fully defined in the language specification:  keywords are case-insensitive, no space is needed between a word and argument, and that the `OUT` instruction is implemented with C's `putchar()` which casts its integer argument as an unsigned char.

Perl generator:

```
$q = q("You're gonna need a bigger boat." - Martin Brody
);
for (split "", $q)
{
    $ch = ord($_);
    $v = 222222;
    while (($v % 256) != $ch) { $v++; }
    while ($v !~ /^[2489]+$/) { $v+=256; }
    print "Out$v\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## 17. [Tri](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Tri) (uses no `H`)

(Newlines are not necessary.)

```
aDD
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
Str
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SicStr
SicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicStr
SicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicStr
SDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcStr
SicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicSicStr
SDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcSDcStr
lin
```

Output is quote 19:

```
"I'm as mad as hell, and I'm not going to take this anymore!" - Howard Beale
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42014/25180):

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFgGhIjJkLmMNopPqQRsTUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: none
- Numbers: `4` `8` `9`
- Uppercase: `D` `K` `O` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `i` `l` `n` `r` `t` `u` `w`

Explanation:

- `aDD` Add all stack contents together. The sum will be the only item in the stack after this command. It will conveniently generate a `0` in the stack if the stack was empty.
- `Sic` Increase all items in the stack.
- `SDc` Decrease all items in the stack.
- `Str` Output all items in the stack as characters.
- `lin` Print a newline.

#### Generator (in CJam)

```
"aDD"N0cq{_@-_0>"Sic""SDc"?\z*"Str"N+@}/;"lin"
```

I feel I cannot find languages for this challenge anymore... unless start to read every page on the wiki.

There should be some other OISCs still work, though.

Answer (score 2):

## 69. Shell (with POSIX utilities), uses no `]`

Or at least with GNU sharutils, because while [`uudecode` is standardized by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/uudecode.html), I rely on the unspecified behavior of the GNU implementation which outputs a partial file when given unfinished input.

```
echo>e  begin   644 d
echo>>e 54%%94RPM$?R!P47ES%RUA86%A8F1A
uudecode    e   2>f
echo    7Life5iS5a5banquetA5and5moSt5Poor5SuckerS5are5Starving5to5death675B5Mame5DenniS|tr  `cat    d`
```

Output is quote 93:

```
"Life is a banquet, and most poor suckers are starving to death!" - Mame Dennis
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40642) `py3\" ';({s[)<+.@=-,X0*/&`

This program creates or overwrites files called `d`, `e` and `f` in the current directory.

The basic principle was to use `tr` to turn unused characters into forbidden characters. Not having `-` available made this a bit tricky.

In the interest of not overly restricting an already fairly narrow field, I'm choosing to forbid a character that wouldn't be of much use anymore.

Comment: OP: "Your program should not take input or have unexpected side effects like creating files." I'm inclined to ignore that rule, too, but I thought it should be pointed out.

Comment: @isaacg Oops, I'd missed the “no creating files” bit. Thanks for the notice. Well, that invalidates both my answers. I don't know what I should do here: deleting my answers would break the chain. That rule is a pity, it rules out TeX.

Comment: Don't worry about the rule - I think not breaking the chain is more important than strictly obeying the rules.

Answer (score 2):

## 65. [Super Stack!](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Super_Stack!) (uses no `o`)

(There are 52 newlines and 15 tabs)

```
1   RANDOM
71
84
71
91  1   SUB
84
85
51
6
95
84
85
58
6
19
6
8
7
74
84
75
79
88
76
6
75
82
91  1   SUB
91  1   SUB
79
82
6
95
84  1   SUB
6
85
91  1   SUB
6
8
85
82
82
75
78
8
6
95
71
57
8
IF  26  ADD OUTPUTASCII FI
```

Output is quote 61:

```
"Say "hello" to my little friend!" - Tony Montana
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40680/32353): `z" &'()*+,-./03;<=>@X[\]epsy{`

The implementation in http://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Orange/Super_Stack!/v2 is used to verify the result (you need to fix a minor syntax error in the interpreter to make it work.)

---

Here we push all ASCII code minus 26 of the quote onto the stack, and then print them out. 26 is chosen to minimize the amount of `0` and `3` in the source code.

Comment: z was forbidden by 67. You should cite it in the forbidden characters.

Answer (score 2):

## 58. [Emmental](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Emmental) (uses no x)

```
##51?4#46?#84#46?#1#48?1#46?#1#48?8#46?#1#48?8#46?##51?2#46?##51?9#46?#1#48?1#46?#1#48?9#46?##51?2#46?#116#46?#111#46?##51?2#46?#1#48?#51?#46?#111#46?##51?2#46?#111#46?#11#55?#46?#116#46?##51?2#46?#116#46?#1#48?4#46?#1#48?1#46?#114#46?#1#48?1#46?##51?2#46?#119#46?#1#48?5#46?#116#46?#1#48?4#46?##51?2#46?#9#55?#46?#1#48?8#46?#1#48?8#46?##51?2#46?#116#46?#1#48?4#46?#1#48?1#46?#121#46?##51?2#46?#1#48?#51?#46?#111#46?#116#46?##51?2#46?#9#55?#46?#11#48?#46?#1#48?#48?#46?##51?2#46?#119#46?#1#48?5#46?#11#48?#46?##51?2#46?#1#48?6#46?#11#55?#46?#115#46?#116#46?##51?2#46?#111#46?#11#48?#46?#1#48?1#46?##51?2#46?#1#48?2#46?#111#46?#114#46?##51?2#46?#116#46?#1#48?4#46?#1#48?1#46?##51?2#46?##55?1#46?#1#48?5#46?#112#46?#112#46?#1#48?1#46?#114#46?#46#46?##51?4#46?##51?2#46?#45#46?##51?2#46?##55?5#46?#11#48?#46?#11#55?#46?#116#46?#1#48?1#46?##51?2#46?#82#46?#111#46?#99#46?#1#48?#55?#46?#11#48?#46?#1#48?1#46?#1#48?#46?
```

Output is quote 89:

```
"Tell 'em to go out there with all they got and win just one for the Gipper." - Knute Rockne
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40807/25180): `"'&()*+-,./\037;<=>@X_[sovy pez]^{}~`

Answer (score 2):

## 52. [D1ffe7e45e](http://esolangs.org/wiki/D1ffe7e45e) (uses no `k`)

(New lines are not necessary, they are to make the post prettier only.)

```
2B2B24DEE88ABB2B24DF6FDEE88ABB24DF6F6899AABB288ABB24DF6F6899AABB24AACDD4DF6899AA
BB24DEE88ABB2B2B288ABB2BD4D46F99B24D46FD46FDEE88ABB24D4D46F99B24D46F6FDEE88ABB24
D46FD46F99B24DF6F6899AABB24AACDD46F6899AABB24DF68EECDD46F6899AABB24DF6CCE5ECDD46
F6CCE5E5E5BBD46FD46F6FDEE88ABB24D46FD46FDEE88ABB24DF6FD4DF99B2B24DF68EECDD46FD4D
46F99B24D4DF6FDEE88ABB2B2B288ABB24DF6FD4DEE88ABB24DF6F6899AABB288ABB24DF6899AABB
2B24AACDD46F6899AABB2B24AACDD46F6899AABB24DF6CCE566899AABB2B24DF68EECDD4D4D4AACD
D46FD4DF6F99B24D46FD46FDEE88ABB2B2B288ABB24DF6F6899AABB24AACDD46F6FD4DF99B24D4DF
6F99B24DF6FD4DF99B24D4D46FDEE88ABB24D4DF6FDEE88ABB2B2B288ABB24D46FD4DF99B24D4DF6
FDEE88ABB2BD46FD4AACDD4D4D4AACDD4D4D4DF99B24DF6F6899AABB288ABB24D4DF6FDEE88ABB24
D46FD46F99B2B24DF68EECDD46FD4DF6F99B2B2B288ABB24DF6899AABB2B24AACDD46F6899AABB24
DF68EECDD46FD4DF6FDEE88ABB24DF6899AABB24DF99B2B2BD4AACDD4D4D4AACDD4DF6899AABB2BD
EE88ABB2B2B288ABB2B2B24DEE88ABB24D4DF6FDEE88ABB24D46FD46F99B24D46F6899AABB288ABB
24D4D4DF99B24D46FD4DF99B24D46F6FDEE88ABB24D46FD46F99B2B2B288ABB2B2B24DEE88ABB24D
F6F6899AABB288ABB24D4D4DF99B24D4DF6F99B24D4DF6F99B24D46FD46FDEE88ABB24D4D46FDEE8
8ABB24D46F6899AABB24AAC5D
```

Output is quote 63:

```
"Mrs. Robinson, you're trying to seduce me. Aren't you?" - Benjamin Braddock
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41303/32353): `"#&'()*+,-./0137;<=>@[\]^_ deopQsvxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `$` `%` `:` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `456` `89`
- Uppercase: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP` `RSTUVW` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `fghij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

---

D1ffe7e45e is a brainfuck variant, but uses the absolute difference between two hexadecimal digit as an instruction. Although `0137` cannot be used, we could use the "no-op" sequence `><` to increase or decrease the last number, thus avoiding the forbidden characters. Additionally I used the additional "rotate-left" instruction to make the output shorter.

This is a (totally unoptimized) Python 3 program that generates the code above, excluding the final "C5D":

```python
def construct(quote):
    ptr = 0
    for c in quote:
        a = ord(c)
        instructions = [0, 6]
        while a:
            if a & 1:
                instructions.append(2)
                a &= ~1
            else:
                instructions.append(9)
                a >>= 1
        while instructions:
            ins = instructions.pop()
            new_ptr = ptr + ins
            if new_ptr < 16 and new_ptr not in {0, 1, 3, 7}:
                ptr = new_ptr
                yield hex(new_ptr)[2:].upper()
                continue
            new_ptr = ptr - ins
            if new_ptr >= 0 and new_ptr not in {0, 1, 3, 7}:
                ptr = new_ptr
                yield hex(new_ptr)[2:].upper()
                continue
            instructions += [ins, 0, 1]
```

Normally D1ffe7e45e requires two nop instructions to terminate the program, otherwise it will loop forever. But that requires the character 0 to produce a difference of ±f. Therefore I "cheated" by doing an infinite loop `+[]` to pause the program. (That's not forbidden by the rules ;) )

Answer (score 2):

## 48. [gs2](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Gs2) (uses no `W`)

(There must not be any whitespaces)

```
f!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!Mf$N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!N!M
```

The output is quote 59:

```
"As God is my witness, I'll never be hungry again." - Scarlett O'Hara
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41502/32353): `"#&'()*+,-./0137:;<=>@[\]^_ deEhopQksvxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `$` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `456` `89`
- Uppercase: `ABCD` `FGHIJKLMNOP` `RSTUV` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `fg` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

---

gs2 is yet another stack-based language, with many of its commands in binary. In particular, all data-constructing operations requires non-ASCII bytes (0x00–0x09). Fortunately most important commands are in the ASCII range. In gs2, the only data-generating command that meets with the limitation is:

- 0x66 (f): `fizzbuzz` (o_O)

(Note that the command list on esolang is not up-to-date. Check the github repository for the latest command list.)

After FizzBuzz is loaded, we could use the 0x24 ($) `last` command to get the character "z", or the 0x21 (!) `head` command to get "1". Then, by repeatedly apply 0x4e 0x21 (N!) `rrange head` one could decrease the number by one, replacing the forbidden command 0x26 (&) `dec`. Finally, the integer can be turned into a 1-element array with 0x4d (M) `itemize`. The whole stack will be printed when the program finishes, thus the quote becomes visible.

Answer (score 2):

## 38. [Ecstatic](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ecstatic), uses no `Z`

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
... 1087770610080204032141129843838487742450779738556529622132280080667217733137017018778945
91566243937383757089300118369796319746354454814268923170465839703277287664090480421751212173
1223956 characters skipped ...
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Output is quote 42:

```
"Plastics." - Mr. Maguire
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41686/788) `"#$&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ ABdeEghJLMNopQksvWxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `4` `6` `89`
- Uppercase: `CD` `FGHI` `K` `OP` `RSTUV` `Y`
- Lowercase: `abc` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

---

This is essentially a unary representation (using exclamation marks `!`) of the following Brainfuck program:

```
++++++++++[>+++>++++>++++++++>++++++++++>++++++++++>+++++++++++<<<<<<-]>++++>++++++>--->--->+++++>+++++<<<<<.>>+++.>>+++.<.>>.+.<---.<++.>>-.<<<<.<.--.>-.<.>>---.>>>-.<<<<+.<.>>.>--.>--.>+++.<++.>---.<----.
```

Comment: I hoped this can be answer 1.

Comment: @user23013 I imagine there are some other languages of a similar flavor

Comment: @PeterOlson Unfortunately many of those languages cannot be used because they require forbidden characters, e.g. Ellipsis `.`, MGIFOS `*`, Unary `0`.

Comment: @KennyTM I found another language for answer 1, which works with any final character (not [Lenguage](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40562/asciis-95-characters-95-movie-quotes#comment93975_40562)).

Comment: @KennyTM But it can only output some of the shortest quotes.

Answer (score 2):

## 37. [Braincrash](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Braincrash) (uses no `U`)

```
!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiiiiii!iiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiii!iiiiiiiiii!iii
```

Output is quote 39:

```
"If you build it, he will come." - Shoeless Joe Jackson
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41755/25180) `"#$&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ ABdeEghJLMNopQksvWxXyzZ{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `4` `6` `89`
- Uppercase: `CD` `FGHI` `K` `OP` `RST` `V` `Y`
- Lowercase: `abc` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

It only works in the non-standard Lua compiler.

I feel the `!` character will be gone soon...

#### Generator (CJam)

```
'i8*:T;0cq{_@-_T\0<'!t\z*T4'!t@}%);
```

Answer (score 2):

## 36. [BRB](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BRB) (uses no `I`)

There are 28,059 characters in the source code, it consists only of the characters `F`, `i` and `t`, in the form:

```
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF…FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFiFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFiFFFFF…FFFFFFFFFFFit
```

**Since the post body is limited to 30,000 characters** I'm not going to reproduce the whole content here. Check http://pastebin.com/zFi8TbHz if you are intereseted. You may also obtain it as this base64-encoded zlib-compressed data:

```
eJzt2lsSgjAQBdHdsRf+3X+5BR6dmZuh+aY8bRKCisfx+DiRU9bhW3sX1cqs4iH4xgwnzbEjfvWE
FUfc6MdOz3ZQy1DOX8Q12C0l46KK20p6uMwroGtbHb8snqgts5W5LjdSmti3SuPW4KV/7QTuCB2B
IWbUVDeBfWre4LfJn5n1rDkf/NU9cgvP3GY29fb4tJqNjh3DgEsx9OectUhBxdA7ZI/30CUeWt8j
i1feuO2hlgy5rzT9t2LoDlW7Yuu3mFUvkU5ucs/Zhxv6xt44fT9lhT/ovGnbyNg2MraNjG0jY9vI
2DYyto2MbSNj28jYNjK2jYxtI2PbyNg2MraNjG0jY9vI2DYyto2MbSNj28jYNjK2jYxtI2PbyNg2
MraNjG0jY9vI2DYyto2MbSNj28jYNjK2jYxtI2PbyNg2MraNjG0jY9vI2DYyto2MbSNj28jYNjK2
jYxtI2PbyNg2MraNjG0jY9vI2DYy9vn7AxSpJ7c=
```

The SHA-1 sum after decompression should be `bd1b5b8c932fd71c5e22f133441baeb6fe6ca7c5` without trailing new lines.

Output is quote 34:

```
"You know how to whistle, don't you, Steve? You just put your lips together and blow." - Marie "Slim" Browning
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41794/32353): `"#$&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ ABdeEghJLMNopQksUvWxXyzZ{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `4` `6` `89`
- Uppercase: `CD` `FGH` `K` `OP` `RST` `V` `Y`
- Lowercase: `abc` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

---

BRB is a language that contains multiple "tapes" that can be modified at runtime. The program above will generate another program on the second tape, and then execute the code on the second tape to print the real quote. This is needed because in BRB the output command is `'` which has been forbidden long time ago.

The generator is pretty simple:

```python
def to_raw_brb_code(quote):
    return ';' + quote + ';' + "{'" * len(quote)

def generate_code(code):
    for char in code:
        yield 'F' * ord(char)
        yield 'i'
    yield 't'

print(''.join(generate_code(to_raw_brb_code(quote))))
```

Comment: A missed opportunity for Markdown golf by trying to fit the rest of the post in the remaining 1941 characters ;)

Answer (score 2):

## 35. [Headsecks](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Headsecks), uses no `Y`

``````````````
!!6!!!!!!!C``2?C!!4C!6!!!C`2?C!!4C`6!!!!!C```2?C`4!!!!!!!4`````````````4!!!!!!!!!46!C```2?C!4``6!!!C``2?C4C!6!!!C`2?C!!4C`6!!!!!C```2?C`4!!!!!!!4`````````````4!!!!!!!!!46!C```2?C!4``6!!!C``2?C4`6!C``2?C`4`6!!!C`2?C```4!!4!!!!!!!!4!!6!!!C`2?C!46!C```2?C``4!4``4````````4`6``C!!!2?C!4`4!!4!!6!!C```2?C46!!!C``2?C``4`````6!C``2?C46!!C```2?C4!!!!!!!!!!46!!!C`2?C``4!6!!!!C`2?C``4C!6!!!C`2?C!!46!!!C`2?C```4`6!C```2?C``4!!6!!!C`2?C!!!44!!!!!!!!!!!!!46!!!C`2?C!!!44
``````````````

Output is quote 47:

```
"Shane. Shane. Come back!" - Joey Starrett
```

[Previously forbidden:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41796/788) `"#$&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ ABdeEghIJLMNopQksUvWxXyzZ{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `4` `6` `89`
- Uppercase: `CD` `FGH` `K` `OP` `RST` `V`
- Lowercase: `abc` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

---

Although Headsecks is not completely a [trivial Brainfuck substitution](http://esolangs.org/wiki/TrivialBrainfuckSubstitution) since it allows somewhat more flexibility in the characters used, as far as the program above is concerned, this is basically equivalent to [`` TrivialBrainfuckSubstitution("C","2","`","!","4","%","6","?") ``](http://esolangs.org/wiki/TrivialBrainfuckSubstitution).

Thus, it is equvalent to the following Brainfuck program that I generated with a [Brainfuck text generator](http://copy.sh/brainfuck/text.html).

```
--[------->++<]>--.>-[--->+<]>--.>+[----->+++<]>+.-------.+++++++++++++.---------.[->+++<]>-.++[--->++<]>.>-[--->+<]>--.>+[----->+++<]>+.-------.+++++++++++++.---------.[->+++<]>-.++[--->++<]>.+[->++<]>+.+[--->+<]>+++.--.--------.--[--->+<]>-.[->+++<]>++.-.++.++++++++.+[++>---<]>-.+.--.--[-->+++<]>.[--->++<]>++.+++++[->++<]>.[-->+++<]>.----------.[--->+<]>++.-[---->+<]>++.>-[--->+<]>--.[--->+<]>+++.+[->+++<]>++.--[--->+<]>---..-------------.[--->+<]>---..
```

Comment: But the only interpreter I've found https://github.com/TieSoul/Multilang doesn't seemed to support wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

## 32. [PoGo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/PoGo) (uses no `F`)

(New lines are not necessary.)

```
OTOSanmuanOPtuanaDanOPtuanaDanOPtuanaDanOPtuanaDanOPtuanaDanOPtuanaDanOPtu
anOPOTOSDawuwuOSaDwuwuwuwuOSaDwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtututuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuwuwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatututuOSaDtuOSaDtutuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuwuOSaDwuwuwuwuwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutuOSaDtutuOSaDtututuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutuOSaDtututuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOSaDwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatuOSaDtututuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututututuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOSaDwuwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtutuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtututuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututututuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatuOSaDtutuOSaDtututuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtututuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututututuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuwuwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatuOSaDtuOSaDtututuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututututuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtutuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOSaDwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututututuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututuOSaDtutuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututututuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtutuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtutuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututututuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatuOSaDtutuOSaDtututuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuwuOSaDwuwuwuwuwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututuOSaDtutuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuwuwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutuOSaDtuOSaDtutuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututututuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututuOSaDtutuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututututuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatututuOSaDtutuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuwuwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutuOSaDtututuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtutuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuwuOSaDwuwuwuwuOSaDwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututututuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututututuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuwuwuwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututuOSaDtutuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuwuwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutuOSaDtututuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtutuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatututuOSaDtutuOSaDtuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatutututututuOSaDtutuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatuOSaDtututututuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
anOPOTOSDawuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuOSaDwuOSaDwuwuwuOPuc
anOPOTOSDatuOSaDtutuOSaDtututuOSaDtuOSaDtuOPuc
```

Output is quote 46:

```
"Oh, Jerry, don't let's ask for the moon. We have the stars." - Charlotte Vale
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41816/32353): `"#$&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ AbBdeEghIJkLMNopQRsUvWxXyYzZ{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `4` `6` `89`
- Uppercase: `CD` `GH` `K` `OP` `ST` `V`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

---

The PoGo language has a memory stack for arithmetics, and a 2D array to store data. Commands are expressed as pair of letters, and the interpreter is case-insensitive, and ignores whitespaces. Therefore still a lot of commands are available.

The first line of the program fills the array with: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]. Then the following lines walk forward and backward on this array to build up the ASCII code of a character, and then print it out.

Generator, excluding the first line:

```python
def encode(quote):
    values = [64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
    direction = 'wu'
    for c in quote:
        code = ord(c)
        statement = 'anOPOTOSDa'
        for v in values:
            statement += direction
            if code & v:
                statement += 'OSaD'
        statement += direction + 'OPuc'
        direction = 'tu' if direction == 'wu' else 'wu'
        values = values[::-1]
        yield statement
```

Answer (score 2):

## 31. [Fuckfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fuckfuck) (uses no `T`)

(Newlines are not necessary.)

```
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!
cccK
tttS!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
tttS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
cccK
```

Output is quote 26:

```
"Why don't you come up sometime and see me?" - Lady Lou
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41821/25180): `"#$&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ AbBdeEFghIJkLMNopQRsUvWxXyYzZ{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `4` `6` `89`
- Uppercase: `CD` `GH` `K` `OP` `S` `V`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

Yet another Brainfuck variant. `tttS!!!!!!!` decreases the number of `!` + 1 times, and `cccK` is for output.

#### Generator (in CJam)

```
0cq{_@256+\- 256%_{('!*"tttS"\+}{;L}?"cccK"@}/;]N*
```

Without newlines:

```
0cq{_@256+\- 256%_{('!*"tttS"\+}{;L}?"cccK"@}/;
```

Answer (score 2):

## 30. [!Py!Batch 1.5](http://esolangs.org/wiki/!!!Batch) (uses no `C`)

```
?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?c?!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?ff
?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?u?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%t?!!!!!?m?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%
?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?a
?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?n?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%ran?!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?m%
?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%ran?!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?m%
?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?f?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%ran?!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?m%
if?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%n%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?a
if?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%?!!?%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?a
if?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%f%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?a
t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?nul?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%n%
ma?!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?ca?!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?c?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?m?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?ff?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?rca?!!?in?!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?8?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?4?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?rf?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?l?!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!?ata?!!?l?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?c?!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%n%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%?!!?%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?nul
fin?!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?tr?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%?!!?%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%f%
?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%f%
ma?!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?ca?!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?c?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?m?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?ff?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?rca?!!?in?!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?2?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?4?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?rf?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?l?!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!?ata?!!?l?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?c?!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%n%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%?!!?%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?nul
fin?!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?tr?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%?!!?%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%f%
?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?c?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%f%
ma?!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?ca?!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?c?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?m?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?ff?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?rca?!!?in?!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?9994?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?rf?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?l?!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!?ata?!!?l?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?c?!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%n%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%?!!?%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?nul
fin?!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?tr?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%?!!?%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%f%
?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?q?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%f%
ma?!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?ca?!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?c?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?m?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?ff?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?rca?!!?in?!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?66?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?rf?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?l?!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?r?!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!?ata?!!?l?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?c?!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%n%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%?!!?%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?nul
fin?!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?tr?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%?!!?%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%f%
?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?a?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%f%
?!!!!??!!!!!?l?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%n%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%?!!?%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%f%
?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!?
?!!!!!?c?!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%?!!!!?%%a%ft?!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?all%c%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?m?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?rr?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?w?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?i?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?an?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?t?!!!!!!!!??!!!!!?r?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!?a?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?%?!!!!?%?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?Scarl?!!!!!?tt?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?O%q%Hara
```

Output is quote 31:

```
"After all, tomorrow is another day!" - Scarlett O'Hara
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41834/32353): `"#$&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ AbBdeEFghIJkLMNopQRsTUvWxXyYzZ{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `4` `6` `89`
- Uppercase: `D` `GH` `K` `OP` `S` `V`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

---

!!!Batch and !Py!Batch are dialects of Windows command script, which replaces common characters with a string of `?!!…!!?`. Uppercase characters are encoded in `?!!…!!+?` which we cannot use, and `"`, `,` and `'` are not replaced so we have to generate the 4 characters `A",'` by other means. We cannot use `(`, `)` in the script for the same reason.

The approach used here is based on http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-genchr.html. The `makecab` program is used to perform a function similar to `chr()`. However, as `(` and `)` are forbidden we cannot use `for /f` at all. Instead, we adjust the header data so that the character we want appear alone in its own line, e.g. in the command

```
makecab ^
    /d compress=off ^
    /d reservepercabinetsize=16650 ^
    /d reserveperfoldersize=13 ^
    /d reserveperdatablocksize=10 ^
    empty.txt target.cab > nul
```

16650 = 10 + 65 × 256. The `target.cab` will then contain the string `\nA\r\n` somewhere. This should be the only line that contains a single character. We then use `findstr` to fetch this character "A" out:

```
findstr /b /e /r . target.cab > a.txt
```

And finally read its content into a variable:

```
set /p character=<a.txt
```

The final batch script is:

```bash
@echo off
pushd %temp%
:a
set n=%random%
set b=%random%
set f=%random%
if exist %n% goto :a
if exist %b% goto :a
if exist %f% goto :a
type nul > %n%
makecab /d compress=off /d reservepercabinetsize=8714 /d reserveperfoldersize=13 /d reserveperdatablocksize=10 %n% %b% > nul
findstr /ber . %b% > %f%
set /p d=<%f%
makecab /d compress=off /d reservepercabinetsize=11274 /d reserveperfoldersize=13 /d reserveperdatablocksize=10 %n% %b% > nul
findstr /ber . %b% > %f%
set /p c=<%f%
makecab /d compress=off /d reservepercabinetsize=9994 /d reserveperfoldersize=13 /d reserveperdatablocksize=10 %n% %b% > nul
findstr /ber . %b% > %f%
set /p q=<%f%
makecab /d compress=off /d reservepercabinetsize=16650 /d reserveperfoldersize=13 /d reserveperdatablocksize=10 %n% %b% > nul
findstr /ber . %b% > %f%
set /p a=<%f%
del %n% %b% %f%
popd
echo %d%%a%fter all%c% tomorrow is another day!%d% - Scarlett O%q%Hara
```

Then we just need to replace the offending characters by `?!!…!!?` and finish.

Answer (score 2):

## 26. [BrainSpace 1.0](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BrainSpace_1.0) (uses no `j`)

```
PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPPOPPPPPPPPPOPPPPPOPPOmmOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmOmmmmmmmmmmmOPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmOmmmmmmmmmOmmmmOmOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPOPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmOmmOmmmmmmmmOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPPPOmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmOmmmmmmOPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPOmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOmmmmmmmmmmmmOmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPPPPPPPPPPPPPOOmmmmmOmmmmmmmOmOPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPOmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmOPPPPPPPPPPPPPO
```

Output is quote 21:

```
"A census taker once tried to test me. I ate his liver with some fava beans and a nice Chianti." - Hannibal Lecter
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41931/32353): `` "#$&'()*+,-./013567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFghIJkLMNopQRsTUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~ ``

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?`
- Numbers: `2` `4` `89`
- Uppercase: `D` `GH` `K` `OP` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `i` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

---

Generator:

```python
def encode(quote):
    val = 0
    for char in quote:
        c = ord(char)
        if c >= val:
            yield 'P' * (c - val)
        else:
            yield 'm' * (val - c)
        val = c
        yield 'O'
```

Answer (score 2):

## 15. [ProgFk](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ProgFk) (uses no `f`)

```
SaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrSncKrKrSncKrSncKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrKrSncKrKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrKrSncKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrKrSncKrKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrKrSncKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrKrSncKrSncKrKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrKrSncKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrKrSncKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrSncKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrKrSncKrKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrKrSncKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrSncKrSncKrKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrSncKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrKrKrSncKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrKrKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrKrKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrKrKrSncKrSncKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrKrSncKrKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrKrKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrKrKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrSncKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrSncKrKrSncStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrKrSncKrKrSncKrSncKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrSncKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrSncKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrKrKrSncKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrKrKrKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrSncKrSncKrKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrKrSncKrKrSncKrSncKrKrStSaSaSaSaSaSaSaKrSncKrKrSncKrKrSncKrSncKrSncStO
```

Output is quote 12:

```
"I love the smell of napalm in the morning." - Lt. Col. Bill Kilgore
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42037/25180):

```
?!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFgGhHiIjJkLmMNopPqQRsTUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~
```

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: none
- Numbers: `4` `8` `9`
- Uppercase: `D` `K` `O` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `l` `n` `r` `t` `u` `w`

Tested in Windows. It didn't work in wine or mono.

Explanation:

- `D` Set current bit to 1.
- `S` Set current bit to 0.
- `Kr` Set current bit to 1 and move left.
- `KrSnc` Set current bit to 0 and move left.
- `t` Output.
- `Sa` Set current bit to 0 and move right.
- `O` End.

#### Generator (in CJam)

```
q{"Sa"7*\i{2md"Kr""KrSnc"?\}7*'D'S?'t}/'O
```

Answer (score 1):

## 62. [Argh!](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Argh!) (uses no `_`)

```
jmA:D!::::O!::::R!:::::aA:::N!:aA::::qC:::::N!:aA::RqCaA::V#:N!:!::::::::::cA
lSRfSAdddfSAfdffSAfddffSRfdfSAfSRdflfSRfdfdfSAfSRdfSSRSRffSAfSAfAfflldfdfllSRfj
::C:q!D!r:R::!::Nk:na::rg:r:mr:fCq:A:NO:::r:hw:n:::attuO::::::r:t::all:r:dniC:j
jdRPSASAPPShPAPPSPPPSPPPPPPPPPPPRSPPPSSPdPPPPPPPddPPPPPPPPhhPhPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPh
d:::::aaA:A:::aA:::::A:aA::!:!:R!aA::::R!:aA::aA::N!:::aA::N!:::N!:aA:mA:N!
lfffllSSRfRfflSRffdffRfSRffAfAfSASRffdfSAfSRffSRffSAfdfSRdfSAfdfSAfSRfSRfSAflfj
::::carim:a::kil::k::l:tI::n:i:mahc::r::t:aM::ht::m::c::!b:D!:t:tu:ba:RA:wh:n:j
jPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPhPPPPPPPPPPPhPPPhAPPSAPPPPPPPPPSRPPSPPPh
j::N!:aA::aA:aA:::R::aA:D!::ka:::aAO!:::nAaA:::cA
ldfSAfSRffSRfSRfffSddSRfSAjlSRflfSRSAfdfSRSRfffSRfj
:!:l::h:::ht:ni:::tIjfR:Hfhk:::r:lkca:S:lraC::::::j
LPPPhPPhPPPPPPPPPPPPhRlPk:lk:qPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPhhPh
```

Output is quote 92.

```
"Cinderella story. Outta nowhere. A former greenskeeper, now, about to become the Masters champion. It looks like a mirac...It's in the hole! It's in the hole! It's in the hole!" - Carl Spackler
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40755/25180): `"'&()*+-,./\03;<=>@X[soy pezv]{}`

Answer (score 1):

## 43. Rebmu (uses no `N`)

```
nl
nlPRjnTCtcMD922TI222jnTCtcMD299TI222jnTCtcMD9889TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD8989TI222jnTCtcMD42499TI222jnTCtcMD8989TI222jnTCtcMD42499TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD42499TI222jnTCtcMD996TI222jnTCtcMD8999TI222jnTCtcMD42499TI222jnTCtcMD9889TI222jnTCtcMD4999TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD4999TI222jnTCtcMD42499TI222jnTCtcMD4989TI222jnTCtcMD988TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD996TI222jnTCtcMD4989TI222jnTCtcMD2988TI222jnTCtcMD989TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD8999TI222jnTCtcMD42499TI222jnTCtcMD4999TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD996TI222jnTCtcMD4989TI222jnTCtcMD6989TI222jnTCtcMD989TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD42499TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD98TI222jnTCtcMD999TI222jnTCtcMD9222TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD999TI222jnTCtcMD2988TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD99TI222jnTCtcMD992TI222jnTCtcMD999TI222jnTCtcMD99TI222jnTCtcMD999TI222jnTCtcMD996TI222jnTCtcMD42499TI222jnTCtcMD6998TI222jnTCtcMD989TI222jnTCtcMD4999TI222jnTCtcMD46TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD89TI222jnTCtcMD999TI222jnTCtcMD6999TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD998TI222jnTCtcMD989TI222jnTCtcMD8998TI222jnTCtcMD989TI222jnTCtcMD4998TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD6989TI222jnTCtcMD998TI222jnTCtcMD999TI222jnTCtcMD8999TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD8999TI222jnTCtcMD992TI222jnTCtcMD42499TI222jnTCtcMD6998TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD9889TI222jnTCtcMD999TI222jnTCtcMD6999TI222jnTCtcMD6699TI222jnTCtcMD4998TI222jnTCtcMD989TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD2989TI222jnTCtcMD999TI222jnTCtcMD998TI222jnTCtcMD998TI222jnTCtcMD42499TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD2989TI222jnTCtcMD989TI222jnTCtcMD6998TI222jnTCtcMD46TI222jnTCtcMD922TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD489TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD292TI222jnTCtcMD999TI222jnTCtcMD4998TI222jnTCtcMD4998TI222jnTCtcMD989TI222jnTCtcMD4999TI222jnTCtcMD6998TI222jnTCtcMD698TI222jnTCtcMD4289TI222jnTCtcMD6999TI222jnTCtcMD8989TI222tcMD2998TI222
```

Output is quote 40:

```
"My mama always said life was like a box of chocolates. You never know what you're gonna get." - Forrest Gump
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41591/25180): `"#&'()*+,-./01357:;<=>@[\]^_ BdeEghJopQksvWxXyz{|}~`

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `$` `%` `?` `` ` ``
- Numbers: `2` `46` `89`
- Uppercase: `A` `CD` `FGHI` `KLM` `OP` `RSTUV` `YZ`
- Lowercase: `abc` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

#### Explanation

- `nl`: Newline.

  - The first `nl` does nothing. But it throws an error running the code in a script file without it. It can be omitted if you run it with `rebmu [...]`.
  - The second `nl` does nothing either. It just make the `PR` uppercase.
- `pr`: Print.
- `jn`: Join two strings.
- `tc`: Convert to char. The first `TC` in `TCtc` is a no-op to make `MD` uppercase.
- `md`: Mod.
- `ti`: Convert to integer. It's a no-op to separate two numbers.

There are other ways than `MD`. But I just reused the generator for Gammaplex.

Answer (score 1):

## 27. [Insomnia](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Insomnia) (uses no `V`)

```
GGGHGHGHGGHGjGHGGHGGHGGGjGGGGGHGGGjGGGHGGHGHGGjGHGHGGGHGHGGjGHGGGHGGHGGjGGGGHGGHGHGjGHGHGGGHGHGHGjGHGGGHGHGHGHGjGGGHGHGHGHGHGjGHGGGHGHGHGHGjGHGHGHGGHGHGHGjGHGGGHGHGHGGjGGHGHGGHGHGGjGHGHGGGHGHGHGjGHGGGHGGHGHGjGHGGGHGGHGHGjGGHGGHGHGHGGjGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGjGHGHGHGGHGGGjGGGGGHGGGjGGGHGGHGHGGjGHGHGGGHGHGGjGHGGGHGGHGGjGGGGHGGHGHGjGHGHGGGHGHGHGjGHGGGHGHGHGHGjGGGHGHGHGHGHGjGHGGGHGHGHGHGjGHGHGHGGHGHGHGjGHGGGHGHGHGGjGGHGHGGHGHGGjGHGHGGGHGHGHGjGHGGGHGGHGHGjGHGGGHGGHGHGjGGHGGHGHGHGGjGHGGHGHGHGHGHGjGGGHGHGHGHGHGjGHGHGGGHGHGHGjGHGHGGGHGHGHGjGGGHGHGHGHGHGjGGHGHGHGGGGjGHGGHGHGGGHGjGHGHGGHGGHGHGjGHGGGHGHGHGHGjGGHGGGGHGHGjGHGHGGGHGHGGjGGGHGHGHGHGHGjGGGHGHGGGGjGHGGHGGGGHGjGHGGHGHGGHGHGjGGHGHGHGHGHGHGjGHGHGGHGGHGHGj
```

Output is quote 27:

```
"I'm walking here! I'm walking here!" - "Ratso" Rizzo
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41926/25180): `` "#$&'()*+,-./013567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFghIJkLMNopQRsTUvWxXyYzZ{|}~ ``

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `!` `%` `?`
- Numbers: `2` `4` `89`
- Uppercase: `D` `GH` `K` `OP` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `ij` `lmn` `qr` `tu` `w`

[Interpreter by n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳](http://nhahtdh.clanteam.com/eso/Insomnia.html).

#### Generator (in CJam)

```
0q{i2*256md+_@^3^[{2md!'H*'G@}8*;]'j@}/;
```

Answer (score 1):

## 24. [3var](http://esolangs.org/wiki/3var), uses no `!`

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaOraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaO
```

Output is quote 33:

```
"I'll have what she's having." - Customer
```

[Previously forbidden](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41942/21487): `` "#$&'()*+,-./013567:;<=>@[\]^_` AbBCdeEFghIjJkLMNopqQRsTUvVWxXyYzZ{|}~ ``

Remaining characters:

- Symbols: `%` `?`
- Numbers: `2` `4` `89`
- Uppercase: `D` `GH` `K` `OP` `S`
- Lowercase: `a` `c` `f` `i` `lmn` `r` `tu` `w`

After my last answer ages back, I had a short list of languages which I wanted to keep up my sleeve. Most of them have been rendered unusable, but some (evil, CaneCode and asdf) have made it in as answers.

This is the last language I had bookmarked that, surprisingly, still works. It uses three instructions:

- `a`: Increment variable B
- `O`: Output variable B as ASCII
- `r`: Reset all variables

I took the opportunity to choose what I believe is the funniest quote in the list :P

<sup>(Funnily enough, when I first found this language I wasn't sure if I could use it since it was unimplemented. Guess what — it looks like someone added an interpreter 3 days ago.)</sup>