# RadioASCII Elements: Output the elements of the periodic table while slowly losing characters

Tags: code-challenge, rosetta-stone

Here is a list of the 118 (current) elements of the periodic table (in a collapsed Stack Snippet for your convenience):

```html
Hydrogen
Helium
Lithium
Beryllium
Boron
Carbon
Nitrogen
Oxygen
Fluorine
Neon
Sodium
Magnesium
Aluminium
Silicon
Phosphorus
Sulfur
Chlorine
Argon
Potassium
Calcium
Scandium
Titanium
Vanadium
Chromium
Manganese
Iron
Cobalt
Nickel
Copper
Zinc
Gallium
Germanium
Arsenic
Selenium
Bromine
Krypton
Rubidium
Strontium
Yttrium
Zirconium
Niobium
Molybdenum
Technetium
Ruthenium
Rhodium
Palladium
Silver
Cadmium
Indium
Tin
Antimony
Tellurium
Iodine
Xenon
Caesium
Barium
Lanthanum
Cerium
Praseodymium
Neodymium
Promethium
Samarium
Europium
Gadolinium
Terbium
Dysprosium
Holmium
Erbium
Thulium
Ytterbium
Lutetium
Hafnium
Tantalum
Tungsten
Rhenium
Osmium
Iridium
Platinum
Gold
Mercury
Thallium
Lead
Bismuth
Polonium
Astatine
Radon
Francium
Radium
Actinium
Thorium
Protactinium
Uranium
Neptunium
Plutonium
Americium
Curium
Berkelium
Californium
Einsteinium
Fermium
Mendelevium
Nobelium
Lawrencium
Rutherfordium
Dubnium
Seaborgium
Bohrium
Hassium
Meitnerium
Darmstadtium
Roentgenium
Copernicium
Ununtrium
Flerovium
Ununpentium
Livermorium
Ununseptium
Ununoctium
```

*Note: This list was found by running the following JavaScript code on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_elements): `[].slice.call($('.wikitable:first tr td:nth-child(3)').map(function(){return this.innerText})).slice(1,-1).join('\n')`*

Your challenge is to output as many of them as possible, in as many languages as possible. This goal is even further complicated by the fact that the radioactive elements are slowly eating away at your remaining usable characters as you go!

### Rules

1. Your answer will consist of 1 to 95 code snippets.
2. Each code snippet must be in a different programming language. For the purpose of this challenge, I'm using a very loose definition of "language": Anything that's not backwards-compatible is a different language. For example, if all Lang A code works in Lang B but Lang B adds more, then they're considered the same language. But Python 2 and Python 3 are considered different, because `print 'foo'` is valid in Python 2 but not in Python 3.
3. The first code snippet may use some or all of the 95 printable ASCII characters. In the second snippet, one ASCII character of your choice will be forbidden. In the third snippet, that character plus one more of your choice must be forbidden. And so on. Tabs and newlines are never forbidden.
4. The forbidden character **must** have been used in the previous snippet, *not* in a comment, string literal, etc.; it must actually get interpreted by the compiler/interpreter. For example, if my first snippet is `print 'Hydrogen'`, I can't make `&` forbidden because I didn't use it. My choices are any of the characters `p`, `r`, `i`, `n`, `t`, , or `'` (I can't use `H`, `y`, `d`, ... because those are in a string literal). The character you choose is from then on forbidden to appear at all in any subsequent snippets.
5. Each code snippet must output a unique element of the periodic table (found in the list above). "Output" can be done by any method you wish: STDOUT, an alert box (ex. in JS), REPL "output" (keep in mind that if it includes quotes, it's invalid), writing to a file, etc.
6. You must either take no input, or an empty string as input (for languages like sed).
7. You may not use built-in functions that return the element name (ex. `ElementData` in Mathematica).

### Formatting

Please format your answer with the following format:

```
### 1. Language A - none forbidden

    code

Optional commentary on this snippet goes here.

### 2. Language B - `a` forbidden

    code

More optional commentary

### 3. Language C - `ab` forbidden

    code

More optional commentary
```

etc.

If backticks (`` ` ``) are forbidden, simply use two backticks around the list instead. For example, ``` ``ab`cd`` ``` will result in `` ab`cd ``. (If the backtick is the first or last character, you must also pad the outer backticks with spaces; ex. ``` `` abc` `` ``` -> `` abc` ``.)

### Scoring

The answer with the most programming languages will win. In the event of a tie, the answer with the smallest cumulative character count of all of the programs will win.

---

<sup>This question was [inspired by this.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40562/3808)</sup>

Comment: Just so I get this right, this is basically the same as the 95 movie quotes challenge except everyone is playing it solitaire?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, that's essentially what it is. (Also, the criterion for "separate language" is less strict, the outputs are shorter, and the forbidden character has some restrictions.)

Comment: Forbidden characters can't be **chosen** from string literals, and they also can't be **used** in future strings?

Comment: I'm just sad you didn't use the term "RadioASCII Elements".

Comment: @Scimonster Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies [status-completed] ;)

Comment: @DLosc Not all C code is valid C++.. for example, naming a variable `class`.

Comment: Should I take "code snippet" to mean "not necessarily a complete program," e.g. `cout<<"Hydrogen";` in C++? Do we need to include `include`s in the code? Does a program need to print a newline after the name of the element?

Comment: @DLosc No, the snippets must all be full, runnable, complete programs. The newline is optional.

Comment: **Please note that this list of elements is now out-of-date. All elements are now officially named.**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## 95 languages (all characters used!)

### (TODO: a couple more answers that I have planned out but not implemented)

#### 1. COBOL - forbids `A`

```
PROGRAM-ID.g.PRODECURE DIVISION.DISPLAY"Ununtrium".
```

Prints `Ununtrium`.

#### 2. REBOL - forbids `B`

```
REBOL[]prin"Tellurium"
```

Prints `Tellurium`.

#### 3. bc - forbids `^`

```
a=0^0
"Strontium"
```

Prints `Strontium`.

#### 4. D - forbids `D`

```
void main(char[][]D){printf="Ruthenium";}
```

Prints `Ruthenium`.

#### 5. Java - forbids `E`

```
enum E{E;{System.out.print("\x41luminium");}}
```

Prints `Aluminium`.

#### 6. Scala - forbids `F`

```
val F=print("Plutonium")
```

Prints `Plutonium`.

#### 7. Rust - forbids `G`

```
fn main(){let G:u8;print("\x41mericium")}
```

Prints `Americium`.

#### 8. Nim - forbids `&`

```
discard 0&0
echo "Neptunium"
```

Prints `Neptunium`.

#### 9. C# - forbids `C`

```
class V{static void Main(){System.Console.Write("Neodymium");}}
```

Prints `Neodymium`.

#### 10. [Burlesque](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Burlesque) - forbids `%`

```
,1 1.%vv"Manganese"Q
```

Prints `Manganese`.

#### 11. Nemerle - forbids `I`

```
Nemerle.IO.print("Magnesium")
```

Prints `Magnesium`.

#### 12. Ada - forbids `J`

```
procedure gnat.io.J is begin put("Palladium");end;
```

Prints `Palladium`.

#### 13. Go - forbids `|`

```
package main
func main(){if 1|1>0{print("Germanium")}}
```

Prints `Germanium`.

#### 14. K - forbids ```

```
`0:"Ytterbium"
```

Prints `Ytterbium`.

#### 15. Erlang - forbids `/`

```
-module(test).
-export([m/0]).
m()->io:put_chars("\x42eryllium").
```

Prints `Beryllium`.

#### 16. Prolog - forbids `:`

```
m:-write('\102erkelium').
```

Prints `Berkelium`.

#### 17. Smalltalk - forbids `K`

```
K:=0.'Lanthanum'display
```

Prints `Lanthanum`.

#### 18. PARI/GP - forbids `L`

```
print(Potassium)
```

Prints `Potassium`.

#### 19. REXX - forbids `M`

```
M=0
say "Tungsten"
```

Prints `Tungsten`.

#### 20. LilyPond - forbids `N`

```
#(let((N 0))(print"\x46levorium"))
```

Prints `Flevorium`.

#### 21. Arc - forbids `Q`

```
(let Q 1(pr "\x41ntimony"))
```

Prints `Antimony`.

#### 22. Common LISP - forbids `R`

```
(let((R 0))(princ"Tantalum"))
```

Prints `Tantalum`.

#### 23. Clojure - forbids `U`

```
(def U)(pr'Selenium)
```

Prints `Selenium`.

#### 24. Logo - forbids `Z`

```
to Z
end
pr[Scandium]bye
```

Prints `Scandium`.

#### 25. Groovy - forbids `W`

```
print"Samarium";W=0
```

Prints `Samarium`.

#### 26. Asymptote - forbids `X`

```
write('\x52ubidium');int X=0;
```

Prints `Rubidium`.

#### 27. Octave - forbids `Y`

```
Y=0;disp Yttrium
```

Prints `Yttrium`.

#### 28. gnuplot - forbids `V`

```
V=0;prin"Vanadium
```

Prints `Vanadium`.

#### 29. Kite - forbids `z`

```
z=0;"\x4eobelium"|print;
```

Prints `Nobelium`.

#### 30. Squirrel - forbids `_`

```
print("\x4eitrogen");local _=0;
```

Prints `Nitrogen`.

#### 31. Curry - forbids `v`

```
v=v;main=putStr"\x4cutetium"
```

Prints `Lutetium`.

#### 32. Fortran - forbids `q`

```
q=0;print'("Thallium")';end
```

Prints `Thallium`.

#### 33. Pascal - forbids `l`

```
begin;var l:integer;write(#70#114#97#110#99#105#117#109)end.
```

Prints `Francium`.

#### 34. PHP - forbids `k`

```
<?=$k="\70\108\117\111\114\105\110\101";
```

Prints `Fluorine`.

#### 35. Haskell - forbids `S`

```
main=putStr"Sodium"
```

Prints `Sodium`.

#### 36. C++ - forbids `~`

```
#include<cstdio>
main(){~puts("\x41ctinium");}
```

Prints `Actinium`.

#### 37. ObjC - forbids `j`

```
main(j){puts("Hydrogen");}
```

Prints `Hydrogen`.

#### 38. Lua - forbids `g`

```
print("\65statine")
```

Prints `Astatine`.

#### 39. JavaScript - forbids `b`

```
alert("\x43h\x6corine")
```

Alerts `Chlorine`.

#### 40. Bash - forbids `h`

```
echo Osmium
```

Prints `Osmium`.

#### 41. Cyan - forbids `o`

```
say"Hassium"
o=0
```

Prints `Hassium`.

#### 42. J - forbids `d`

```
wd'Titanium'
```

Prints `Titanium`.

#### 43. Scheme - forbids `x`

```
(let((x 0))(print"Vana\x64ium"))
```

Prints `Vanadium`.

#### 44. C - forbids `{`

```
main(){puts("\x55ranium");}
```

Prints `Uranium`.

#### 45. FORTH - forbids `m`

```
84 emit
104 emit
111 emit
114 emit
105 emit
117 emit
109 emit
```

Prints `Thorium`.

#### 46. BASIC - forbids `T`

```
T$="Tin"
?T$
```

Prints `Tin`.

#### 47. Perl 6 - forbids `y`

```
say "\o124\o145\o162\o142\o151\o165\o155"
```

Prints `Terbium`.

#### 48. [Asdf](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Asdf) - forbids `a`

```
asaasaasssasaasssassaasaasssaasaasssaasaasssaasaasssaasaasssasaasssassaasaasssasaasssassasaasssassasaasssassaasaasssaasaasssasaasssassaasaasssaasaasssasaasssassasaasssassasaasssassaasaasssaasaasssasaasssassasaasssassaasaasssasaasssassasaasssassaasaasssaasaasssasaasssassaasaasssasaasssassaasaasssasaasssassasaasssassaasaasssasaasssassasaasssassasaasssassaasaasssaasaasssasaasssassasaasssassaasaasssasaasssassaasaasssaasaasssasaasssassaasaasssasaasssassasaasssassaasaasssaasaasssaasaasssasaasssassasaasssass
```

Prints `Arsenic`. [Generating script](https://bpaste.net/show/1e0b74843da1).

#### 49. Tcl - forbids `s`

```
puts "\123\151\154\151\143\157\156"
```

Prints `Silicon`.

#### 50. Perl - forbids `;`

```
print"\122\150\157\144\151\165\155";
```

Prints `Rhodium`.

#### 51. Python - forbids `r`

```
print"\103\150\162\157\155\151\165\155"
```

Prints `Chromium`.

#### 52. [WARP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/WARP) - forbids `=`

```
=nn0(82(104(110(105(117(109
```

Prints `Rhenium`.

#### 53. [ETA](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ETA) - forbids `n`

```
nnOtOe nHHOne enenteht O
nnHHHe nHHtOe enenteht O
nntOHe nHHtne enenteht O
nnHnHe nHHtne enenteht O
nntnte nHHtne enenteht O
nHOHne nHHHte enenteht O
```

Prints `Bromine`.

#### 54. [Axo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Axo) - forbids `\`

```
99*3+(94+8*('u'(93+9*(35*7*('fu'(7+(\
```

Prints `Thulium`.

#### 55. Ruby - forbids `t`

```
putc 69
putc 117
putc 114
putc 111
putc 112
putc 105
putc 117
putc 109
```

Prints `Europium`.

#### 56. [DBFV!](http://esolangs.org/wiki/DBFV!) - forbids `u`

```
u<9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u6 u>
u<9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u6 u>
u<9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u3 u>
u<9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u8 u>
u<9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u6 u>
u<9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 u>
u<9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u9 *u6 *u4 u>
```

Prints `Niobium`. Each space is actually a newline.

#### 57. [Mouse](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Mouse) - forbids `'`

```
77 !' 101 !' 114 !' 99 !' 117 !' 114 !' 121 !'
```

Prints `Mercury`.

#### 58. [Word](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Word) - forbids `f`

```
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff.
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff.
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff.
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff.
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff.
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff.
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff.
```

Prints `Cadmium`.

#### 59. [Ftack](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ftack) - forbids `$`

```
H 109 117 105 104 116 105 $ 1 76
```

Prints `Lithium`.

#### 60. [WASD](http://esolangs.org/wiki/WASD) - forbids `e`

We introduce the concept of the *trivial Brainfuck solution* (TBS): we can print any character in 257 Brainfuck commands by incrementing the accumulator *c* times, outputting, then incrementing it (256-*c*) more times to reset it. Repeating this for each character in the string yields the solution. Whenever we have two subprograms `i` and `o` that function exactly like Brainfuck's `+` and `.`, we call the translated TBS the (`i`, `o`)-TBS.

Instead of wrapping around we might be able to set the accumulator to zero after printing using some subprogram `o'`. This is the (`i`, `o'`)-zeroing TBS.

Alternatively, we might have no wrapping but a subprogram `d` that decrements the accumulator. This is a the (`i`, `o`, `d`)-TBS.

For WASD a (`w`, `e`)-TBS prints `Silver`.

#### 61. [URSL](http://esolangs.org/wiki/URSL) - forbids `w`

A (`i1`, `w1`, `c1`)-TBS prints `Krypton`.

#### 62. [Emmental](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Emmental) - forbids `#`

```
#73#114#105#100#105#117#109
```

Prints `Iridium`.

#### 63. [Owl](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Owl) - forbids `?`

```
0[]?83)117)108)102)117)114)
```

Prints `Sulfur`.

#### 64. [RUBE](http://esolangs.org/wiki/RUBE) - forbids `)`

```
    +   +   +       +
 8478 666 667 6965767 6 )
 cccccccccccccccccccccccc

 ........................
O
c
.
```

Prints `Holmium`.

#### 65. [Headsecks](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Headsecks) - forbids `(`

A (`(`, `"`)-TBS prints `Bohrium`.

#### 66. [FALSE](http://esolangs.org/wiki/FALSE) - forbids `[`

```
[]!71,97,108,105,117,109,
```

Prints `Gallium`.

#### 67. [Betterave](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Betterave) - forbids `-`

```
,-,++66,-,+8,+5,+*55,*8958
```

Prints `Hafnium`.

#### 68. [Kipple](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Kipple) - forbids `>`

```
70>o 101>o 114>o 109>o 105>o 117>o 109>o
```

Prints `Fermium`.

#### 69. [GolfScript](http://esolangs.org/wiki/GolfScript) - forbids `]`

```
68]117]98]110]105]117]109]""^
```

Prints `Dubnium`.

#### 70. [FlogScript](http://esolangs.org/wiki/FlogScript) - forbids `"`

```
67"P.97"P.108"P.99"P.105"P.117"P.109"P.
```

Prints `Calcium`.

#### 71. [OOo CODE](http://esolangs.org/wiki/OOo_CODE) - forbids `p`

A (`PpP`, `PPp`)-TBS prints `Bismuth`.

#### 72. [dc](http://esolangs.org/wiki/dc) - forbids `P`

```
67P97P100P109P105P117P109P
```

Prints `Cadmium`.

#### 73. [Capuirequiem](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Capuirequiem) - forbids `O`

```
82O97O100O105O117O109O
```

Prints `Radium`.

#### 74. [BitChanger](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BitChanger) - forbids `}`

```
TODO
```

Prints `Cobalt`.

#### 75. [Vrejvax](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Vrejvax) - forbids `<`

```
TODO
```

Prints `Cerium`.

#### 76. [Fueue](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fueue) - forbids `H`

```
80 111 108 111 110 105 117 109 H
```

Prints `Polonium`.

#### 77. [Pi](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Pi) - forbids `6`

Run `bf2pi` from the wiki article on a trivial Brainfuck solution to print `Xenon`.

#### 78. [CJam](http://esolangs.org/wiki/CJam) - forbids `5`

A (`1+`, `c 0`)-zeroing TBS (with `0` prepended) prints `Nickel`.

#### 79. [Wordfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Wordfuck) - forbids `9`

A (`9999`, `99`)-TBS prints `Carbon`.

#### 80. [Lenguage](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage) - forbids `7`

```
≈ 3^(257*4*3) sevens
```

See 91-94 (use only `7`.) Prints `Radon`.

#### 81. [Binaryfuck (hexadecimal)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Binaryfuck) - forbids `4`

```
TODO
```

Prints `Barium`.

#### 82. [CaneCode](http://esolangs.org/wiki/CaneCode) - forbids `8`

A (`1`, `8`)-TBS prints `Iodine`.

#### 83. [Numberwang](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Numberwang) - forbids `3`

A (`2`, `3`)-TBS prints `Indium`, but `2` decrements instead of incrementing, so subtract each character code from 256 first.

#### 84. [ferNANDo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ferNANDo) - forbids `2`

```
1 1 1
2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1
2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2
2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1
2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1
2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2
```

Prints `Argon`.

#### 85. [Unefunge-98](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge) - forbids `@`

Prepending `0` to a (`1+`, `,0`)-zeroing TBS, and appending `@`, prints `Helium`.

#### 86. [Whirl](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Whirl) - forbids `1`

Prepending `One Load Zero` to an (`Add`, `AscIO Zero`)-zeroing TBS prints `Boron`.

#### 87. [ReverseFuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ReverseFuck) - forbids `,`

A (`-`, `,`)-TBS prints `Erbium`.

#### 88. [Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck) - forbids `+`

A (`+`, `.`)-TBS prints `Curium`.

#### 89. [Deadfish~](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish~) - forbids `c`

An (`i`, `c`)-TBS prints `Copper`.

#### 90. [Iota](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Iota) - forbids `i`

We compute a Church-numeral base-256-decoding to `Zinc` to make up for Iota's lack of IO. Define

```
succ = ***i*i*i*ii***i*i*i*ii**i*i*ii*i*i*i*ii*i*i*ii
```

Then the solution is 1516858978 repetitions of `succ` followed by `*ii`, for a total length of 69775512991 bytes.

#### Unary-like programs

The following four solutions (and 70) are similar: they all consist of approximately 3^(257*4*3) repetitions of the character they forbid (except Ellipsis is thrice as long). The exact value is decided by converting the TBS to octal as described on the wiki.

#### 91. [Ellipsis](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ellipsis) - forbids `.`

```
≈ 3^(257*4*3+1) periods
```

Prints `Neon`.

#### 92. [Ecstatic](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ecstatic) - forbids `!`

```
≈ 3^(257*4*3) exclamation marks
```

Prints `Lead`.

#### 93. [MGIFOS](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MGIFOS) - forbids `*`

```
≈ 3^(257*4*3) asterisks
```

Prints `Iron`.

#### 94. [Unary](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary) - forbids `0`

```
≈ 3^(257*4*3) zeros
```

Prints `Gold`.

#### 95. [Whitespace](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Whitespace) - forbids space

The Whitespace program generated by this Python script:

```
import sys
for c in 'Oxygen':
    print '   ' + ''.join(' \t'[int(b)] for b in bin(ord(c))[2:])
    sys.stdout.write('\t\n  ')
print '\n\n'
```

prints `Oxygen`.

Comment: So... you use the characters you forbid in almost every program?

Comment: When I write "forbids `x`", I really mean "uses `x` and forbids it for the next solutions". The string became unmanageable otherwise.

Comment: Oh, OK. Although having them all together would make it easier to look for any mistakes :)

Answer (score 18):

## 51 Languages

I might add to this later, but here are 51 languages.

#### 1. Java - none forbidden

```
public class p{public static void main(String[]J){System.out.println("Tellurium");}}
```

#### 2. C++ - `J` forbidden

```
#include<cstdio>
main(){int Q=std::puts("Palladium");}
```

#### 3. C - `JQ` forbidden

```
main(W){puts("Neodymium");}
```

#### 4. D - `JQW` forbidden

```
import std.stdio;void main(string[]z){write("Zirconium");}
```

#### 5. Nimrod - `JQWz` forbidden

```
var q="Ruthenium"
echo q
```

#### 6. Fortran-95 - `JQWzq` forbidden

```
program Y
print *,"Potassium"
end program Y
```

#### 7. Batch - `JQWzqY` forbidden

```
@set @c=Aluminium&echo %@c%
```

#### 8. Befunge - `JQWzqY%` forbidden

```
"muinoloP">:#,_@
```

Output Polonium.

#### 9. Vala - `JQWzqY#%` forbidden

```
int main(string[]@a){print("Manganese");return 0;}
```

#### 10. Bash - `JQWzqY#%@` forbidden

```
cd /usr/bin ~/cake;./echo Germanium
```

#### 11. ECMAScript 6 - `JQWzqY#%@~` forbidden

```
alert(`Strontium`)
```

#### 12. Perl 5 - `` JQWzqY#%@~` `` forbidden

```
$_=Magnesium;say
```

#### 13. Scala - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_ `` forbidden

```
object e{def main(args:Array[String]){print("\u0059tterbium")}}
```

#### 14. Perl 6 - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_: `` forbidden

```
$j='Lanthanum';say
```

#### 15. Python 2 - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:j `` forbidden

```
print'Lutetium'
```

#### 16. Python 3 - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jL `` forbidden

```
print('Krypton')
```

#### 17. PHP - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK `` forbidden

```
$n='Berkelium';echo$n;
```

#### 18. Pascal - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$ `` forbidden

```
Program f(X);begin write('Ununtrium');end.
```

#### 19. POGAACK - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$X `` forbidden

```
poock!pogack?poock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pogack!pogaaack!pogaack!pogaack?pogack!poock!pogaaack?pogack?poock!pock!pock!pogack!pogaaack!pock!pock!pock!pock!pogaack!pogaack?pogack!pogaaack!pogaaack?poock!pock!pogack?poock!pogack!pogaaack!pock!pock!pogaack!pogaack?pogack!poock!pogaaack?pogaaack!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pogaaack?poock!pock!pock!pogaaack?poock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pogaaack?poock!pock!pogaaack?pogaaack!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pock!pogaaack?
```

Prints Hydrogen.

#### 20. COW - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$Xg `` forbidden

```
MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOMooMoOMOOMOoMOoMOomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOomoomoOMooMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMooMOoMooMOoMOoMOoMOoMOoMooMOoMooMOoMOoMOoMOoMOoMooMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMooMOoMOoMOoMOoMOoMOoMOoMOoMoo
```

Prints Plutonium.

#### 21. Blub - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgM `` forbidden

```
Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub?Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub.Blub?Blub.Blub.Blub?Blub.Blub?Blub!Blub.Blub?Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub.Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub?Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub.Blub?Blub.Blub.Blub?Blub.Blub?Blub!Blub.Blub?Blub!Blub.Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub!Blub.Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub!Blub.Blub!Blub?Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub.Blub?Blub.Blub.Blub?Blub.Blub?Blub!Blub.Blub?Blub!Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub.Blub!Blub.Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub!Blub.
```

Prints Flerovium.

#### 22. Ook!- `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB `` forbidden

```
Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook?Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook?Ook.Ook.Ook?Ook.Ook?Ook!Ook.Ook?Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook?Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook?Ook.Ook.Ook?Ook.Ook?Ook!Ook.Ook?Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook.Ook!Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.
```

Prints Americium.

#### 23. Ruby - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB! `` forbidden

```
def e?()return "Neptunium"end;print e?
```

#### 24. Lua - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!? `` forbidden

```
f=2*4 if f==8then print("Titanium")end
```

#### 25. R - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?* `` forbidden

```
U<-"Rubidium";print(U)
```

#### 26. Scheme - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U `` forbidden

```
(display "Francium")
```

#### 27. TI Basic - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U) `` forbidden

```
Disp ("Vanadium"
```

#### 28. REXX - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)( `` forbidden

```
do Z=1 to 1
    say 'Europium'
end
return
```

#### 29. BASIC (Yabasic) - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(Z `` forbidden

```
PRINT "Chromium"
```

#### 30. Pyth - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI `` forbidden

```
|0"Scandium
```

#### 31. CJam - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI| `` forbidden

```
"Nobelium"1\\-
```

#### 32. GolfScript - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\ `` forbidden

```
"Samarium"1/
```

#### 33. Brainfuck - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/ `` forbidden

```
,>-[--->+<]>-----.+[--->++++<]>.-----------.--[--->+<]>-.-----------.+++++.+++++++.--------.
```

Takes an empty string as input.

#### 34. Haskell - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/, `` forbidden

```
'Antimon'++['y']
```

#### 35. Deadfish - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[ `` forbidden

```
iisiiiisiiiiiioiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiiiiiioddddddoiiiodddddddddoiiiiiodddddddddo]
```

One of the few of these snippets to output a newline afterwards.

#### 36. [Rebmu](http://rebmu.hostilefork.com/) - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[] `` forbidden

```
PR"Tungsten"
```

#### 37. Tcl - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P `` forbidden

```
puts "Actinium"
```

#### 38. There Once was a Fish Named Fred - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P" `` forbidden

```
a named a a a once was there Fred once a a fish named a a a a a once was was was there Fred once fish was was was was was was was fish a a a a a a a fish was was was was was was was was was fish a a a a a fish was was was was was was was was was was was was fish a a a a a a a a fish
```

Prints Selenium.

#### 39. BrainFNORD - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P"F `` forbidden

```
eris 23 eris eris eris fnord hail pineal 5 fnord eris eris eris eris eris eris eris kallisti 23 eris eris eris fnord hail hail hail hail pineal 5 fnord hail kallisti hail hail hail hail hail hail hail hail hail hail hail kallisti eris eris kallisti eris eris eris kallisti eris eris eris eris eris eris eris eris kallisti eris eris kallisti hail hail hail hail hail hail hail hail hail kallisti
```

Prints Nitrogen.

#### 40. [Text](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Text) - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P"Fl `` forbidden

```
Astatine
```

#### 41. J - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P"Fln `` forbidden

```
'Caesium'
```

#### 42. Pi - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P"Fln' `` forbidden

```
3.4743302180342223222232222423222332223225222222427402331802252232322322343223322224434433435
```

Prints Tantalum.

#### 43. [Marbelous](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/marbelous.py) - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P"Fln'. `` forbidden

```
43686C7072696E65  
      --        }0
```

Prints Chlorine. This relies on the use of spaces for empty cells. [Marbelous Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40808/29611)

#### 44. DNA# - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P"Fln'.} `` forbidden

```
ATCGGCTAATCGATCGATCGATATATTAATGCGCCGATATATCGGCATGCTAATCGATCGATCGATCGATATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATGCGCCGATATATCGGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATGCATATCGATCGATCGGCATATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAATTAGCATATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGCAT
```

Prints Thallium.

#### 45. oOo - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P"Fln'.}G `` forbidden

```
OoOOoOOoOOoOoOoOoOOoOOoOOoOoooOooOooOooooOoOOoooOooOOoOooOooOoooOoOooOooOooOooOoooooOoOooOoOOoooOooOOoOooOooOooOOoOooOooOOoOooOooOooOooOOoOoOOoOOoOOoOOoOOOoOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOooOOo
```

Prints Bromine.

#### 46. ABC - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P"Fln'.}GO `` forbidden

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAC
```

Prints Tin. Note that the interpreters on esolang are all unavailable. However, [4chan's implementation written in Scheme](http://dis.4chan.org/read/prog/1217371234) works (#59).

#### 47. WASD - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P"Fln'.}GOC `` forbidden

```
w1sssdwwa2dwwwe1sssdwa2dweessesssssssssewwwwwwwwwwwwesssssssse
```

Prints Yttrium.

#### 48. Super Stack! - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P"Fln'.}GOCw `` forbidden

```
99 105 110 101 115 114 65
if outputascii fi
```

Prints Arsenic.

#### 49. Golunar - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P"Fln'.}GOCws `` forbidden

```
1334726751425099782624362025339077479253628945660119316869724137277474322140
```

Prints Lithium.

#### 50. Unary - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P"Fln'.}GOCws1 `` forbidden

The source is `0` repeated

```
40732627912143966203790325934799402365062057246763194506454552300861148
```

times.

Prints Hassium.

#### 51. Lenguage - `` JQWzqY#%@~`_:jLK$XgMB!?*U)(ZI|\/,[]P"Fln'.}GOCws10 `` forbidden

The source is `>` repeated

```
9305604867582777545366404070305393137665254080212227303922021923795365639900
```

times.

Prints Bohrium.

---

Most of the odd languages used can be found on the [esolangs wiki](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Please note that all brainfuck (and brainfuck derivatives) snippets were written with 8-bit cells in mind.

Comment: Sorry but all those `2` was pretty strange for Pi language so I ran it on my interpreter (http://migl.io/projects/pi), actually it returns `ª·ÄÊcnw`.

Comment: @Mig `2` is repeated a lot since for any digit of pi greater than or equal to `3`, it represents `+`. The Pi code used in my answer requires 8-bit cells (it begins by decrementing 0), and produces the correct output on the interpreter in the [esolang page for Pi](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Pi).

Answer (score 7):

## <s>20</s> 24 languages

Here's something to get the ball rolling.  I decided to do the elements in order because I don't know enough languages for the order to matter much.

#### 1. C# - none forbidden

```
public class P{public static void Main(){System.Console.Write("Hydrogen");}}
```

#### 2. PHP - `W` forbidden

```
echo$e="Helium";
```

#### 3. QBasic - `W$` forbidden

```
?"Lithium"
```

#### 4. Windows Batch Script - `W$?` forbidden

```
dir>nul&echo Beryllium
```

#### 5. Brainf*** - `W$?&` forbidden

```
++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>.----------[>++<-]-.+++.---.-.
```

Outputs Boron.

#### 6. C++ - `W$?&+` forbidden

```
#include<iostream>
main(){std::cout<<"Carbon";}
```

#### 7. Befunge - `W$?&+<` forbidden

```
"n eg or ti N">,_@
```

Outputs Nitrogen.

#### 8. Bash - `W$?&+<@` forbidden

```
echo Oxygen 2>1
```

#### 9. [Sisi](https://github.com/dloscutoff/sisi) - `W$?&+<@>` forbidden

```
9 print "Fluorine"
```

#### 10. C - `W$?&+<@>9` forbidden

```
#include"stdio.h"
main(){printf("Neon%c",10);}
```

#### 11. Common Lisp - `W$?&+<@>9,` forbidden

```
(format t "~Codium" #\S)
```

#### 12. [Zephyr](https://github.com/dloscutoff/zephyr) - `W$?&+<@>9,#` forbidden

```
if 1\=0:print"Magnesium";end if
```

#### 13. Prolog - `W$?&+<@>9,#\` forbidden

```
:-write('Aluminium').
```

([Test here](http://ideone.com/EofJ9r).)

#### 14. Java - `W$?&+<@>9,#\:` forbidden

```
class A{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print("Silicon");}}
```

#### 15. Golfscript - `W$?&+<@>9,#\:.` forbidden

```
];"Phosphorus"
```

#### 16. Pyth - `W$?&+<@>9,#\:.]` forbidden

```
|0"Sulfur
```

#### 17. ActionScript - `W$?&+<@>9,#\:.]|` forbidden

```
trace("Chlorine");
```

#### 18. PowerShell - `W$?&+<@>9,#\:.]|;` forbidden

```
write-host"Argon"
```

Fortunately, PowerShell commands can be written in lowercase, avoiding the forbidden `W`.

#### 19. JavaScript - `W$?&+<@>9,#\:.]|;-` forbidden

```
alert("Potassium")
```

#### 20. Python 3 - `W$?&+<@>9,#\:.]|;-"` forbidden

```
print('Calcium')
```

#### 21. Python 2 - `W$?&+<@>9,#\:.]|;-"(` forbidden

```
print'Scandium'
```

#### 22. Perl - `W$?&+<@>9,#\:.]|;-"('` forbidden

```
say q{Titanium}
```

#### 23. Ruby - `W$?&+<@>9,#\:.]|;-"('{` forbidden

```
puts %q!Vanadium!
```

#### 24. CJam - `W$?&+<@>9,#\:.]|;-"('{!` forbidden

```
67c104c114c111c108)c105c117c108)c
```

Outputs Chromium. `)` increments were used to avoid the forbidden 9 in 109 (`m`).

Comment: sed seems to complain: `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression` - maybe try `s/./Beryllium/` or `s/^/Beryllium/`?

Comment: Don't you need the function declaration for C and C++?

Comment: @professorfish Good catch--I didn't get a chance to test all of these. Now that I have, sed (v 4.2.1 on Ubuntu 12.04) doesn't give an error or indeed do anything on an empty input as specified by the OP. (I.e. `echo -n | sed -e 's/^/Beryllium/'`.) I may replace it with something else.

Comment: @BetaDecay Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

### 23 Languages

I set out to beat the 20 language answer... and now I can't be bothered to shoot for 52. ;)

#### 1. Mathematica - none forbidden

```
J;"Krypton"
```

#### 2. Ruby - `J` forbidden

```
K=1;puts 'Vanadium'
```

#### 3. Python 2 - `JK` forbidden

```
Q=1;print 'Xenon'
```

#### 4. Python 3 - `JKQ` forbidden

```
X=1;print('Osmium')
```

#### 5. PHP - `JKQX` forbidden

```
$V=1;echo 'Oxygen';
```

#### 6. Julia - `JKQXV` forbidden

```
O=1;println('Ytterbium')
```

#### 7. JavaScript - `JKQXVO` forbidden

```
Y=1;alert('Yttrium')
```

#### 8. CoffeeScript - `JKQXVOY` forbidden

```
q=1;alert 'Zinc'
```

#### 9. C - `JKQXVOYq` forbidden

```
main(Z){printf("Zirconium");}
```

#### 10. C++ - `JKQXVOYqZ` forbidden

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(){int x;printf("Lawrencium");}
```

#### 11. Matlab - `JKQXVOYqZx` forbidden

```
w=1;'Nickel'
```

#### 12. Perl - `JKQXVOYqZxw` forbidden

```
$k=1;print "Berkelium";
```

#### 13. Perl 6 - `JKQXVOYqZxwk` forbidden

```
$f=1;say'Darmstadtium';
```

#### 14. Java - `JKQXVOYqZxwkf` forbidden

```
public class p{public static void main(String[]v){System.out.println("Dubnium");}}
```

#### 15. [Marbelous](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/marbelous.py) - `JKQXVOYqZxwkfv` forbidden

```
44797370726F7369756D
```

Prints `Dysprosium`.

#### 16. Lua - `JKQXVOYqZxwkfvD` forbidden

```
G=1;print("Erbium")
```

#### 17. Octave - `JKQXVOYqZxwkfvDG` forbidden

```
F=1;disp('Einsteinium');
```

#### 18. Rust - `JKQXVOYqZxwkfvDGF` forbidden

```
fn main(){let E=1;println!("Europium");}
```

#### 19. Fortran - `JKQXVOYqZxwkfvDGFE` forbidden

```
print *,"Indium"
```

#### 20. CJam - `JKQXVOYqZxwkfvDGFEp` forbidden

```
H;"Iodine"
```

#### 21. Golfscript - `JKQXVOYqZxwkfvDGFEpH` forbidden

```
U"Iridium"
```

#### 22. Pyth - `JKQXVOYqZxwkfvDGFEpHU` forbidden

```
I1"Iron
```

I *think* this should be

```
if 1:
    print "Iron"
```

#### 23. Brainfuck - `JKQXVOYqZxwkfvDGFEpHUI` forbidden

```
++++++++[>+>++>+++>++++>+++++>++++++>+++++++>++++++++>+++++++++>++++++++++>+++++++++++>++++++++++++>+++++++++++++>++++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>>++.--<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>++.--<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+.-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>----.++++<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>+.-<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>---.+++<<<<<<<<<<<<<<.
```

Prints `Beryllium`.

Comment: Your Pyth answer does what you think it does :)

Comment: How did you forbid G in language 17? There isn't a G in the Lua answer...

Comment: @BetaDecay thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

### <s>20</s> <s>21</s> 26 languages

Okay, let's see if I can do something out of this, not even trying to aim for top spot... if I can get 20 languages without any mistakes I'll be more than happy.

#### 1. JAVA - none forbidden

```
class J{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print("Hydrogen");}}
```

Prints `Hydrogen`.

#### 2. Pascal - `J` forbidden

```
Program H; begin write('Helium'); end.
```

Prints `Helium`.

#### 3. C - `JP` forbidden

```
#include <stdio.h> main(){printf("Lithium");}
```

Prints `Lithium`.

#### 4. PHP - `JPf` forbidden

```
<?php echo "Beryllium";?>
```

Prints `Beryllium`.

#### 5. C# - `JPf?` forbidden

```
using System;class O{static void Main(){Console.Write("Boron");}}
```

Prints `Boron`.

#### 6. PROLOG - `JPf?W` forbidden

```
:-initialization(main). main:-write('Carbon').
```

Prints `Carbon` - tested [here](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_prolog_online.php).

#### 7. JavaScript - `JPf?W'` forbidden

```
<html>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert("Nitrogen");
    </script>
</html>
```

Prints `Nitrogen`.

#### 8. LOLCODE - `JPf?W'=` forbidden

```
HAI
    VISIBLE "Oxygen"
KTHXBYE
```

Prints `Oxygen`.

#### 9. Befunge '93 - `JPf?W'=K` forbidden

```
"eniroulF">:#,_@
```

Prints `Fluorine` - tested [here](http://www.bedroomlan.org/tools/befunge-93-playground).

#### 10. Visual Basic - `JPf?W'=K@` forbidden

```
Module V
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Neon")
    End Sub
End Module
```

Prints `Neon`.

#### 11. HTML5 - `JPf?W'=K@M` forbidden

```
&#83;&#111;&#100;&#105;&#117;&#109;
```

Prints `Sodium` - inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40586/32139).

#### 12. Brainfuck - `JPf?W'=K@M&` forbidden

```
++[---------->+<]>.-[------>+<]>-.++++++.+++++++.---------.[--->+<]>----.----------.++++++++++++.--------.
```

Prints `Magnesium` - tested [here](http://copy.sh/brainfuck/).

#### 13. JSFuck - `JPf?W'=K@&M<` forbidden

```
(+![]+[][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]
```

Prints `Aluminium` - tested [here](http://www.jsfuck.com/).

#### 14. Bash - `JPf?W'=K@&M<[` forbidden

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Silicon"
```

Prints `Silicon`.

#### 15. Assembly NASM - `JPf?W'=K@&M<[!` forbidden

```
section .text
    global _start
section    .data
    msg db  "Phosphorus"
    len equ $ - msg
_start:
    mov edx, len
    mov ecx, msg
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

Prints `Phosphorus`- tested [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_assembly_online.php).

#### 16. D - `JPf?W'=K@&M<[!$` forbidden

```
import std.stdio;void main(){write("Chlorine");}
```

Prints `Chlorine`.

#### 17. Fortran '95 - `JPf?W'=K@&M<[!$d` forbidden

```
program C
    print *, "Argon"
end program C
```

Prints `Argon` - tested [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_fortran_online.php).

#### 18. Lua - `JPf?W'=K@&M<[!$d*` forbidden

```
print("Sul\x66ur")
```

Prints `Sulfur` - tested [here](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_lua_online.php).

#### 19. Golfscript - `JPf?W'=K@&M<[!$dt` forbidden

```
U"\x50o\x74assium"
```

Prints `Potassium` - tested [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/).

#### 20. Perl 5 - `JPf?W'=K@&M<[!$*dU` forbidden

```
use v5.10;
say "Calciu\x{6d}";
```

Prints `Calcium` - tested [here](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_perl_online.php).

#### 21. Nimrod - `JPf?W'=K@&M<[!$*dUu` forbidden

```
echo  "Scan\x64i\x75m"
```

Prints `Scandium`.

#### 22. Python - `JPf?W'=K@&M<[!$*dUuh` forbidden

```
print "Titani\165m";
```

Prints `Titanium`.

#### 23. Unlambda - `JPf?W'=K@&M<[!$*dUuh;` forbidden

`````
`r````.I.r.o.ni
`````

Prints `Iron`. - tested [here](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_unlambda_online.php).

#### 24. Forth - `` JPf?W'=K@&M<[!$*dUuh;` ``  forbidden

```
\ 
.( Cobalt) CR
```

Prints `Cobalt` - tested [here](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_forth_online.php).

#### 25. Lua - `` JPf?W'=K@&M<[!$*dUuh;`\ `` forbidden

```
print("Nickel")
```

Prints `Nickel` - tested [here](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_lua_online.php)

#### 26. Emoticon - `` JPf?W'=K@&M<[!$*dUuh;`\p `` forbidden

```
Zinc :-Q
```

Prints `Zinc`- tested [here](http://repl.it/languages/Emoticon)

Oh well, I think that's about enough for me.

Comment: `s/Nytrogen/Nitrogen/g`; otherwise, nice job (and props for using Pascal, Fortran, and Assembly).