# Decompose a number with bit-xor without the digits 0, 3, 7

Tags: code-golf, number

### Challenge

Write a function or program which takes a positive decimal number, call it *A*, and output two positive numbers, *B* and *C*, such that:

- *A* == *B* bitxor *C*
- *B* and *C* must not contain any of the digits 0, 3 or 7 in its decimal representation.

### Examples

```
>>> decompose(3)
1, 2
>>> decompose(7)
1, 6
>>> decompose(718)
121, 695
>>> decompose(99997)
2, 99999
>>> decompose(4294967296)
4294968218, 922
>>> decompose(5296080632396965608312971217160142474083606142654386510789497504098664630388377556711796340247136376)
6291484486961499292662848846261496489294168969458648464915998254691295448225881546425551225669515922,
1191982455588299219648819556299554251659915414942295896926425126251962564256469862862114191986258666
```

Since the decomposition is not unique, your function/program does not need to output the exact same results as these provided examples.

### Very detailed rules

1. Submissions should be in the form of a **complete function or program**. `import` statements *do* count towards the final score.
2. You may assume the input *A* always contains at least a digit of 0, 3 or 7.
3. You may assume a decomposition always exist.
4. You may use BigInt if they are part of the standard libraries of the language, or can be installed through the language's *de jure* package manager.
5. The function should be fast. It should take no more than **20 seconds** to run on reasonably modern computer when fed a 100-digit number, and no more than 2 seconds when fed a 10-digit number.
6. The function/program should support input up to at least **100 digits**.

   - If the function/program can only support integers up to N<100 digits, there will be a **penalty** of +10×(100/N - 1) bytes to the final score. This is to encourage golfers to support a wider range of numbers even if importing may be verbose.
7. There is **no restriction on the presentation** of input/outputs as long as they are clearly in decimal representation.

   - The function may input and output strings/BigInts if the built-in integer types are not sufficient.
   - The input may come from the function parameter, command line argument or STDIN.
   - The function may return the result, or just print the result directly to STDOUT.
   - However, signed overflow in the input/outputs are not allowed.
   - Approximate answers are not tolerated, the input/outputs must be exact.

### Scoring

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest solution in bytes win.

There is a penalty if the program can only support numbers less than 100 digits:

- 64-bit integers (19 digits) = +42 bytes
- 63-bit integers (18 digits) = +45 bytes
- 53-bit integers (15 digits) = +56 bytes
- 31/32-bit integers (9 digits) = +101 bytes

Comment: Are you sure such decomposition is always possible? Can you sketch me a proof?

Comment: Someone block 1, 5, 9 in the [95 Movie Quotes question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40562/25180) then.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't have a concrete proof, but consider probability: There are about 7^N numbers which does not contain 0, 3 or 7 with N digits. Thus, there are roughly 7^(2N)/2 pairs. And 7^(2N)/2 >> 10^N for all N. So as long as bitxor distributes the result uniformly, we should be pretty safe. (I do have a program for decomposition and I've yet to see any non-decomposable number).

Comment: 100 digits? that means Python wins straight away, as it is the only commonly used language here that supports arbitrary precision integers. Why not 19 digits, which fits in a 64-but unsigned integer? (2^64= 18 446 744 073 709 551 616)

Comment: @steveverrill: Because the [original problem](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40822/32353) that leads to this is based around a 98-digit number, sorry. Also, at least Ruby and Haskell support arbitrary-sized integer natively.

Comment: @steveverrill Mathematica... GolfScript... CJam...

Comment: You've caught me out there @MartinBüttner! :-) Maybe "only python" was an exaggeration. What I meant to say is that many people's favourite languages (OK, my favourite languages) are effectively excluded because they don't support arbitrary precision integers. Mathematica, Golfscript and CJam win everything anyway. But the last two tend to get less upvotes than other languages, because a lot of people can't understand the code.

Comment: And Java (had to say that)

Comment: @steveverrill What if we add a 8*(100/N) bytes penalty if the program can only support up to N digits (+42 bytes if you can only use `uint64_t`)? To compensate if C# programmers rushing from `System.Numerics.BigInteger` to `ulong` just to squeeze a few bytes out.

Comment: @KennyTM You can include it if you like, as it would make the question more inclusive. So the penalty for a 64-bit integer would be 800/19=42.1 bytes and for a 99-bit integer 800/99=8.08 bytes? I'm too busy / exhausted to answer anyway. Although I did like the idea of the question, and I have upvoted it.

Comment: @steveverrill actually I intended the penalty to be 0 for N=100, ~40 for N=19 and infinity for N=0. Updated the rule for that (seems too long though :\ )

Comment: @steverrill: and Julia, and many more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CJam, 70 bytes

```
ri:Q{;Qmr_Q^`1$`+730`&}g_Q^p
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Randomly selects integers until it finds a match. This barely complies with the 20 second limit for 64-bit integers (using the Java interpreter), so I've added 42 to the actual byte count.

#### Example run

```
$ cjam t <<< 7777777777; echo
2695665494
6161166119
```

Answer (score 10):

## Common Lisp, <strike>240</strike> <strike>224</strike> <strike>183</strike> <strike>173</strike> 169 bytes

Common Lisp is a bit verbose for golfing. However, this decomposes 100-digit numbers in under a second, and 200-digit integers in less than ten seconds, so no need for penalties. The algorithm is deterministic.

```
(defun s(z)(and #1=(some(lambda(q)(position q(format()"~a"z)))"037")(+ z(floor z(expt 10 #1#)))))
(defun d(x)(do((y x(or(s y)(s #3=(logxor x y))(return`(,y,#3#)))))(())))
```

The line feed between the functions is for typographic purposes only. Test run with the 100-digit reference input:

```
(time (d 5296080632396965608312971217160142474083606142654386510789497504098664630388377556711796340247136376))
took 677,000 microseconds (0.677000 seconds) to run.
      20,989 microseconds (0.020989 seconds, 3.10%) of which was spent in GC.
During that period, and with 8 available CPU cores,
     671,875 microseconds (0.671875 seconds) were spent in user mode
           0 microseconds (0.000000 seconds) were spent in system mode
 54,221,104 bytes of memory allocated.
(1864921261592819619661568919418981552559955289196969112566252282429216186594265918444566258544614425
 5891958562486995519825158818455999516899524658151445485616155916296966645869599949958954491929662561)
```

As a bonus, I'm including a version of the code that incrementally builds the solution top-down. It can manage a 1000-digit number in less than ten seconds, but cannot compete in golf due to the additional code.

```
(defun decompose (x)
  (flet ((s (z)
           (mapcan #'(lambda (c) (and #1=(position c #2=(format () "~a" z))
                                 (list (- (length #2#) #1# 1))))
                   '(#\0 #\3 #\7))))
    (do ((y x (let ((p (nconc (s y) (s #3=(logxor x y)))))
                (or p (return`(,y,#3#)))
                (+ y (expt 10 (apply #'max p))))))
        (nil))))

* (time (decompose (parse-integer (make-string 1000 :initial-element #\7))))
took 9,226,000 microseconds (9.226000 seconds) to run.
        90,966 microseconds (0.090966 seconds, 0.99%) of which was spent in GC.
During that period, and with 8 available CPU cores,
     9,234,375 microseconds (9.234375 seconds) were spent in user mode
             0 microseconds (0.000000 seconds) were spent in system mode
 487,434,560 bytes of memory allocated.
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
 4184469818464841952189561886965821566229261221619858498284264289194458622668559698924621446851546256444641488616184155821914881485164244662156846141894655485889656891849662551896595944656451462198891289692696856414192264846811616261884188919426294584158925218559295881946496911489245664261126565546419851585441144861859822815144162828551969425529258169849412525611662488849586554989254181228254465226521648916188265491499166186964881248156451994924294646681548996645996894665198811511522424996844864211629888924642289925565591484541149414914699289441561496451494562955652129199261462268846144518142486845251946444998812988291119592418684842524648484689261441456645518518812265495165189812912919529151991611962525419626921619824496626511954895189658691229655648659252448158451924925658586522262194585891859285841914968868466462442488528641466655911199816288496111884591648442984864269495264612518852292965985888414945855422266658614684922884216851481646226111486498155591649619266595911992489425412191)
* (apply #'logxor *)
7777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 103 + 42 = 145 bytes

Python natively supports bigints, but this program far exceeds 20 seconds for a 100-digit number. However, it decomposes 64-bit integers in around 2 seconds.

```
from random import *
def d(a):
 b=c=0
 while set(`b`+`c`)&set('037'):
    b=randint(1,a);c=a^b
 return b,c
```

Comment: Clever idea using randomness. If you're defining a function, you don't need a `while` loop to keep trying random values -- you can just call the function again. Without need for control structure, you can then collapse the function to a `lambda` and a ternary: `from random import* d=lambda a,b=0:set(\`b\`+\`a^b\`)&set(\'037\')and d(a,randint(1,a))or(b,a^b)`. Though you might be better off just not using a function.

Comment: I considered recursion, but it causes a stack overflow for large numbers (even just 11 digits).

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 (132 bytes)

(This is just to stimulate better solutions. This is my solution when solving the original problem in ASCII movie.)

```
def d(a):
 l=len(str(a));s=int('1'*l);u=10**(l-1)
 while u:
  while set(str(s)+str((a^s)//u))&set('037'):s+=u
  u//=10
 print(s,a^s)
```

Although the behavior of bitwise xor in decimal system is pretty complicated, there is one major observation: *modifying the low digits will not affect the high digits*. Therefore, we can work top-down: try to make the top digits free of 0, 3, 7, and then work on the next digit, until the whole number is worked out. This allows us to run in linear time, then processing a thousand-digit number can complete under 1 second. (The Common Lisp solution is also using the same technique I believe.)

Comment: But fixing low digits *may* affect high digits.  For instance, `997^8 == 1005`.  I think there is a kernel of an idea here, but it isn't obvious.

Comment: @KeithRandall: Yes it is just like 999…999 + 1, but, given the choice of `{1,2,4,5,6,8,9}`, there would be some of them that won't affect the high digits. (e.g. `997^2 == 999`). The inner `while` loop does the exhaustion to find the choice that keeps the high digits valid.

Comment: right, but then it's not obvious (to me, at least) that there is definitely a digit that will work.